# What is in your .vimrc?

Tags: vim, refactoring

Vi and Vim allow for really awesome customization, typically stored inside a `.vimrc` file. Typical features for a programmer would be syntax highlighting, smart indenting and so on.

**What other tricks for productive programming have you got, hidden in your .vimrc?**

I am mostly interested in refactorings, auto classes and similar productivity macros, especially for C#.

Comment: I think you should have asked people to post their **commented** vim config files.

Comment: Why not share this things on github? I have my whole .vim folder under git and it all can be seen here: http://github.com/lsdr/vim-folder

Comment: I don't think that entire .vimrcs are useful; if a bunch of people upvote an answer, are you just going to take the whole thing and slap it into your system?  Snippets are much more useful, just as a list of useful aliases or functions is much better than entire .(bash|z)rc files.

Answer (score 104):

You asked for it :-)

```
"{{{Auto Commands

" Automatically cd into the directory that the file is in
autocmd BufEnter * execute "chdir ".escape(expand("%:p:h"), ' ')

" Remove any trailing whitespace that is in the file
autocmd BufRead,BufWrite * if ! &bin | silent! %s/\s\+$//ge | endif

" Restore cursor position to where it was before
augroup JumpCursorOnEdit
   au!
   autocmd BufReadPost *
            \ if expand("<afile>:p:h") !=? $TEMP |
            \   if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
            \     let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = line("'\"") |
            \     let b:doopenfold = 1 |
            \     if (foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo) > foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1)) |
            \        let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1 |
            \        let b:doopenfold = 2 |
            \     endif |
            \     exe JumpCursorOnEdit_foo |
            \   endif |
            \ endif
   " Need to postpone using "zv" until after reading the modelines.
   autocmd BufWinEnter *
            \ if exists("b:doopenfold") |
            \   exe "normal zv" |
            \   if(b:doopenfold > 1) |
            \       exe  "+".1 |
            \   endif |
            \   unlet b:doopenfold |
            \ endif
augroup END

"}}}

"{{{Misc Settings

" Necesary  for lots of cool vim things
set nocompatible

" This shows what you are typing as a command.  I love this!
set showcmd

" Folding Stuffs
set foldmethod=marker

" Needed for Syntax Highlighting and stuff
filetype on
filetype plugin on
syntax enable
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" Who doesn't like autoindent?
set autoindent

" Spaces are better than a tab character
set expandtab
set smarttab

" Who wants an 8 character tab?  Not me!
set shiftwidth=3
set softtabstop=3

" Use english for spellchecking, but don't spellcheck by default
if version >= 700
   set spl=en spell
   set nospell
endif

" Real men use gcc
"compiler gcc

" Cool tab completion stuff
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest,full

" Enable mouse support in console
set mouse=a

" Got backspace?
set backspace=2

" Line Numbers PWN!
set number

" Ignoring case is a fun trick
set ignorecase

" And so is Artificial Intellegence!
set smartcase

" This is totally awesome - remap jj to escape in insert mode.  You'll never type jj anyway, so it's great!
inoremap jj <Esc>

nnoremap JJJJ <Nop>

" Incremental searching is sexy
set incsearch

" Highlight things that we find with the search
set hlsearch

" Since I use linux, I want this
let g:clipbrdDefaultReg = '+'

" When I close a tab, remove the buffer
set nohidden

" Set off the other paren
highlight MatchParen ctermbg=4
" }}}

"{{{Look and Feel

" Favorite Color Scheme
if has("gui_running")
   colorscheme inkpot
   " Remove Toolbar
   set guioptions-=T
   "Terminus is AWESOME
   set guifont=Terminus\ 9
else
   colorscheme metacosm
endif

"Status line gnarliness
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ (%{&ff}){%Y}\ [%l,%v][%p%%]

" }}}

"{{{ Functions

"{{{ Open URL in browser

function! Browser ()
   let line = getline (".")
   let line = matchstr (line, "http[^   ]*")
   exec "!konqueror ".line
endfunction

"}}}

"{{{Theme Rotating
let themeindex=0
function! RotateColorTheme()
   let y = -1
   while y == -1
      let colorstring = "inkpot#ron#blue#elflord#evening#koehler#murphy#pablo#desert#torte#"
      let x = match( colorstring, "#", g:themeindex )
      let y = match( colorstring, "#", x + 1 )
      let g:themeindex = x + 1
      if y == -1
         let g:themeindex = 0
      else
         let themestring = strpart(colorstring, x + 1, y - x - 1)
         return ":colorscheme ".themestring
      endif
   endwhile
endfunction
" }}}

"{{{ Paste Toggle
let paste_mode = 0 " 0 = normal, 1 = paste

func! Paste_on_off()
   if g:paste_mode == 0
      set paste
      let g:paste_mode = 1
   else
      set nopaste
      let g:paste_mode = 0
   endif
   return
endfunc
"}}}

"{{{ Todo List Mode

function! TodoListMode()
   e ~/.todo.otl
   Calendar
   wincmd l
   set foldlevel=1
   tabnew ~/.notes.txt
   tabfirst
   " or 'norm! zMzr'
endfunction

"}}}

"}}}

"{{{ Mappings

" Open Url on this line with the browser \w
map <Leader>w :call Browser ()<CR>

" Open the Project Plugin <F2>
nnoremap <silent> <F2> :Project<CR>

" Open the Project Plugin
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>pal  :Project .vimproject<CR>

" TODO Mode
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>todo :execute TodoListMode()<CR>

" Open the TagList Plugin <F3>
nnoremap <silent> <F3> :Tlist<CR>

" Next Tab
nnoremap <silent> <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>

" Previous Tab
nnoremap <silent> <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>

" New Tab
nnoremap <silent> <C-t> :tabnew<CR>

" Rotate Color Scheme <F8>
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :execute RotateColorTheme()<CR>

" DOS is for fools.
nnoremap <silent> <F9> :%s/$//g<CR>:%s// /g<CR>

" Paste Mode!  Dang! <F10>
nnoremap <silent> <F10> :call Paste_on_off()<CR>
set pastetoggle=<F10>

" Edit vimrc \ev
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>ev :tabnew<CR>:e ~/.vimrc<CR>

" Edit gvimrc \gv
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>gv :tabnew<CR>:e ~/.gvimrc<CR>

" Up and down are more logical with g..
nnoremap <silent> k gk
nnoremap <silent> j gj
inoremap <silent> <Up> <Esc>gka
inoremap <silent> <Down> <Esc>gja

" Good call Benjie (r for i)
nnoremap <silent> <Home> i <Esc>r
nnoremap <silent> <End> a <Esc>r

" Create Blank Newlines and stay in Normal mode
nnoremap <silent> zj o<Esc>
nnoremap <silent> zk O<Esc>

" Space will toggle folds!
nnoremap <space> za

" Search mappings: These will make it so that going to the next one in a
" search will center on the line it's found in.
map N Nzz
map n nzz

" Testing
set completeopt=longest,menuone,preview

inoremap <expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>" : "\<c-g>u\<cr>"
inoremap <expr> <c-n> pumvisible() ? "\<lt>c-n>" : "\<lt>c-n>\<lt>c-r>=pumvisible() ? \"\\<lt>down>\" : \"\"\<lt>cr>"
inoremap <expr> <m-;> pumvisible() ? "\<lt>c-n>" : "\<lt>c-x>\<lt>c-o>\<lt>c-n>\<lt>c-p>\<lt>c-r>=pumvisible() ? \"\\<lt>down>\" : \"\"\<lt>cr>"

" Swap ; and :  Convenient.
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;

" Fix email paragraphs
nnoremap <leader>par :%s/^>$//<CR>

"ly$O#{{{ "lpjjj_%A#}}}jjzajj

"}}}

"{{{Taglist configuration
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
let Tlist_Enable_Fold_Column = 0
let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow = 1
let Tlist_Use_SingleClick = 1
let Tlist_Inc_Winwidth = 0
"}}}

let g:rct_completion_use_fri = 1
"let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = "pdf"
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = "kpdf"

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Comment: But why 3, set shiftwidth=3, set softtabstop=3... maybe 2 or 4 but why 3?

Comment: Just wondering, but won't mapping jj to <Esc> give you a slight lag when hitting j in insert mode?

Comment: @sykora: yes, but as soon as you type another char (that isn't j) it will appear. I do the same thing, but instead with jk, as I think hitting jk is faster than hitting jj. Only times this has affected me is typing out the alphabet, so maybe kj you be better.

Comment: @Johan: because 'three's a magic number'. :) Actually, that's just bikeshedding but I prefer three too. :)

Comment: What causes the combo `<ESC>:`  do not work anymore?

Comment: You could use `set invpaste` instead of writing a function for Paste_on_off.

Comment: "set shiftwidth=3" "set softtabstop=3" - Linux kernel coding Style. Chapter 1: Indentation... ;)

Comment: About the first autocommand you have there - check out :he autochdir :)

Comment: @Johan Why not? I use 4, but it's a matter of preference, really.

Comment: Just a tip, along with the `nnoremap ; :`, you'll want a `vnoremap ; :` too :)

Comment: If real men use gcc, why don't you? (compiler gcc is commented out!)

Comment: Interesting thing about jj not being normally used - it's true! jj is second-to-last used digram (in form xx, after qq) in English language: http://www.springerlink.com/content/c52577302m4pg186

Comment: @ShrikantSharat wrt to swapping of `;` and `:` did you find it interferes without many other mappings? For example, my NERDTree mapping of F2 failed, as did anything starting with `\` or `,`

Comment: @puk, I think you used `nmap` :). Use `nnoremap` and it should work fine.

Comment: @ShrikantSharat I made sure to copy it exactly. I wondered if any one else was having these problems

Comment: @puk, Hehe, I must've been clearer. Try `nnoremap <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` or whatever the NERDTree command is.

Comment: @ShrikantSharat yes I JUST got an answer right now, it was because all my maps with colons in them got all confused http://stackoverflow.com/a/9327083/654789

Answer (score 73):

This isn't in my .vimrc file, but yesterday I learned about the `]p` command. This pastes the contents of a buffer just like `p` does, but it automatically adjusts the indent to match the line the cursor is on! This is excellent for moving code around.

Comment: You mean this is similar to :set paste, p, :set nopaste ?

Comment: As far as I know, the :set paste option doesn't have any effect on the p command, it only affects text typed (or pasted through a terminal) in insert mode. So no, it's a different feature.

Comment: Shouldn't be upvoting for this, because it's not answering the question, but I like it very much ;)

Answer (score 52):

I use the following to keep all the temporary and backup files in one place:

```
set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup
set directory=~/.vim/tmp
```

Saves cluttering working directories all over the place.

You will have to create these directories first, vim will **not** create them for you.

Comment: I should mention you'll have to create those directories yourself, vim won't do it for you.

Comment: Does this handle multiple identical files properly? (e.g. if you're editing several different branches of the same code)

Comment: No, this will overwrite old backup files with the same name.  If anyone has a way around this, let me know.

Comment: Try this: 

au BufWritePre * let &bex = '-' . strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") . '.vimbackup'

(That's one line.)

And I must mention this too: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip962

Comment: That would work, but I think it would give you a new backup file every single time you saved.  Depending on what you want that may be great or terrible.  Very handy tip though.  Would be good to be able to set the backupext (bex) to the full path, but I can't find any way to do that.

Comment: And after I type that I see the wikia tip you link to has the ability to save the full path under the backup dir, along with a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: This also keeps Vim from complaining when opening [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)-synced files across multiple machines.

Answer (score 31):

Someone (viz. Frew) who posted above had this line:

"Automatically cd into the directory that the file is in:"

```
autocmd BufEnter * execute "chdir ".escape(expand("%:p:h"), ' ')
```

I was doing something like that myself until I discovered the same thing could be accomplished with a built in setting:

```
set autochdir
```

I think something similar has happened to me a few different times.  Vim has so many different built-in settings and options that it's sometimes quicker and easier to roll-your-own than search the docs for the built-in way to do it.

Comment: great find! i like using built in stuff more ^_^. plus this does not fail if there is a | in the filename.

Comment: autochdir has some annoyances that I could never work around (changing directory before loading a file given on the command line), and I read elsewhere here on SO about `autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h:gs/ /\\ /` which does the same basic thing but doesn't cripple the command line.

Comment: I prefer to make it optional and use this command to enter the current file's directory :cd %:h

Answer (score 28):

My latest addition is for **highlighting of the current line**

```
set cul                                           # highlight current line
hi CursorLine term=none cterm=none ctermbg=3      # adjust color
```

Comment: is there any way to select from more colors?

Comment: What's the difference between set cul and set cursorline?

Comment: I just use the "set cul" to get a line under my current row. The cursorline setting is messing too much with the syntax highlighting for my taste.

Comment: Refer to this script (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349) to get the available colors. May need to turn on 256 color support for vim to get a wider variety.

Comment: @Claes Actually, `set cul` and `set cursorline` do the exact same thing.

Comment: As a warning you have to make sure you select an appropriate color. Yellow, for example, will render a lot of your tags not visibile

Answer (score 23):

**Update 2012**: I'd now really recommend checking out [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) which has replaced my old statusline script, albeit currently missing a few features I miss.

---

I'd say that the statusline stuff in [my vimrc](https://github.com/gaving/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) was probably most interesting/useful out of the lot (ripped from the authors vimrc [here](http://github.com/scrooloose/vimfiles/blob/52b9810195dc571a87eb8ef6af5ae821184b1baa/vimrc) and corresponding blog post [here](http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2009/07/vim-pr0n-combating-long-lines.html)).

Screenshot:

[status line http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/849/statusline.png](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/849/statusline.png)

Code:

```
"recalculate the trailing whitespace warning when idle, and after saving
autocmd cursorhold,bufwritepost * unlet! b:statusline_trailing_space_warning

"return '[\s]' if trailing white space is detected
"return '' otherwise
function! StatuslineTrailingSpaceWarning()
    if !exists("b:statusline_trailing_space_warning")

        if !&modifiable
            let b:statusline_trailing_space_warning = ''
            return b:statusline_trailing_space_warning
        endif

        if search('\s\+$', 'nw') != 0
            let b:statusline_trailing_space_warning = '[\s]'
        else
            let b:statusline_trailing_space_warning = ''
        endif
    endif
    return b:statusline_trailing_space_warning
endfunction


"return the syntax highlight group under the cursor ''
function! StatuslineCurrentHighlight()
    let name = synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.'),1),'name')
    if name == ''
        return ''
    else
        return '[' . name . ']'
    endif
endfunction

"recalculate the tab warning flag when idle and after writing
autocmd cursorhold,bufwritepost * unlet! b:statusline_tab_warning

"return '[&et]' if &et is set wrong
"return '[mixed-indenting]' if spaces and tabs are used to indent
"return an empty string if everything is fine
function! StatuslineTabWarning()
    if !exists("b:statusline_tab_warning")
        let b:statusline_tab_warning = ''

        if !&modifiable
            return b:statusline_tab_warning
        endif

        let tabs = search('^\t', 'nw') != 0

        "find spaces that arent used as alignment in the first indent column
        let spaces = search('^ \{' . &ts . ',}[^\t]', 'nw') != 0

        if tabs && spaces
            let b:statusline_tab_warning = '[mixed-indenting]'
        elseif (spaces && !&et) || (tabs && &et)
            let b:statusline_tab_warning = '[&et]'
        endif
    endif
    return b:statusline_tab_warning
endfunction

"recalculate the long line warning when idle and after saving
autocmd cursorhold,bufwritepost * unlet! b:statusline_long_line_warning

"return a warning for "long lines" where "long" is either &textwidth or 80 (if
"no &textwidth is set)
"
"return '' if no long lines
"return '[#x,my,$z] if long lines are found, were x is the number of long
"lines, y is the median length of the long lines and z is the length of the
"longest line
function! StatuslineLongLineWarning()
    if !exists("b:statusline_long_line_warning")

        if !&modifiable
            let b:statusline_long_line_warning = ''
            return b:statusline_long_line_warning
        endif

        let long_line_lens = s:LongLines()

        if len(long_line_lens) > 0
            let b:statusline_long_line_warning = "[" .
                        \ '#' . len(long_line_lens) . "," .
                        \ 'm' . s:Median(long_line_lens) . "," .
                        \ '$' . max(long_line_lens) . "]"
        else
            let b:statusline_long_line_warning = ""
        endif
    endif
    return b:statusline_long_line_warning
endfunction

"return a list containing the lengths of the long lines in this buffer
function! s:LongLines()
    let threshold = (&tw ? &tw : 80)
    let spaces = repeat(" ", &ts)

    let long_line_lens = []

    let i = 1
    while i <= line("$")
        let len = strlen(substitute(getline(i), '\t', spaces, 'g'))
        if len > threshold
            call add(long_line_lens, len)
        endif
        let i += 1
    endwhile

    return long_line_lens
endfunction

"find the median of the given array of numbers
function! s:Median(nums)
    let nums = sort(a:nums)
    let l = len(nums)

    if l % 2 == 1
        let i = (l-1) / 2
        return nums[i]
    else
        return (nums[l/2] + nums[(l/2)-1]) / 2
    endif
endfunction


"statusline setup
set statusline=%f "tail of the filename

"display a warning if fileformat isnt unix
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{&ff!='unix'?'['.&ff.']':''}
set statusline+=%*

"display a warning if file encoding isnt utf-8
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{(&fenc!='utf-8'&&&fenc!='')?'['.&fenc.']':''}
set statusline+=%*

set statusline+=%h "help file flag
set statusline+=%y "filetype
set statusline+=%r "read only flag
set statusline+=%m "modified flag

"display a warning if &et is wrong, or we have mixed-indenting
set statusline+=%#error#
set statusline+=%{StatuslineTabWarning()}
set statusline+=%*

set statusline+=%{StatuslineTrailingSpaceWarning()}

set statusline+=%{StatuslineLongLineWarning()}

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

"display a warning if &paste is set
set statusline+=%#error#
set statusline+=%{&paste?'[paste]':''}
set statusline+=%*

set statusline+=%= "left/right separator

function! SlSpace()
    if exists("*GetSpaceMovement")
        return "[" . GetSpaceMovement() . "]"
    else
        return ""
    endif
endfunc
set statusline+=%{SlSpace()}

set statusline+=%{StatuslineCurrentHighlight()}\ \ "current highlight
set statusline+=%c, "cursor column
set statusline+=%l/%L "cursor line/total lines
set statusline+=\ %P "percent through file
set laststatus=2
```

Amongst other things, it informs on the status line of the usual standard file information but
also includes additional things like warnings for :set paste, mixed indenting, trailing
white space etc. Pretty useful if you're particularly anal about your
code formatting.

Furthermore and as shown in the screenshot, combining it with
[syntastic](http://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/tree/master) allows any syntax errors to
be highlighted on it (assuming your language of choice has an associated syntax checker
bundled.

Comment: I am having troubles with the above. There is a missing conditional in LongLines(). I changed it to "while i < threshold" however len is also missing that is being called inside that condition. Any ideas about the len?

Comment: It's ok, I found the real thing here: http://dotfiles.org/~gregf/.vimrc

Comment: @pug Internal server error there now. =( Can you give a hint or paste relevant portion of .vimrc somewhere, please?

Comment: @Anton fixed the paste that got messed up by the code formatting. Should be good now. I'd also recommend sticking it in a plugin/statusline.vim file to keep it from cluttering up your .vimrc if you're going to use it.

Comment: @Gavin Works excellent, thank you for the fix and for the tip! I used to have something like `autocmd BufEnter *.py match OverLength /\%81v.\+/` in .vimrc for highlighting long lines, but your approach might be less distracting. Also, syntax check result in the status bar is one seriously cool thing!

Answer (score 19):

My mini version:

```
syntax on
set background=dark
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2

if has("autocmd")
  filetype plugin indent on
endif

set showcmd             " Show (partial) command in status line.
set showmatch           " Show matching brackets.
set ignorecase          " Do case insensitive matching
set smartcase           " Do smart case matching
set incsearch           " Incremental search
set hidden              " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
```

The big version, collected from various places:

```
syntax on
set background=dark
set ruler                     " show the line number on the bar
set more                      " use more prompt
set autoread                  " watch for file changes
set number                    " line numbers
set hidden
set noautowrite               " don't automagically write on :next
set lazyredraw                " don't redraw when don't have to
set showmode
set showcmd
set nocompatible              " vim, not vi
set autoindent smartindent    " auto/smart indent
set smarttab                  " tab and backspace are smart
set tabstop=2                 " 6 spaces
set shiftwidth=2
set scrolloff=5               " keep at least 5 lines above/below
set sidescrolloff=5           " keep at least 5 lines left/right
set history=200
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set linebreak
set cmdheight=2               " command line two lines high
set undolevels=1000           " 1000 undos
set updatecount=100           " switch every 100 chars
set complete=.,w,b,u,U,t,i,d  " do lots of scanning on tab completion
set ttyfast                   " we have a fast terminal
set noerrorbells              " No error bells please
set shell=bash
set fileformats=unix
set ff=unix
filetype on                   " Enable filetype detection
filetype indent on            " Enable filetype-specific indenting
filetype plugin on            " Enable filetype-specific plugins
set wildmode=longest:full
set wildmenu                  " menu has tab completion
let maplocalleader=','        " all my macros start with ,
set laststatus=2

"  searching
set incsearch                 " incremental search
set ignorecase                " search ignoring case
set hlsearch                  " highlight the search
set showmatch                 " show matching bracket
set diffopt=filler,iwhite     " ignore all whitespace and sync

"  backup
set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim_backup
set viminfo=%100,'100,/100,h,\"500,:100,n~/.viminfo
"set viminfo='100,f1

" spelling
if v:version >= 700
  " Enable spell check for text files
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt setlocal spell spelllang=en
endif

" mappings
" toggle list mode
nmap <LocalLeader>tl :set list!<cr>
" toggle paste mode
nmap <LocalLeader>pp :set paste!<cr>
```

Comment: fyi, 'smartindent' is obsolete (cindent replaces it) and isn't doing anything when you use filetype indenting, and will only be active when it's not useful

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes the simplest things are the most valuable.  The 2 lines in my .vimrc that are totally indispensable:

```
nore ; :
nore , ;
```

Comment: I did `nore \ ;` instead since I use `,` as my `<leader>`

Comment: But what does it do ? :)

Comment: semi-colon is a rarely used command.  colon is an extremely common command, used to enter command-line mode.  Remapping one to the other allows you to enter command-line mode without hitting the shift key, thus saving the muscles in your little fingers.

Comment: On French keyboards you don't need 'shift' to write ',', ';' and ':'... But '\', '[' and ']' are a real pain.

Answer (score 12):

Misc. settings:

1. Turn off annoying error bells:

   ```
   set noerrorbells
   set visualbell
   set t_vb=
   ```
2. Make cursor move as expected with wrapped lines:

   ```
   inoremap <Down> <C-o>gj
   inoremap <Up> <C-o>gk
   ```
3. Lookup `ctags` "tags" file up the directory, until one is found:

   ```
   set tags=tags;/
   ```
4. Display SCons files wiith Python syntax:

   ```
   autocmd BufReadPre,BufNewFile SConstruct set filetype=python
   autocmd BufReadPre,BufNewFile SConscript set filetype=python
   ```

Comment: Add #!/usr/bin/python to the SConstruct file, it will trigger Vim's built in file type detection magic

Comment: Is there a better way to make `j`/`k` move as expected with wrapped lines? I don't want to press `g` every time.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not the most advanced vim'er in the world, but here's a few I've picked up

```
function! Mosh_Tab_Or_Complete()
    if col('.')>1 && strpart( getline('.'), col('.')-2, 3 ) =~ '^\w'
        return "\<C-N>"
    else
        return "\<Tab>"
endfunction

inoremap <Tab> <C-R>=Mosh_Tab_Or_Complete()<CR>
```

Makes the tab-autocomplete figure out whether you want to place a word there or an actual
tab(4 spaces).

```
map cc :.,$s/^ *//<CR>
```

Remove all opening whitespace from here to the end of the file. For some reason I find this useful a lot.

```
set nu! 
set nobackup
```

Show line numbers and don't create those annoying backup files. I've never restored anything from an old backup anyways.

```
imap ii <C-[>
```

While in insert, press i twice to go to command mode. I've never come across a word or variable with 2 i's in a row, and this way I don't have to have my fingers leave the home row or press multiple keys to switch back and forth.

Comment: Interesting mapping of ii ... very interesting.  It's a pretty cool idea - though I'd be worried that it would severely impact my ability to use a 'vanilla' vim should I have to.

Comment: I've been doing the same thing with ;; for a long time, and haven't run into any problems.  When forced to use vanilla vi/vim I immediately remember to use the stupid [esc] key (which was one reason I hated vim for so many years!).  To me, this setting is absolutely essential.  I'd never willingly use vi(m) without it.  

<br>

And I like the idea of using 'ii' instead of ';;': more intuitive, almost like a toggle.

Comment: Another possibility is to use Ctrl-C to leave insert mode. It almost does the same as Escape (the only difference which bothers me is when operating on the lines of a visual block).

Answer (score 8):

My heavily commented vimrc, with readline-esque (emacs) keybindings:

```
if version >= 700

"------ Meta ------"

" clear all autocommands! (this comment must be on its own line)
autocmd!

set nocompatible                " break away from old vi compatibility
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac    " support all three newline formats
set viminfo=                    " don't use or save viminfo files

"------ Console UI & Text display ------"

set cmdheight=1                 " explicitly set the height of the command line
set showcmd                     " Show (partial) command in status line.
set number                      " yay line numbers
set ruler                       " show current position at bottom
set noerrorbells                " don't whine
set visualbell t_vb=            " and don't make faces
set lazyredraw                  " don't redraw while in macros
set scrolloff=5                 " keep at least 5 lines around the cursor
set wrap                        " soft wrap long lines
set list                        " show invisible characters
set listchars=tab:>·,trail:·    " but only show tabs and trailing whitespace
set report=0                    " report back on all changes
set shortmess=atI               " shorten messages and don't show intro
set wildmenu                    " turn on wild menu :e <Tab>
set wildmode=list:longest       " set wildmenu to list choice
if has('syntax')
    syntax on
    " Remember that rxvt-unicode has 88 colors by default; enable this only if
    " you are using the 256-color patch
    if &term == 'rxvt-unicode'
        set t_Co=256
    endif

    if &t_Co == 256
        colorscheme xoria256
    else
        colorscheme peachpuff
    endif
endif

"------ Text editing and searching behavior ------"

set nohlsearch                  " turn off highlighting for searched expressions
set incsearch                   " highlight as we search however
set matchtime=5                 " blink matching chars for .x seconds
set mouse=a                     " try to use a mouse in the console (wimp!)
set ignorecase                  " set case insensitivity
set smartcase                   " unless there's a capital letter
set completeopt=menu,longest,preview " more autocomplete <Ctrl>-P options
set nostartofline               " leave my cursor position alone!
set backspace=2                 " equiv to :set backspace=indent,eol,start
set textwidth=80                " we like 80 columns
set showmatch                   " show matching brackets
set formatoptions=tcrql         " t - autowrap to textwidth
                                " c - autowrap comments to textwidth
                                " r - autoinsert comment leader with <Enter>
                                " q - allow formatting of comments with :gq
                                " l - don't format already long lines

"------ Indents and tabs ------"

set autoindent                  " set the cursor at same indent as line above
set smartindent                 " try to be smart about indenting (C-style)
set expandtab                   " expand <Tab>s with spaces; death to tabs!
set shiftwidth=4                " spaces for each step of (auto)indent
set softtabstop=4               " set virtual tab stop (compat for 8-wide tabs)
set tabstop=8                   " for proper display of files with tabs
set shiftround                  " always round indents to multiple of shiftwidth
set copyindent                  " use existing indents for new indents
set preserveindent              " save as much indent structure as possible
filetype plugin indent on       " load filetype plugins and indent settings

"------ Key bindings ------"

" Remap broken meta-keys that send ^[
for n in range(97,122) " ASCII a-z
    let c = nr2char(n)
    exec "set <M-". c .">=\e". c
    exec "map  \e". c ." <M-". c .">"
    exec "map! \e". c ." <M-". c .">"
endfor

""" Emacs keybindings
" first move the window command because we'll be taking it over
noremap <C-x> <C-w>
" Movement left/right
noremap! <C-b> <Left>
noremap! <C-f> <Right>
" word left/right
noremap  <M-b> b
noremap! <M-b> <C-o>b
noremap  <M-f> w
noremap! <M-f> <C-o>w
" line start/end
noremap  <C-a> ^
noremap! <C-a> <Esc>I
noremap  <C-e> $
noremap! <C-e> <Esc>A
" Rubout word / line and enter insert mode
noremap  <C-w> i<C-w>
noremap  <C-u> i<C-u>
" Forward delete char / word / line and enter insert mode
noremap! <C-d> <C-o>x
noremap  <M-d> dw
noremap! <M-d> <C-o>dw
noremap  <C-k> Da
noremap! <C-k> <C-o>D
" Undo / Redo and enter normal mode
noremap  <C-_> u
noremap! <C-_> <C-o>u<Esc><Right>
noremap! <C-r> <C-o><C-r><Esc>

" Remap <C-space> to word completion
noremap! <Nul> <C-n>

" OS X paste (pretty poor implementation)
if has('mac')
    noremap  √ :r!pbpaste<CR>
    noremap! √ <Esc>√
endif

""" screen.vim REPL: http://github.com/ervandew/vimfiles
" send paragraph to parallel process
vmap <C-c><C-c> :ScreenSend<CR>
nmap <C-c><C-c> mCvip<C-c><C-c>`C
imap <C-c><C-c> <Esc><C-c><C-c><Right>
" set shell region height
let g:ScreenShellHeight = 12


"------ Filetypes ------"

" Vimscript
autocmd FileType vim setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=8 softtabstop=4

" Shell
autocmd FileType sh setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=8 softtabstop=4

" Lisp
autocmd Filetype lisp,scheme setlocal equalprg=~/.vim/bin/lispindent.lisp expandtab shiftwidth=2 tabstop=8 softtabstop=2

" Ruby
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2

" PHP
autocmd FileType php setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4

" X?HTML & XML
autocmd FileType html,xhtml,xml setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2

" CSS
autocmd FileType css setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4

" JavaScript
" autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.json setfiletype javascript
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
let javascript_enable_domhtmlcss=1

"------ END VIM-500 ------"

endif " version >= 500
```

Comment: fyi, 'smartindent' is obsolete (cindent replaces it) and isn't doing anything when you use filetype indenting, and will only be active when it's not useful

Answer (score 7):

```
syntax on
set cindent
set ts=4
set sw=4
set backspace=2
set laststatus=2
set nohlsearch
set modeline
set modelines=3
set ai
map Q gq

set vb t_vb=

set nowrap
set ss=5
set is
set scs
set ru

map <F2> <Esc>:w<CR>
map! <F2> <Esc>:w<CR>

map <F10> <Esc>:qa<CR>
map! <F10> <Esc>:qa<CR>

map <F9>  <Esc>:wqa<CR>
map! <F9>  <Esc>:wqa<CR>

inoremap <s-up> <Esc><c-w>W<Ins>
inoremap <s-down> <Esc><c-w>w<Ins>

nnoremap <s-up> <c-w>W
nnoremap <s-down> <c-w>w

" Fancy middle-line <CR>
inoremap <C-CR> <Esc>o
nnoremap <C-CR> o

" This is the way I like my quotation marks and various braces
inoremap '' ''<Left>
inoremap "" ""<Left>
inoremap () ()<Left>
inoremap <> <><Left>
inoremap {} {}<Left>
inoremap [] []<Left>
inoremap () ()<Left>

" Quickly set comma or semicolon at the end of the string
inoremap ,, <End>,
inoremap ;; <End>;
au FileType python inoremap :: <End>:


au FileType perl,python set foldlevel=0
au FileType perl,python set foldcolumn=4
au FileType perl,python set fen
au FileType perl        set fdm=syntax
au FileType python      set fdm=indent
au FileType perl,python set fdn=4
au FileType perl,python set fml=10
au FileType perl,python set fdo=block,hor,mark,percent,quickfix,search,tag,undo,search

au FileType perl,python abbr sefl self
au FileType perl abbr sjoft shift
au FileType perl abbr DUmper Dumper

function! ToggleNumberRow()
       if !exists("g:NumberRow") || 0 == g:NumberRow
               let g:NumberRow = 1
               call ReverseNumberRow()
       else
               let g:NumberRow = 0
               call NormalizeNumberRow()
       endif
endfunction


" Reverse the number row characters
function! ReverseNumberRow()
       " map each number to its shift-key character
       inoremap 1 !
       inoremap 2 @
       inoremap 3 #
       inoremap 4 $
       inoremap 5 %
       inoremap 6 ^
       inoremap 7 &
       inoremap 8 *
       inoremap 9 (
       inoremap 0 )
       inoremap - _
    inoremap 90 ()<Left>
       " and then the opposite
       inoremap ! 1
       inoremap @ 2
       inoremap # 3
       inoremap $ 4
       inoremap % 5
       inoremap ^ 6
       inoremap & 7
       inoremap * 8
       inoremap ( 9
       inoremap ) 0
       inoremap _ -
endfunction

" DO the opposite to ReverseNumberRow -- give everything back
function! NormalizeNumberRow()
       iunmap 1
       iunmap 2
       iunmap 3
       iunmap 4
       iunmap 5
       iunmap 6
       iunmap 7
       iunmap 8
       iunmap 9
       iunmap 0
       iunmap -
       "------
       iunmap !
       iunmap @
       iunmap #
       iunmap $
       iunmap %
       iunmap ^
       iunmap &
       iunmap *
       iunmap (
       iunmap )
       iunmap _
       inoremap () ()<Left>
endfunction

"call ToggleNumberRow()
nnoremap <M-n> :call ToggleNumberRow()<CR>

" Add use <CWORD> at the top of the file
function! UseWord(word)
       let spec_cases = {'Dumper': 'Data::Dumper'}
       let my_word = a:word
       if has_key(spec_cases, my_word)
               let my_word = spec_cases[my_word]
       endif

       let was_used = search("^use.*" . my_word, "bw")

       if was_used > 0
               echo "Used already"
               return 0
       endif

       let last_use = search("^use", "bW")
       if 0 == last_use
               last_use = search("^package", "bW")
               if 0 == last_use
                       last_use = 1
               endif
       endif

       let use_string = "use " . my_word . ";"
       let res = append(last_use, use_string)
       return 1
endfunction

function! UseCWord()
       let cline = line(".")
       let ccol = col(".")
       let ch = UseWord(expand("<cword>"))
       normal mu
       call cursor(cline + ch, ccol)

endfunction

function! GetWords(pattern)
       let cline = line(".")
       let ccol = col(".")
       call cursor(1,1)

       let temp_dict = {}
       let cpos = searchpos(a:pattern)
       while cpos[0] != 0
               let temp_dict[expand("<cword>")] = 1
               let cpos = searchpos(a:pattern, 'W')
       endwhile

       call cursor(cline, ccol)
       return keys(temp_dict)
endfunction

" Append the list of words, that match the pattern after cursor
function! AppendWordsLike(pattern)
       let word_list = sort(GetWords(a:pattern))
       call append(line("."), word_list)
endfunction


nnoremap <F7>  :call UseCWord()<CR>

" Useful to mark some code lines as debug statements
function! MarkDebug()
       let cline = line(".")
       let ctext = getline(cline)
       call setline(cline, ctext . "##_DEBUG_")
endfunction

" Easily remove debug statements
function! RemoveDebug()
       %g/#_DEBUG_/d
endfunction

au FileType perl,python inoremap <M-d> <Esc>:call MarkDebug()<CR><Ins>
au FileType perl,python inoremap <F6> <Esc>:call RemoveDebug()<CR><Ins>
au FileType perl,python nnoremap <F6> :call RemoveDebug()<CR>

" end Perl settings

nnoremap <silent> <F8> :TlistToggle<CR>
inoremap <silent> <F8> <Esc>:TlistToggle<CR><Esc>

function! AlwaysCD()
       if bufname("") !~ "^scp://" && bufname("") !~ "^sftp://" && bufname("") !~ "^ftp://"
               lcd %:p:h
       endif
endfunction
autocmd BufEnter * call AlwaysCD()

function! DeleteRedundantSpaces()
       let cline = line(".")
       let ccol = col(".")
       silent! %s/\s\+$//g
       call cursor(cline, ccol)
endfunction
au BufWrite * call DeleteRedundantSpaces()

set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set cul

colorscheme evening

autocmd FileType python set formatoptions=wcrq2l
autocmd FileType python set inc="^\s*from"
autocmd FileType python so /usr/share/vim/vim72/indent/python.vim

autocmd FileType c      set si
autocmd FileType mail   set noai
autocmd FileType mail   set ts=3
autocmd FileType mail   set tw=78
autocmd FileType mail   set shiftwidth=3
autocmd FileType mail   set expandtab
autocmd FileType xslt   set ts=4
autocmd FileType xslt   set shiftwidth=4
autocmd FileType txt    set ts=3
autocmd FileType txt    set tw=78
autocmd FileType txt    set expandtab

" Move cursor together with the screen
noremap <c-j> j<c-e>
noremap <c-k> k<c-y>

" Better Marks
nnoremap ' `
```

Answer (score 6):

Some fixes for common typos have saved me a surprising amount of time:

```
:command WQ wq
:command Wq wq
:command W w
:command Q q

iab anf and
iab adn and
iab ans and
iab teh the
iab thre there
```

Comment: I don't like this -- it just trains errors.

Comment: I like it for the words: and, the, there but not for the save and quit

Comment: @Svante, normally I would agree, except I have this in my command also, I tend to save often or save/quit often.  Often my pinkie is just a fraction of a second too slow on lifting off the shift key and BAM one or the other end up being capitalized, its annoying!

Comment: vi was written on and for the ADM3A terminal, which had a designated key for colon (:) so you did not need to press shift. If you remap a key that's not normally used at all in normal / visual mode,  like the space bar, you won't run into this problem as much.                                                                                                                 
    nnoremap <Space> :     and     
    vnomap <Space> :



http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg

Comment: I like this for the save/quit commands, but not for the words. If you make the mistake when the safety net is not there, Vim will tell you your mistake. If you spell the as "teh" when autocorrect is not there, you won't notice and you'll look uneducated.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't realize how many of my 3200 .vimrc lines were just for my quirky needs and would be pretty uninspiring to list here.  But maybe that's why Vim is so useful...

```
iab AlP ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
iab MoN January February March April May June July August September October November December
iab MoO Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
iab NuM 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 
iab RuL ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0

" Highlight every other line
map ,<Tab> :set hls<CR>/\\n.*\\n/<CR>

" This is for working across multiple xterms and/or gvims
" Transfer/read and write one block of text between vim sessions (capture whole line):
" Write
nmap ;w :. w! ~/.vimxfer<CR>
" Read
nmap ;r :r ~/.vimxfer<CR>
" Append 
nmap ;a :. w! >>~/.vimxfer<CR>
```

Answer (score 5):

My 242-line `.vimrc` is not that interesting, but since nobody mentioned it, I felt like I must share the two most important mappings that have enhanced my workflow besides the default mappings:

```
map <C-j> :bprev<CR>
map <C-k> :bnext<CR>
set hidden " this will go along
```

Seriously, switching buffers is **the** thing to do very often. Windows, sure, but everything doesn't fit the screen so nicely.

Similar set of maps for quick browsing of errors (see quickfix) and grep results:

```
map <C-n> :cn<CR>
map <C-m> :cp<CR>
```

Simple, effortless and efficient.

Comment: I have not switched between buffers much, since Vim got tab support. I have the "back" and "forward" extra keys on my keyboard mapped to the tab navigation commands.

Comment: @Don Reba, you know, the tabs just replicate some of the buffers' functionality. So there's no much difference to "use" either buffers or tabs. Purists will say that tabs are meant to organize tasks to separate regions and nothing more. All I say is that buffers have all the convenience and that I have left using tabs, reserving them to something else should something higher abstraction come in need.:)

Answer (score 4):

```
set nobackup 
set nocp
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set et
set ignorecase

set ai
set ruler
set showcmd
set incsearch
set dir=$temp       " Make swap live in the %TEMP% directory
syn on

" Load the color scheme
colo inkpot
```

Answer (score 4):

I use cscope from within vim (making great use of the multiple buffers). I use control-K to initiate most of the commands (stolen from ctags as I recall). Also, I've already generated the .cscope.out file.

if has("cscope")

```
set cscopeprg=/usr/local/bin/cscope
set cscopetagorder=0
set cscopetag
set cscopepathcomp=3
set nocscopeverbose
cs add .cscope.out
set csverb

"
" cscope find
"
" 0 or s: Find this C symbol
" 1 or d: Find this definition
" 2 or g: Find functions called by this function
" 3 or c: Find functions calling this function
" 4 or t: Find assignments to
" 6 or e: Find this egrep pattern
" 7 or f: Find this file
" 8 or i: Find files #including this file
" 
map ^Ks     :cs find 0 <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
map ^Kd     :cs find 1 <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
map ^Kg     :cs find 2 <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
map ^Kc     :cs find 3 <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
map ^Kt     :cs find 4 <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
map ^Ke     :cs find 6 <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
map ^Kf     :cs find 7 <C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR><CR>
map ^Ki     :cs find 8 <C-R>=expand("%")<CR><CR>
```

endif

Answer (score 4):

I keep my vimrc file up on github.  You can find it here:

http://github.com/developernotes/vim-setup/tree/master

Answer (score 3):

I'm on OS X, so some of these might have better defaults on other platforms, but regardless:

```
syntax on
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: You might want to look up `softtabstop` and use that instead of `tabstop`. Leaving `tabstop` at its default value of 8 will help when reading files that others have created with tabs.

Comment: What does OSX have to do with tabs?

Answer (score 3):

```
map = }{!}fmt^M}
map + }{!}fmt -p '> '^M}
set showmatch
```

= is for reformatting normal paragraphs.  + is for reformatting paragraphs in quoted emails.  showmatch is for flashing the matching parenthesis/bracket when I type a close parenthesis or bracket.

Answer (score 3):

Use the first available 'tags' file in the directory tree:

```
:set tags=tags;/
```

Left and right are for switching buffers, not moving the cursor:

```
map <right> <ESC>:bn<RETURN>
map <left> <ESC>:bp<RETURN>
```

Disable search highlighting with a single keypress:

```
map - :nohls<cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab autoindent cindent 
set encoding=utf-8 fileencoding=utf-8
set nobackup nowritebackup noswapfile autoread
set number
set hlsearch incsearch ignorecase smartcase

if has("gui_running")
    set lines=35 columns=140
    colorscheme ir_black
else
    colorscheme darkblue
endif

" bash like auto-completion
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest

inoremap <C-j> <Esc>

" for lusty explorer
noremap glr \lr
noremap glf \lf
noremap glb \lb

" use ctrl-h/j/k/l to switch between splits
map <c-j> <c-w>j
map <c-k> <c-w>k
map <c-l> <c-w>l
map <c-h> <c-w>h

" Nerd tree stuff
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['\.pyc$', '\.pyo$']
noremap gn :NERDTree<Cr>

" cd to the current file's directory
noremap gc :lcd %:h<Cr>
```

Comment: I like a lot of what's going on in your config. Multiple sets per line, `if has("gui_running")`, and cool maps. I've copied most of your config into mine. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your vimrc:

```
imap <C-l> <Space>=><Space>
```

and never think about typing a hashrocket again. Yes, I know you don't need to in Ruby 1.9. But never mind that.

My full vimrc is [here](https://github.com/dpoggi/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc).

Comment: This is a great idea, but I would suggest only mapping it for ruby files: `autocmd FileType ruby imap <C-l> <Space>=><Space>`

Comment: Could you explain what that does for an Emacs person who doesn't know Ruby?

Comment: This adds a Control-L hotkey to Vim's insert mode to automatically type a hashrocket with spaces ( => ). The hashrocket is Ruby's key-value operator for hashes.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much actually in [my .vimrc](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse#svn/misc/trunk) (even if it has 850 lines). Mostly settings and a few common and simple mappings that I was too lazy to extract into plugins.

If you mean "template-files" by "auto-classes", I'm using a [template-expander plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate) -- on this same site, you'll find the ftplugins I've defined for C&C++ editing, some may be adapted to C# I guess.

Regarding the refactoring aspect, there is a tip dedicated to this subject on http://vim.wikia.com ; IIRC the example code is for C#. It inspired me a [refactoring plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhRefactor) that still needs of lot of work (it needs to be refactored actually).

You should have a look at the archives of vim mailing-list, specially the subjects about using vim as an effective IDE. Don't forget to have a look at :make, tags, ...

HTH,

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'll have to scavenge my [configs](http://github.com/adimit/config) yourself. Have fun. Mostly it's just my desired setup, including mappings and random syntax-relevant stuff, as well as folding setup and some plugin configuration, a tex-compilation parser etc.

BTW, something I found extremely useful is "highlight word under cursor":

```
 highlight flicker cterm=bold ctermfg=white
 au CursorMoved <buffer> exe 'match flicker /\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '/').'\>/'
```

Note that only `cterm` and `termfg` are used, because I don't use `gvim`. If you want that to work in `gvim` just replac them with `gui` and `guifg`, respectively.

Comment: How to get it working with multiple windows opened? It seems to work only with the main, launched as first, buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to keep [my .vimrc](http://www.pixelbeat.org/settings/.vimrc) as generally useful as possible.

A handy trick in there is a handler for .gpg files to edit them securely:

```
au BufNewFile,BufReadPre *.gpg :set secure vimi= noswap noback nowriteback hist=0 binary
au BufReadPost *.gpg :%!gpg -d 2>/dev/null
au BufWritePre *.gpg :%!gpg -e -r 'name@email.com' 2>/dev/null
au BufWritePost *.gpg u
```

Answer (score 2):

1) I like a statusline (with the filename, ascii value (decimal), hex value, and the standard lines, cols, and %):

```
set statusline=%t%h%m%r%=[%b\ 0x%02B]\ \ \ %l,%c%V\ %P
" Always show a status line
set laststatus=2
"make the command line 1 line high
set cmdheight=1
```

2) I also like mappings for split windows.

```
" <space> switches to the next window (give it a second)
" <space>n switches to the next window
" <space><space> switches to the next window and maximizes it
" <space>= Equalizes the size of all windows
" + Increases the size of the current window
" - Decreases the size of the current window

 :map <space> <c-W>w
:map <space>n <c-W>w
:map <space><space> <c-W>w<c-W>_
:map <space>= <c-W>=
if bufwinnr(1)
  map + <c-W>+
  map - <c-W>-
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

My .vimrc includes (among other, more usefull things) the following line:

```
set statusline=%2*%n\|%<%*%-.40F%2*\|\ %2*%M\ %3*%=%1*\ %1*%2.6l%2*x%1*%1.9(%c%V%)%2*[%1*%P%2*]%1*%2B
```

I got bored while learning for my high school finals.

Comment: can you please explain what this does?

Comment: It shows a statusline with buffer number, file name, modification status, position within the buffer and a hex code of the character under cursor. Nicely formatted and colored.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my .vimrc. I use Gvim 7.2

```
set guioptions=em
set showtabline=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2

" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab
set autoindent

" Colors and fonts
colorscheme inkpot
set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI

"TAB navigation like firefox
:nmap <C-S-tab> :tabprevious<cr>
:nmap <C-tab> :tabnext<cr>
:imap <C-S-tab> <ESC>:tabprevious<cr>i
:imap <C-tab> <ESC>:tabnext<cr>i
:nmap <C-t> :tabnew<cr>
:imap <C-t> <ESC>:tabnew<cr>i
:map <C-w> :tabclose<cr>

" No Backups and line numbers
set nobackup
set number
set nuw=6

" swp files are saved to %Temp% folder
set dir=$temp
" sets the default size of gvim on open
set lines=40 columns=90
```

Answer (score 1):

What's in my `.vimrc`?

```
ngn@macavity:~$ cat .vimrc
" This file intentionally left blank
```

The real config files lie under `~/.vim/ :)`

And most of the stuff there is parasiting on other people's efforts, blatantly adapted from `vim.org` to my editing advantage.

Comment: I almost have this but .vimrc needs to contain "set nocompatible" if you use those features doesn't it? At least removing it causes a load of errors here!

Answer (score 1):

Line numbers and syntax highlighting.

```
set number
syntax on
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my humble .vimrc.
It is a work in progress (As it should always be), so forgive the messy layout and the commented out lines.

```
" =====Key mapping
" Insert empty line.
nmap <A-o> o<ESC>k
nmap <A-O> O<ESC>j
" Insert one character.
nmap <A-i> i <Esc>r
nmap <A-a> a <Esc>r
" Move on display lines in normal and visual mode.
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
vnoremap j gj
vnoremap k gk
" Do not lose * register when pasting on visual selection.
vmap p "zxP
" Clear highlight search results with <esc>
nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
" Center screen on next/previous selection.
map n nzz
map N Nzz
" <Esc> with jj.
inoremap jj <Esc>
" Switch jump to mark.
nnoremap ' `
nnoremap ` '
" Last and next jump should center too.
nnoremap <C-o> <C-o>zz
nnoremap <C-i> <C-i>zz
" Paste on new line.
nnoremap <A-p> :pu<CR>
nnoremap <A-S-p> :pu!<CR>
" Quick paste on insert mode.
inoremap <C-F> <C-R>"
" Indent cursor on empty line.
nnoremap <A-c> ddO
nnoremap <leader>c ddO
" Save and quit quickly.
nnoremap <leader>s :w<CR>
nnoremap <leader>q :q<CR>
nnoremap <leader>Q :q!<CR>
" The way it should have been.
noremap Y y$
" Moving in buffers.
nnoremap <C-S-tab> :bprev<CR>
nnoremap <C-tab> :bnext<CR>
" Using bufkill plugin.
nnoremap <leader>b :BD<CR>
nnoremap <leader>B :BD!<CR>
nnoremap <leader>ZZ :w<CR>:BD<CR>
" Moving and resizing in windows.
nnoremap + <C-W>+
nnoremap _ <C-W>-
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
nnoremap <leader>w <C-w>c
" Moving in tabs
noremap <c-right> gt
noremap <c-left> gT
nnoremap <leader>t :tabc<CR>
" Moving around in insert mode.
inoremap <A-j> <C-O>gj
inoremap <A-k> <C-O>gk
inoremap <A-h> <Left>
inoremap <A-l> <Right>

" =====General options
" I copy a lot from external apps.
set clipboard=unnamed
" Don't let swap and backup files fill my working directory.
set backupdir=c:\\temp,.    " Backup files
set directory=c:\\temp,.    " Swap files
set nocompatible
set showmatch
set hidden
set showcmd                     " This shows what you are typing as a command.
set scrolloff=3
" Allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start
" Syntax highlight
syntax on                           
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

" =====Searching
set ignorecase
set hlsearch
set incsearch

" =====Indentation settings
" autoindent just copies the indentation from the line above.
"set autoindent
" smartindent automatically inserts one extra level of indentation in some cases.
set smartindent
" cindent is more customizable, but also more strict.
"set cindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

" =====GUI options.
" Just Vim without any gui.
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=T
set lines=40
set columns=150
" Consolas is better, but Courier new is everywhere.
"set guifont=Courier\ New:h9
set guifont=Consolas:h9
" Cool status line.
set statusline=%<%1*===\ %5*%f%1*%(\ ===\ %4*%h%1*%)%(\ ===\ %4*%m%1*%)%(\ ===\ %4*%r%1*%)\ ===%====\ %2*%b(0x%B)%1*\ ===\ %3*%l,%c%V%1*\ ===\ %5*%P%1*\ ===%0* laststatus=2
colorscheme mildblack
let g:sienna_style = 'dark'

" =====Plugins

" ===BufPos
nnoremap <leader>ob :call BufWipeout()<CR>
" ===SuperTab
" Map SuperTab to space key.
let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<c-space>'
let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<s-c-space>'
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = 'context'
" ===miniBufExpl
" let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavVim = 1
" let g:miniBufExplMapCTabSwitchBufs = 1
" let g:miniBufExplorerMoreThanOne = 0
" ===AutoClose
" let g:AutoClosePairs = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']', '"': '"', "'": "'"}
" ===NERDTree
nnoremap <leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
" ===delimitMate
let delimitMate = "(:),[:],{:}"
```

Comment: The gj , gk is really useful when you've line wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything is [here](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/). It is mainly programming oriented, in C++ in particular.

Answer (score 1):

My .vimrc and .bashrc plus my entire .vim folder (with all the plugins) are available at:
http://code.google.com/p/pal-nix/.

Here's my .vimrc for quick review:

```
" .vimrc 
"
" $Author$
" $Date$
" $Revision$
```

" * Initial Configuration * {{{1 "
" change directory on open file, buffer switch etc. {{{2
set autochdir

" turn on filetype detection and indentation {{{2
filetype indent plugin on

" set tags file to search in parent directories with tags; {{{2
set tags=tags;

" reload vimrc on update  {{{2
autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc source %

" set folds to look for markers {{{2
:set foldmethod=marker

" automatically save view and reload folds {{{2
"au BufWinLeave * mkview
"au BufWinEnter * silent loadview

" behave like windows {{{2
"source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim " can't use  if on (use with gvim only)
"behave mswin

" load dictionary files for complete suggestion with Ctrl-n {{{2
set complete+=k
autocmd FileType * exec('set dictionary+=~/.vim/dict/' . &filetype)

" * User Interface * {{{1 "
" turn on coloring {{{2
if has('syntax')
    syntax on
endif

" gvim color scheme of choice {{{2
if has('gui')
    so $VIMRUNTIME/colors/desert.vim
endif

" turn off annoying bell {{{2
set vb

" set the directory for swp files {{{2
if(isdirectory(expand("$VIMRUNTIME/swp")))
    set dir=$VIMRUNTIME/swp
endif

" have fifty lines of cmdline (etc) history {{{2
set history=50

" have cmdline completion  (for filenames, help topics, option names) {{{2
" first list the available options and complete the longest common part, then
" have further s cycle through the possibilities:
set wildmode=list:longest,full

" use "[RO]" for "[readonly]" to save space in the message line: {{{2
set shortmess+=r

" display current mode and partially typed commands in status line  {{{2
set showmode
set showcmd

" Text Formatting -- General  {{{2
set nocompatible     "prevents vim from emulating vi's original bugs
set backspace=2      "make backspace work normal (indent, eol, start)
set autoindent
set smartindent      "makes vim smartly guess indent level
set tabstop=2        "sets up 2 space tabs
set shiftwidth=2     "tells vim to use 2 spaces when text is indented
set smarttab         "uses shiftwidth for inserting s
set expandtab        "insert spaces instead of 
set softtabstop=2    "makes vim see multiple space characters as tabstops
set showmatch        "causes cursor to jump to bracket match
set mat=5            "how many tenths of a second to blink matches
set guioptions-=T    "removes toolbar from gvim
set ruler            "ensures each window contains a status line
set incsearch        "vim will search for text as you type
set hlsearch         "highlight search terms
set hl=l:Visual      "use Visual mode's highlighting scheme --much better
set ignorecase       "ignore case in searches --faster this way
set virtualedit=all  "allows the cursor to stray beyond defined text
set number           "show line numbers in left margin
set path=$PWD/**     "recursively set the path of the project
                     "get more information from the status line 
set statusline=[%n]\ %<%.99f\ %h%w%m%r%{exists('*CapsLockStatusline')?CapsLockStatusline():''}%y%=%-16(\ %l,%c-%v\ %)%P
set laststatus=2     "keep status line showing
set cursorline       "highlight current line
highlight CursorLine guibg=lightblue guifg=white ctermbg=blue ctermfg=white
"set spell          "spell check
set spellsuggest=3  "suggest better spelling
set spelllang=en    "set language
set encoding=utf-8  "set character encoding

" * Macros * {{{1 "
" Function keys {{{2
" Don't you always find yourself hitting  instead of ? {{{3
inoremap  
noremap

" turn off syntax highlighting {{{3
nnoremap   :nohlsearch
inoremap   :nohlsearcha

" NERD Tree Explorer {{{3
nnoremap   :NERDTreeToggle

" open tag list {{{3
nnoremap   :TlistToggle

" Spell check {{{3
nnoremap   :set spell

" No spell check {{{3
nnoremap   :set nospell

" refactor curly braces on keyword line {{{3
map  :%s/) \?\n^\s*{/) {/g

" useful mappings to paste and reformat/reindent {{{2
nnoremap  P P'[v']=
nnoremap  p P'[v']=

" * Scripts * {{{1 "
:au Filetype html,xml,xsl source ~/.vim/scripts/closetag.vim

" Modeline {{{1
" vim:set fdm=marker sw=4 ts=4:

Answer (score 1):

The return, backspace, spacebar and hyphen keys aren't bound to anything useful, so I map them to navigate more conveniently through the document:

```
" Page down, page up, scroll down, scroll up
noremap <Space> <C-f>
noremap - <C-b>
noremap <Backspace> <C-y>
noremap <Return> <C-e>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I launch gVim without arguments, I want it to open in my "project" directory, so that I can do `:find` etc.  However, when I launch it with files, I don't want it to switch directory, I want it to stay right there (in part, so that it opens the file I want it to open!).

```
if argc() == 0
   cd $PROJECT_DIR
endif
```

So that I can use `:find` from any file in the current project, I set up my path to look up the directory tree 'til it finds `src` or `scripts` and descends into those, at least until it hits `c:\work` which is the root of all of my projects.  This allows me to open files in a project that is not current (i.e. `PROJECT_DIR` above specifies a different directory).

```
set path+=src/**;c:/work,scripts/**;c:/work
```

So that I get automatic saving and reloading, and exiting of insert mode when gVim loses focus, as well as automatic checkout from Perforce when editing a readonly file...

```
augroup AutoSaveGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd FocusLost       *.cpp,*.h,*.cs,*.rad*,Jam*,*.py,*.bat,*.mel    wa
    autocmd FileChangedRO   *.cpp,*.h,*.cs,*.rad*,Jam*,*.py,*.bat,*.mel    silent !p4 edit %:p
    autocmd FileChangedRO   *.cpp,*.h,*.cs,*.rad*,Jam*,*.py,*.bat,*.mel    w!
augroup END

augroup OutOfInsert
    autocmd!
    autocmd FocusLost * call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-N>")
augroup END
```

And finally, switch to the directory of the file in the current buffer so that it's easy to `:e` other files in that directory.

```
augroup MiscellaneousTomStuff
    autocmd!
    " make up for the deficiencies in 'autochdir'
    autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h:gs/ /\\ /
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

The line I can't live without and generally first appearing in my `.vimrc`:

```
" prevent switch to Replece mode if <Insert> pressed in insert mode
imap <Insert> <Nop>
```

Another bit I can't live without is preserving the current line when hitting PgDown/PgUp:

```
map <silent> <PageUp> 1000<C-U>
map <silent> <PageDown> 1000<C-D>
imap <silent> <PageUp> <C-O>1000<C-U>
imap <silent> <PageDown> <C-O>1000<C-D>
set nostartofline
```

Disable the annoying matching parentheses highlighting:

```
set noshowmatch
let loaded_matchparen = 1
```

Disable syntax highlighting when editing huge (>4MB) files:

```
au BufReadPost *        if getfsize(bufname("%")) > 4*1024*1024 |
\                               set syntax= |
\                       endif
```

And finally [my simple in-line calculator](http://vimrc-dissection.blogspot.com/2010/05/vim-inline-calculator.html):

```
function CalcX(line_num)
        let l = getline(a:line_num)
        let expr = substitute( l, " *=.*$","","" )
        exec ":let g:tmp_calcx = ".expr
        call setline(a:line_num, expr." = ".g:tmp_calcx)
endfunction
:map <silent> <F11> :call CalcX(".")<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two functions that I use extensively are placeholders to jump to files and InsertChangeLog (), jointly "facilitate the creation of files with more friendly description

```
" place holders snippets
" File Templates
" --------------
"  <leader>j jumps to the next marker
" iabbr <buffer> for for <+i+> in <+intervalo+>:<cr><tab><+i+>
function! LoadFileTemplate()
    "silent! 0r ~/.vim/templates/%:e.tmpl
    syn match vimTemplateMarker "<+.\++>" containedin=ALL
    hi vimTemplateMarker guifg=#67a42c guibg=#112300 gui=bold
endfunction
function! JumpToNextPlaceholder()
    let old_query = getreg('/')
    echo search("<+.\\++>")
    exec "norm! c/+>/e\<CR>"
    call setreg('/', old_query)
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile * :call LoadFileTemplate()
nnoremap <leader>j :call JumpToNextPlaceholder()<CR>a
inoremap <leader>j <ESC>:call JumpToNextPlaceholder()<CR>a


fun! InsertChangeLog()
    normal(1G)
    call append(0, "Arquivo: <+Description+>")
    call append(1, "Criado: " . strftime("%a %d/%b/%Y hs %H:%M"))
    call append(2, "Last Change: " . strftime("%a %d/%b/%Y hs %H:%M"))
    call append(3, "autor: <+digite seu nome+>")
    call append(4, "site: <+digite o endereço de seu site+>")
    call append(5, "twitter: <+your twitter here+>")
    normal gg
endfun
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    " insert change log in files
    fun! InsertChangeLog()
    let l:flag=0
    for i in range(1,5)
        if getline(i) !~ '.*Last Change.*'
            let l:flag = l:flag + 1
        endif
    endfor
    if l:flag >= 5
        normal(1G)
        call append(0, "File: <+Description+>")
        call append(1, "Created: " . strftime("%a %d/%b/%Y hs %H:%M"))
        call append(2, "Last Change: " . strftime("%a %d/%b/%Y hs %H:%M"))
        call append(3, "author: <+your name+>")
        call append(4, "site: <+site+>")
        call append(5, "twitter: <+your twitter here+>")
        normal gg
    endif
endfun
map <special> <F4> <esc>:call InsertChangeLog()<cr>

" update changefile log
" http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/51005
fun! LastChange()
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    if line("$") >= 5
        1,5s/\s*Last Change:\s*\zs.*/\="" . strftime("%Y %b %d %X")/ge
    endif
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun
autocmd BufWritePre * keepjumps call LastChange()

    function! JumpToNextPlaceholder()
    let old_query = getreg('/')
    echo search("<+.\\++>")
    exec "norm! c/+>/e\<CR>"
    call setreg('/', old_query)
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile * :call LoadFileTemplate()
nnoremap <special> <leader>j :call JumpToNextPlaceholder()<CR>a
inoremap <special> <leader>j <ESC>:call JumpToNextPlaceholder()<CR>a

" Cientific calculator
command! -nargs=+ Calc :py print <args>
py from math import *
map ,c :Calc


set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\
\ ft:%{&ft}\ \
\ff:%{&ff}\ \
\%{strftime(\"%a\ %d/%m/%Y\ \
\%H:%M:%S\",getftime(expand(\"%:p\")))}%=\ \
\buf:%n\ \
\L:%04l\ C:%04v\ \
\T:%04L\ HEX:%03.3B\ ASCII:%03.3b\ %P
set laststatus=2 " Always show statusline
```

Answer (score 1):

This isnt in my .vimrc but its related.

In your .bashrc add this line
`alias :q=exit`

Its amazing how much I have used this, sometimes without even realising!

Answer (score 1):

My .vimrc is [available on Github](https://github.com/mikl/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc). Lots of small tweaks and handy bindings in there :)

Answer (score 0):

I put my .vimrc at http://dotfiles.org/~petdance/.vimrc, and I have [some other files at dotfiles.org, too](http://dotfiles.org/~petdance/).

Answer (score 0):

My `~/.vimrc` is pretty standard (mostly the `$VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim`), but I use my `~/.vim` directory extensively, with custom scripts in `~/.vim/ftplugin` and `~/.vim/syntax`.

Answer (score 0):

[my .vimrc](http://media.camronflanders.com/.vimrc). My word swap function is usually a big hit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are mine. They've been evolving for a number of years and they work equally well in Linux/Windows/OSX (last time I checked):

[vimrc](https://github.com/jmcantrell/dotfiles-vim/blob/master/vimrc) and
[gvimrc](https://github.com/jmcantrell/dotfiles-vim/blob/master/gvimrc)

Answer (score 0):

```
" **************************
" * vim general options ****
" **************************
set nocompatible
set history=1000
set mouse=a

" don't have files trying to override this .vimrc:
set nomodeline

" have <F1> prompt for a help topic, rather than displaying the introduction
" page, and have it do this from any mode:
nnoremap <F1> :help<Space>
vmap <F1> <C-C><F1>
omap <F1> <C-C><F1>
map! <F1> <C-C><F1>

set title

" **************************
" * set visual options *****
" **************************
set nu
set ruler
syntax on

" colorscheme oceandeep
set background=dark

set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest,full

" use "[RO]" for "[readonly]"
set shortmess+=r

set scrolloff=3

" display the current mode and partially-typed commands in the status line:
set showmode
set showcmd

" don't make it look like there are line breaks where there aren't:
set nowrap

" **************************
" * set editing options ****
" **************************
set autoindent
filetype plugin indent on
set backspace=eol,indent,start
autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=80
autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab shiftwidth=8

" * Search & Replace
" make searches case-insensitive, unless they contain upper-case letters:
set ignorecase
set smartcase
" show the `best match so far' as search strings are typed:
set incsearch
" assume the /g flag on :s substitutions to replace all matches in a line:
set gdefault

" ***************************
" * tab completion **********
" ***************************
setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
imap <Tab> <C-x><C-o>
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>

" ***************************
" * keyboard mapping ********
" ***************************
imap <A-1> <Esc>:tabn 1<CR>i
imap <A-2> <Esc>:tabn 2<CR>i
imap <A-3> <Esc>:tabn 3<CR>i
imap <A-4> <Esc>:tabn 4<CR>i
imap <A-5> <Esc>:tabn 5<CR>i
imap <A-6> <Esc>:tabn 6<CR>i
imap <A-7> <Esc>:tabn 7<CR>i
imap <A-8> <Esc>:tabn 8<CR>i
imap <A-9> <Esc>:tabn 9<CR>i

map <A-1> :tabn 1<CR>
map <A-2> :tabn 2<CR>
map <A-3> :tabn 3<CR>
map <A-4> :tabn 4<CR>
map <A-5> :tabn 5<CR>
map <A-6> :tabn 6<CR>
map <A-7> :tabn 7<CR>
map <A-8> :tabn 8<CR>
map <A-9> :tabn 9<CR>

" ***************************
" * Utilities Needed ********
" ***************************
function InsertTabWrapper()
      let col = col('.') - 1
      if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
          return "\<tab>"
      else
          return "\<c-p>"
      endif
endfunction

" end of .vimrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most significant things below are the font choices and the colour schemes.  Yes, I have spent far too long enjoyably fiddling with those things. :)

```
"set tildeop
set nosmartindent
" set guifont=courier
" awesome programming font
" set guifont=peep:h09:cANSI
" another nice looking font for programming and general use
set guifont=Bitstream_Vera_Sans_MONO:h09:cANSI
set lines=68
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set ignorecase
set nobackup
" set writebackup

" Some of my favourite colour schemes, lovingly crafted over the years :)
" very dark scarlet background, almost white text
" hi Normal   guifg=#FFFFF0 guibg=#3F0000 ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black
" C64 colours
"hi Normal   guifg=#8CA1EC guibg=#372DB4 ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black 
" nice forest green background with bisque fg
hi Normal   guifg=#9CfCb1 guibg=#279A1D ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black 
" dark green background with almost white text 
"hi Normal   guifg=#FFFFF0 guibg=#003F00 ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black

" french blue background, almost white text
"hi Normal   guifg=#FFFFF0 guibg=#00003F ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black

" slate blue bg, grey text
"hi Normal   guifg=#929Cb1 guibg=#20403F ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black 

" yellow/orange bg, black text
hi Normal   guifg=#000000 guibg=#f8db3a ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set guifont=FreeMono\ 12

colorscheme default

set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set nobackup "do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
set history=10000 "keep 10000 lines of command line history
set ruler "show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd "display incomplete commands
set showmode
set showmatch
set nojoinspaces "do not insert a space, when joining lines
set whichwrap="" "do not jump to the next line when deleting
"set nowrap
filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
set hlsearch
set incsearch "do incremental searching
set autoindent
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set number
set laststatus=2
set visualbell "do not beep
set tabpagemax=100
set statusline=%F\ %h%m%r%=%l/%L\ \(%-03p%%\)\ %-03c\ 

"use listmode to make tabs visible and make them gray so they are not
"disctrating too much
set listchars=tab:»\ ,eol:¬,trail:.
highlight NonText ctermfg=gray guifg=gray
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=gray guifg=gray
highlight clear MatchParen
highlight MatchParen cterm=bold
set list


match Todo /@todo/ "highlight doxygen todos


"different tabbing settings for different file types
if has("autocmd")
    autocmd FileType c setlocal tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
    autocmd FileType cpp setlocal tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
    autocmd FileType go setlocal tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab
    autocmd FileType make setlocal tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab
    autocmd FileType python setlocal tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab

    " doesnt work properly -- revise me
    autocmd CursorMoved * call RonnyHighlightWordUnderCursor()
    autocmd CursorMovedI * call RonnyHighlightWordUnderCursor()

    "jump to the end of the file if it is a logfile
    autocmd BufReadPost *.log normal G

    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go
endif


highlight Search ctermfg=white ctermbg=gray
highlight IncSearch ctermfg=white ctermbg=gray
highlight RonnyWordUnderCursorHighlight cterm=bold


function! RonnyHighlightWordUnderCursor()
python << endpython
import vim

# get the character under the cursor
row, col = vim.current.window.cursor
characterUnderCursor = ''
try:
    characterUnderCursor = vim.current.buffer[row-1][col]
except:
    pass

# remove last search
vim.command("match RonnyWordUnderCursorHighlight //")

# if the cursor is currently located on a real word, move on and highlight it
if characterUnderCursor.isalpha() or characterUnderCursor.isdigit() or characterUnderCursor is '_':

    # expand cword to get the word under the cursor
    wordUnderCursor = vim.eval("expand(\'<cword>\')")
    if wordUnderCursor is None :
        wordUnderCursor = ""

    # escape the word
    wordUnderCursor = vim.eval("RonnyEscapeString(\"" + wordUnderCursor + "\")")
    wordUnderCursor = "\<" + wordUnderCursor + "\>"

    currentSearch = vim.eval("@/")

    if currentSearch != wordUnderCursor :
        # highlight it, if it is not the currently searched word
        vim.command("match RonnyWordUnderCursorHighlight /" + wordUnderCursor + "/")

endpython
endfunction


function! RonnyEscapeString(s)
python << endpython
import vim

s = vim.eval("a:s")

escapeMap = {
    '"'     : '\\"',
    "'"     : '\\''',
    "*"     : '\\*',
    "/"     : '\\/',
    #'' : ''
}

s = s.replace('\\', '\\\\')

for before, after in escapeMap.items() :
    s = s.replace(before, after)

vim.command("return \'" + s + "\'")
endpython
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created my own syntax for my to do or checklist documents which highlights things like

-> do this (in bold)

!-> do this now (in orange)

++> doing this in process (in green)

=> this is done (in gray)

I have the document in ./syntax/ as fc_comdoc.vim

in vimrc to set this syntax for anything with my custom extension .txtcd or .txtap

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.txtap,*.txtcd   setf fc_comdoc
```

Answer (score 0):

I show fold contents and syntax groups on mouse-over:

```
function! SyntaxBallon()
    let synID   = synID(v:beval_lnum, v:beval_col, 0)
    let groupID = synIDtrans(synID)
    let name    = synIDattr(synID, "name")
    let group   = synIDattr(groupID, "name")
    return name . "\n" . group
endfunction

function! FoldBalloon()
    let foldStart = foldclosed(v:beval_lnum)
    let foldEnd   = foldclosedend(v:beval_lnum)
    let lines = []
    if foldStart >= 0
        " we are in a fold
        let numLines = foldEnd - foldStart + 1
        if (numLines > 17)
            " show only the first 8 and the last 8 lines
            let lines += getline(foldStart, foldStart + 8)
            let lines += [ '-- Snipped ' . (numLines - 16) . ' lines --']
            let lines += getline(foldEnd - 8, foldEnd)
        else
            " show all lines
            let lines += getline(foldStart, foldEnd)
        endif
    endif
    " return result
    return join(lines, has("balloon_multiline") ? "\n" : " ")
endfunction

function! Balloon()
    if foldclosed(v:beval_lnum) >= 0
        return FoldBalloon()
    else
        return SyntaxBallon()
endfunction

set balloonexpr=Balloon()
set ballooneval
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
set number
set autoindent
set smartindent
set background=dark
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
set tw=80
set expandtab
set mousehide
set cindent
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·
set autoread
filetype on
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on

" abbreviations for c programming
func LoadCAbbrevs()
 "  iabbr do do {<CR>} while ();<C-O>3h<C-O>
 "  iabbr for for (;;) {<CR>}<C-O>k<C-O>3l<C-O>
 "  iabbr switch switch () {<CR>}<C-O>k<C-O>6l<C-O>
 "  iabbr while while () {<CR>}<C-O>k<C-O>5l<C-O>
 "  iabbr if if () {<CR>}<C-O>k<C-O>2l<C-O>
    iabbr #d #define
    iabbr #i #include
endfunc
au FileType c,cpp call LoadCAbbrevs()

au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
                         \ exe "normal g'\"" | endif

autocmd FileType python set nocindent shiftwidth=4 ts=4 foldmethod=indent
```

Not much there.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this now:

```
:nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

I found it in [ViEmu Blog](http://www.viemu.com/blog/2009/06/16/a-vim-and-viemu-mapping-you-really-cant-miss-never-type-noh-again/) and I really dig this. A short explanation - It makes Esc turn off search highlight in normal mode.

Comment: I tried this for a while, but then found it was causing lines to be deleted when I pressed the down arrow, immediately after starting vim. Removing this line stopped it happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set cindent
set noautoindent
set noexpandtab
set nocompatible
set cino=:0(4u0
set backspace=indent,start
set term=ansi
let lpc_syntax_for_c=1
syntax enable

autocmd FileType c set cin noai nosi
autocmd FileType lpc set cin noai nosi
autocmd FileType css set nocin ai noet
autocmd FileType js set nocin ai noet
autocmd FileType php set nocin ai noet

function! DeleteFile(...)
  if(exists('a:1'))
    let theFile=a:1
  elseif ( &ft == 'help' )
    echohl Error
    echo "Cannot delete a help buffer!"
    echohl None
    return -1
  else
    let theFile=expand('%:p')
  endif
  let delStatus=delete(theFile)
  if(delStatus == 0)
    echo "Deleted " . theFile
  else
    echohl WarningMsg
    echo "Failed to delete " . theFile
    echohl None
  endif
  return delStatus
endfunction
"delete the current file
com! Rm call DeleteFile()
"delete the file and quit the buffer (quits vim if this was the last file)
com! RM call DeleteFile() <Bar> q!
```

Answer (score 0):

The results of years of my meddling with vim are all [here](http://pastebin.com/f82bd697).

Answer (score 0):

Useful stuff for C/C++ and svn usage (could be easily modified for git/hg/whatever).
I set them to my F-keys.

Not C#, but useful nonetheless.

```
function! SwapFilesKeep()
    " Open a new window next to the current one with the matching .cpp/.h pair"
    let command = "echo " . bufname("%") . "|sed s,\h$,\H,|sed s,cpp,h,|sed s,H$,cpp,"
    let newfilename = system(command)
    silent execute("vs " . newfilename)
endfunction

function! SwapFiles()
    " swap between .cpp and .h "
    let command = "echo " . bufname("%") . "|sed s,\h$,\H,|sed s,cpp,h,|sed s,H$,cpp,"
    let newfilename = system(command)
    silent execute("e " . newfilename)
endfunction

function! SvnDiffAll()
    let tempfile = system("tempfile")
    silent execute ":!svn diff .>" . tempfile
    execute ":sf ".tempfile
    return
endfunction

function! SvnLog()
    let fn = expand('%')
    let tempfile = system("tempfile")
    silent execute ":!svn log -v " . fn . ">" . tempfile
    execute ":sf ".tempfile
    return
endfunction

function! SvnStatus()
    let tempfile = system("tempfile")
    silent execute ":!svn status .>" . tempfile
    execute ":sf ".tempfile
    return
endfunction

function! SvnDiff()
    " diff with BASE "
    let dir = expand('%:p:h')
    let fn = expand('%')
    let fn = substitute(fn,".*\\","","")
    let fn = substitute(fn,".*/","","")
    silent execute ":vert diffsplit " . dir . "/.svn/text-base/" . fn . ".svn-base"
    silent execute ":set ft=cpp"
    unlet fn dir
    return
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

***:map + v%zf***    # hit "+" to fold a function/loop anything within a paranthesis.

***:set expandtab***  # tab will be expanded as spaces as per the setting of ts (tabspace)

Answer (score 0):

```
set ai 
set si 
set sm 
set sta 
set ts=3 
set sw=3 
set co=130 
set lines=50 
set nowrap 
set ruler 
set showcmd 
set showmode 
set showmatch 
set incsearch 
set hlsearch 
set gfn=Consolas:h11
set guioptions-=T
set clipboard=unnamed
set expandtab
set nobackup

syntax on 
colors torte
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to split my .vimrc into different sections so that I can turn different sections on and off on all the different machines I run on, i.e. some bits on windows some on linux etc:

```
"*****************************************
"* SECTION 1 - THINGS JUST FOR GVIM      *
"*****************************************
if v:version >= 700

    "Note: Other plugin files
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/bens_pscripts.vim
    "source ~/.vim/ben_init/stim_projects.vim
    "source ~/.vim/ben_init/temp_commands.vim
    "source ~/.vim/ben_init/wwatch.vim

    "Extract sections of code as a function (works in C, C++, Perl, Java)
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/functify.vim

    "Settings that relate to the look/feel of vim in the GUI
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/gui_settings.vim

    "General VIM settings
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/general_settings.vim

    "Settings for programming
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/c_programming.vim

    "Settings for completion
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/completion.vim

    "My own templating system
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/templates.vim

    "Abbreviations and interesting key mappings
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/abbrev.vim

    "Plugin configuration
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/plugin_config.vim

    "Wiki configuration
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/wiki_config.vim

    "Key mappings
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/key_mappings.vim

    "Auto commands
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/autocmds.vim

    "Handy Functions written by other people
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/handy_functions.vim

    "My own omni_completions
    source ~/.vim/ben_init/bens_omni.vim

endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my vimrc I have a bigger collection of plugins. Everything is stored in a git repository at http://github.com/jceb/vimrc.

```
" Author: Jan Christoph Ebersbach jceb AT e-jc DOT de

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ---------- Settings ----------
"
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Prevent modelines in files from being evaluated (avoids a potential
" security problem wherein a malicious user could write a hazardous
" modeline into a file) (override default value of 5)
set modeline
set modelines=5

" ########## miscellaneous options ##########
set nocompatible               " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set whichwrap=<,>              " Cursor key move the cursor to the next/previous line if pressed at the end/beginning of a line
set backspace=indent,eol,start " more powerful backspacing
set viminfo='20,\"50           " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more than
set history=100                " keep 50 lines of command line history
set incsearch                  " Incremental search
set hidden                     " hidden allows to have modified buffers in background
set noswapfile                 " turn off backups and files
set nobackup                   " Don't keep a backup file
set magic                      " special characters that can be used in search patterns
set grepprg=grep\ --exclude='*.svn-base'\ -n\ $*\ /dev/null " don't grep through svn-base files
" Try do use the ack program when available
let tmp = ''
for i in ['ack', 'ack-grep']
 let tmp = substitute (system ('which '.i), '\n.*', '', '')
 if v:shell_error == 0
  exec "set grepprg=".tmp."\\ -a\\ -H\\ --nocolor\\ --nogroup"
  break
 endif
endfor
unlet tmp
"set autowrite                                               " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
" Suffixes that get lower priority when doing tab completion for filenames.
" These are files we are not likely to want to edit or read.
set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc,.pdf,.exe
"set autochdir                  " move to the directory of the edited file
set ssop-=options              " do not store global and local values in a session
set ssop-=folds                " do not store folds

" ########## visual options ##########
set wildmenu             " When 'wildmenu' is on, command-line completion operates in an enhanced mode.
set wildcharm=<C-Z>
set showmode             " If in Insert, Replace or Visual mode put a message on the last line.
set guifont=monospace\ 8 " guifont + fontsize
set guicursor=a:blinkon0 " cursor-blinking off!!
set ruler                " show the cursor position all the time
set nowrap               " kein Zeilenumbruch
set foldmethod=indent    " Standardfaltungsmethode
set foldlevel=99         " default fold level
set winminheight=0       " Minimal Windowheight
set showcmd              " Show (partial) command in status line.
set showmatch            " Show matching brackets.
set matchtime=2          " time to show the matching bracket
set hlsearch             " highlight search
set linebreak
set lazyredraw           " no readraw when running macros
set scrolloff=3          " set X lines to the curors - when moving vertical..
set laststatus=2         " statusline is always visible
set statusline=(%{bufnr('%')})\ %t\ \ %r%m\ #%{expand('#:t')}\ (%{bufnr('#')})%=[%{&fileformat}:%{&fileencoding}:%{&filetype}]\ %l,%c\ %P " statusline
"set mouse=n             " mouse only in normal mode support in vim
"set foldcolumn=1        " show folds
set number               " draw linenumbers
set nolist               " list nonprintable characters
set sidescroll=0         " scroll X columns to the side instead of centering the cursor on another screen
set completeopt=menuone  " show the complete menu even if there is just one entry
set listchars+=precedes:<,extends:> " display the following nonprintable characters
if $LANG =~ ".*\.UTF-8$" || $LANG =~ ".*utf8$" || $LANG =~ ".*utf-8$"
 set listchars+=tab:»·,trail:·" display the following nonprintable characters
endif
set guioptions=aegitcm   " disabled menu in gui mode
"set guioptions=aegimrLtT
set cpoptions=aABceFsq$  " q: When joining multiple lines leave the cursor at the position where it would be when joining two lines.
" $:  When making a change to one line, don't redisplay the line, but put a '$' at the end of the changed text.
" v: Backspaced characters remain visible on the screen in Insert mode.

colorscheme peaksea " default color scheme

" default color scheme
" if &term == '' || &term == 'builtin_gui' || &term == 'dumb'
if has('gui_running')
 set background=light " use colors that fit to a light background
else
 set background=light " use colors that fit to a light background
 "set background=dark " use colors that fit to a dark background
endif

syntax on " syntax highlighting

" ########## text options ##########
set smartindent              " always set smartindenting on
set autoindent               " always set autoindenting on
set backspace=2              " Influences the working of <BS>, <Del>, CTRL-W and CTRL-U in Insert mode.
set textwidth=0              " Don't wrap words by default
set shiftwidth=4             " number of spaces to use for each step of indent
set tabstop=4                " number of spaces a tab counts for
set noexpandtab              " insert spaces instead of tab
set smarttab                 " insert spaces only at the beginning of the line
set ignorecase               " Do case insensitive matching
set smartcase                " overwrite ignorecase if pattern contains uppercase characters
set formatoptions=lcrqn      " no automatic linebreak
set pastetoggle=<F11>        " put vim in pastemode - usefull for pasting in console-mode
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac " favorite fileformats
set encoding=utf-8           " set default-encoding to utf-8
set iskeyword+=_,-           " these characters also belong to a word
set matchpairs+=<:>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ---------- Special Configuration ----------
"
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" ########## determine terminal encoding ##########
"if has("multi_byte") && &term != 'builtin_gui'
"    set termencoding=utf-8
"
"    " unfortunately the normal xterm supports only latin1
"    if $TERM == "xterm" || $TERM == "xterm-color" || $TERM == "screen" || $TERM == "linux" || $TERM_PROGRAM == "GLterm"
"        let propv = system("xprop -id $WINDOWID -f WM_LOCALE_NAME 8s ' $0' -notype WM_LOCALE_NAME")
"        if propv !~ "WM_LOCALE_NAME .*UTF.*8"
"            set termencoding=latin1
"        endif
"    endif
"    " for the possibility of using a terminal to input and read chinese
"    " characters
"    if $LANG == "zh_CN.GB2312"
"        set termencoding=euc-cn
"    endif
"endif

" Set paper size from /etc/papersize if available (Debian-specific)
if filereadable('/etc/papersize')
 let s:papersize = matchstr(system('/bin/cat /etc/papersize'), '\p*')
 if strlen(s:papersize)
  let &printoptions = "paper:" . s:papersize
 endif
 unlet! s:papersize
endif

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ---------- Autocommands ----------
"
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

filetype plugin on " automatically load filetypeplugins
filetype indent on " indent according to the filetype

if !exists("autocommands_loaded")
 let autocommands_loaded = 1

 augroup templates
  " read templates
  " au BufNewFile ?akefile,*.mk TSkeletonSetup Makefile
  " au BufNewFile *.tex TSkeletonSetup latex.tex
  " au BufNewFile build*.xml TSkeletonSetup antbuild.xml
  " au BufNewFile test*.py,*Test.py TSkeletonSetup pyunit.py
  " au BufNewFile *.py TSkeletonSetup python.py
 augroup END

 augroup filetypesettings
  " Do word completion automatically
  au FileType debchangelog setl expandtab
  au FileType asciidoc,mkd,txt,mail call DoFastWordComplete()
  au FileType tex,plaintex setlocal makeprg=pdflatex\ \"%:p\"
  au FileType mkd setlocal autoindent
  au FileType java,c,cpp setlocal noexpandtab nosmarttab
  au FileType mail setlocal textwidth=70
  au FileType mail call FormatMail()
  au FileType mail setlocal formatoptions=tcrqan
  au FileType mail setlocal comments+=b:--
  au FileType txt setlocal formatoptions=tcrqn textwidth=72
  au FileType asciidoc,mkd,tex setlocal formatoptions=tcrq textwidth=72
  au FileType xml,docbk,xhtml,jsp setlocal formatoptions=tcrqn
  au FileType ruby setlocal shiftwidth=2

  au BufReadPost,BufNewFile *  set formatoptions-=o " o is really annoying
  au BufReadPost,BufNewFile *  call ReadIncludePath()

  " Special Makefilehandling
  au FileType automake,make setlocal list noexpandtab

  au FileType xsl,xslt,xml,html,xhtml runtime! scripts/closetag.vim

  " Omni completion settings
  "au FileType c  setlocal completefunc=ccomplete#Complete
  au FileType css setlocal omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
  "au FileType html setlocal completefunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
  "au FileType js setlocal completefunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
  "au FileType php setlocal completefunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
  "au FileType python setlocal completefunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
  "au FileType ruby setlocal completefunc=rubycomplete#Complete
  "au FileType sql setlocal completefunc=sqlcomplete#Complete
  "au FileType *  setlocal completefunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
  "au FileType xml setlocal completefunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags

  au FileType help setlocal nolist

  " insert a prompt for every changed file in the commit message
  "au FileType svn :1![ -f "%" ] && awk '/^[MDA]/ { print $2 ":\n - " }' %
 augroup END

 augroup hooks
  " replace "Last Modified: with the current time"
  au BufWritePre,FileWritePre * call LastMod()

  " line highlighting in insert mode
  autocmd InsertLeave * set nocul
  autocmd InsertEnter * set cul

  " move to the directory of the edited file
  "au BufEnter *      if isdirectory (expand ('%:p:h')) | cd %:p:h | endif

  " jump to last position in the file
  au BufRead *  if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &filetype != "mail" | exe "normal g`\"" | endif
  " jump to last position every time a buffer is entered
  "au BufEnter *  if line("'x") > 0 && line("'x") <= line("$") && line("'y") > 0 && line("'y") <= line("$") && &filetype != "mail" | exe "normal g'yztg`x" | endif
  "au BufLeave *  if &modifiable | exec "normal mxHmy"
 augroup END

 augroup highlight
  " make visual mode dark cyan
  au FileType * hi Visual ctermfg=Black ctermbg=DarkCyan gui=bold guibg=#a6caf0
  " make cursor red
  au BufEnter,BufRead,WinEnter * :call SetCursorColor()

  " hightlight trailing spaces and tabs and the defined print margin
  "au FileType * hi WhiteSpaceEOL_Printmargin ctermfg=black ctermbg=White guifg=Black guibg=White
  au FileType * hi WhiteSpaceEOL_Printmargin ctermbg=White guibg=White
  au FileType * let m='' | if &textwidth > 0 | let m='\|\%' . &textwidth . 'v.' | endif | exec 'match WhiteSpaceEOL_Printmargin /\s\+$' . m .'/'
 augroup END
endif

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ---------- Functions ----------
"
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" set cursor color
function! SetCursorColor()
 hi Cursor ctermfg=black ctermbg=red guifg=Black guibg=Red
endfunction
call SetCursorColor()

" change dir the root of a debian package
function! GetPackageRoot()
 let sd = getcwd()
 let owd = sd
 let cwd = owd
 let dest = sd
 while !isdirectory('debian')
  lcd ..
  let owd = cwd
  let cwd = getcwd()
  if cwd == owd
   break
  endif
 endwhile
 if cwd != sd && isdirectory('debian')
  let dest = cwd
 endif
 return dest
endfunction

" vim tip: Opening multiple files from a single command-line
function! Sp(dir, ...)
 let split = 'sp'
 if a:dir == '1'
  let split = 'vsp'
 endif
 if(a:0 == 0)
  execute split
 else
  let i = a:0
  while(i > 0)
   execute 'let files = glob (a:' . i . ')'
   for f in split (files, "\n")
    execute split . ' ' . f
   endfor
   let i = i - 1
  endwhile
  windo if expand('%') == '' | q | endif
 endif
endfunction
com! -nargs=* -complete=file Sp call Sp(0, <f-args>)
com! -nargs=* -complete=file Vsp call Sp(1, <f-args>)

" reads the file .include_path - useful for C programming
function! ReadIncludePath()
 let include_path = expand("%:p:h") . '/.include_path'
 if filereadable(include_path)
  for line in readfile(include_path, '')
   exec "setl path +=," . line
  endfor
 endif
endfunction

" update last modified line in file
fun! LastMod()
 let line = line(".")
 let column = col(".")
 let search = @/

 " replace Last Modified in the first 20 lines
 if line("$") > 20
  let l = 20
 else
  let l = line("$")
 endif
 " replace only if the buffer was modified
 if &mod == 1
  silent exe "1," . l . "g/Last Modified:/s/Last Modified:.*/Last Modified: " .
     \ strftime("%a %d. %b %Y %T %z %Z") . "/"
 endif
 let @/ = search

 " set cursor to last position before substitution
 call cursor(line, column)
endfun

" toggles show marks plugin
"fun! ToggleShowMarks()
" if exists('b:sm') && b:sm == 1
"  let b:sm=0
"  NoShowMarks
"  setl updatetime=4000
" else
"  let b:sm=1
"  setl updatetime=200
"  DoShowMarks
" endif
"endfun

" reformats an email
fun! FormatMail()
 " workaround for the annoying mutt send-hook behavoir
 silent! 1,/^$/g/^X-To: .*/exec 'normal gg'|exec '/^To: /,/^Cc: /-1d'|1,/^$/s/^X-To: /To: /|exec 'normal dd'|exec '?Cc'|normal P
 silent! 1,/^$/g/^X-Cc: .*/exec 'normal gg'|exec '/^Cc: /,/^Bcc: /-1d'|1,/^$/s/^X-Cc: /Cc: /|exec 'normal dd'|exec '?Bcc'|normal P
 silent! 1,/^$/g/^X-Bcc: .*/exec 'normal gg'|exec '/^Bcc: /,/^Subject: /-1d'|1,/^$/s/^X-Bcc: /Bcc: /|exec 'normal dd'|exec '?Subject'|normal P

 " delete signature
 silent! /^> --[\t ]*$/,/^-- $/-2d
 " fix quotation
 silent! /^\(On\|In\) .*$/,/^-- $/-1:s/>>/> >/g
 silent! /^\(On\|In\) .*$/,/^-- $/-1:s/>\([^\ \t]\)/> \1/g
 " delete inner and trailing spaces
 normal :%s/[\xa0\x0d\t ]\+$//g
 normal :%s/\([^\xa0\x0d\t ]\)[\xa0\x0d\t ]\+\([^\xa0\x0d\t ]\)/\1 \2/g
 " format text
 normal gg
 " convert bad formated umlauts to real characters
 normal :%s/\\\([0-9]*\)/\=nr2char(submatch(1))/g
 normal :%s/&#\([0-9]*\);/\=nr2char(submatch(1))/g
 " break undo sequence
 normal iu
 exec 'silent! /\(^\(On\|In\) .*$\|\(schrieb\|wrote\):$\)/,/^-- $/-1!par '.&tw.'gqs0'
 " place the cursor before my signature
 silent! /^-- $/-1
 " clear search buffer
 let @/ = ""
endfun

" insert selection at mark a
fun! Insert() range
 exe "normal vgvmzomy\<Esc>"
 normal `y
 let lineA = line(".")
 let columnA = col(".")

 normal `z
 let lineB = line(".")
 let columnB = col(".")

 " exchange marks
 if lineA > lineB || lineA <= lineB && columnA > columnB
  " save z in c
  normal mc
  " store y in z
  normal `ymz
  " set y to old z
  normal `cmy
 endif

 exe "normal! gvd`ap`y"
endfun

" search with the selection of the visual mode
fun! VisualSearch(direction) range
 let l:saved_reg = @"
 execute "normal! vgvy"
 let l:pattern = escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')
 let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")
 if a:direction == '#'
  execute "normal! ?" . l:pattern . "^M"
 elseif a:direction == '*'
  execute "normal! /" . l:pattern . "^M"
 elseif a:direction == '/'
  execute "normal! /" . l:pattern
 else
  execute "normal! ?" . l:pattern
 endif
 let @/ = l:pattern
 let @" = l:saved_reg
endfun

" 'Expandvar' expands the variable under the cursor
fun! <SID>Expandvar()
 let origreg = @"
 normal yiW
 if (@" == "@\"")
  let @" = origreg
 else
  let @" = eval(@")
 endif
 normal diW"0p
 let @" = origreg
endfun

" execute the bc calculator
fun! <SID>Bc(exp)
 setlocal paste
 normal mao
 exe ":.!echo 'scale=2; " . a:exp . "' | bc"
 normal 0i "bDdd`a"bp
 setlocal nopaste
endfun

fun! <SID>RFC(number)
 silent exe ":e http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc" . a:number . ".txt"
endfun

" The function Nr2Hex() returns the Hex string of a number.
func! Nr2Hex(nr)
 let n = a:nr
 let r = ""
 while n
  let r = '0123456789ABCDEF'[n % 16] . r
  let n = n / 16
 endwhile
 return r
endfunc

" The function String2Hex() converts each character in a string to a two
" character Hex string.
func! String2Hex(str)
 let out = ''
 let ix = 0
 while ix < strlen(a:str)
  let out = out . Nr2Hex(char2nr(a:str[ix]))
  let ix = ix + 1
 endwhile
 return out
endfunc

" translates hex value to the corresponding number
fun! Hex2Nr(hex)
 let r = 0
 let ix = strlen(a:hex) - 1
 while ix >= 0
  let val = 0
  if a:hex[ix] == '1'
   let val = 1
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '2'
   let val = 2
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '3'
   let val = 3
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '4'
   let val = 4
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '5'
   let val = 5
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '6'
   let val = 6
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '7'
   let val = 7
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '8'
   let val = 8
  elseif a:hex[ix] == '9'
   let val = 9
  elseif a:hex[ix] == 'a' || a:hex[ix] == 'A'
   let val = 10
  elseif a:hex[ix] == 'b' || a:hex[ix] == 'B'
   let val = 11
  elseif a:hex[ix] == 'c' || a:hex[ix] == 'C'
   let val = 12
  elseif a:hex[ix] == 'd' || a:hex[ix] == 'D'
   let val = 13
  elseif a:hex[ix] == 'e' || a:hex[ix] == 'E'
   let val = 14
  elseif a:hex[ix] == 'f' || a:hex[ix] == 'F'
   let val = 15
  endif
  let r = r + val * Power(16, strlen(a:hex) - ix - 1)
  let ix = ix - 1
 endwhile
 return r
endfun

" mathematical power function
fun! Power(base, exp)
 let r = 1
 let exp = a:exp
 while exp > 0
  let r = r * a:base
  let exp = exp - 1
 endwhile
 return r
endfun

" Captialize movent/selection
function! Capitalize(type, ...)
  let sel_save = &selection
  let &selection = "inclusive"
  let reg_save = @@

  if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
 silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
 silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
  elseif a:type == 'block'
 silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]y"
  else
 silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif

  silent exe "normal! `[gu`]~`]"

  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
endfunction

" Find file in current directory and edit it.
function! Find(...)
  let path="."
  if a:0==2
    let path=a:2
  endif
  let l:list=system("find ".path. " -name '".a:1."' | grep -v .svn ")
  let l:num=strlen(substitute(l:list, "[^\n]", "", "g"))
  if l:num < 1
    echo "'".a:1."' not found"
    return
  endif
  if l:num != 1
    let tmpfile = tempname()
    exe "redir! > " . tmpfile
    silent echon l:list
    redir END
    let old_efm = &efm
    set efm=%f

    if exists(":cgetfile")
        execute "silent! cgetfile " . tmpfile
    else
        execute "silent! cfile " . tmpfile
    endif

    let &efm = old_efm

    " Open the quickfix window below the current window
    botright copen

    call delete(tmpfile)
  endif
endfunction

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ---------- Plugin Settings ----------
"
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" hide dotfiles by default - the gh mapping quickly changes this behavior
let g:netrw_list_hide = '\(^\|\s\s\)\zs\.\S\+'

" Do not go to active window.
"let g:bufExplorerFindActive = 0
" Don't show directories.
"let g:bufExplorerShowDirectories = 0
" Sort by full file path name.
"let g:bufExplorerSortBy = 'fullpath'
" Show relative paths.
"let g:bufExplorerShowRelativePath = 1

" don't allow autoinstalling of scripts
let g:GetLatestVimScripts_allowautoinstall = 0

" load manpage-plugin
runtime! ftplugin/man.vim

" load matchit-plugin
runtime! macros/matchit.vim

" minibuf explorer
"let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1
"let g:miniBufExplorerMoreThanOne = 0
"let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 0
"let g:miniBufExplUseSingleClick = 1
"let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavVim = 1
"let g:miniBufExplVSplit = 25
"let g:miniBufExplSplitBelow = 1
"let g:miniBufExplForceSyntaxEnable = 1
"let g:miniBufExplTabWrap = 1

" calendar plugin
" let g:calendar_weeknm = 4

" xml-ftplugin configuration
let xml_use_xhtml = 1

" :ToHTML
let html_number_lines = 1
let html_use_css = 1
let use_xhtml = 1

" LatexSuite
"let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
"let g:Tex_Diacritics = 1

" python-highlightings
let python_highlight_all = 1

" Eclim settings
"let org.eclim.user.name     = g:tskelUserName
"let org.eclim.user.email    = g:tskelUserEmail
"let g:EclimLogLevel         = 4 " info
"let g:EclimBrowser          = "x-www-browser"
"let g:EclimShowCurrentError = 1
" nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <tab> :call eclim#util#FillTemplate("${", "}")<CR>
" nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <leader>i :JavaImport<CR>
" nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <leader>d :JavaDocSearch -x declarations<CR>
" nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <CR> :JavaSearchContext<CR>
" nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <CR> :AntDoc<CR>

" quickfix notes plugin
map <Leader>n <Plug>QuickFixNote
nnoremap <F6> :QFNSave ~/.vimquickfix/
nnoremap <S-F6> :e ~/.vimquickfix/
nnoremap <F7> :cgetfile ~/.vimquickfix/
nnoremap <S-F7> :caddfile ~/.vimquickfix/
nnoremap <S-F8> :!rm ~/.vimquickfix/

" EnhancedCommentify updated keybindings
vmap <Leader><Space> <Plug>VisualTraditional
nmap <Leader><Space> <Plug>Traditional
let g:EnhCommentifyTraditionalMode = 'No'
let g:EnhCommentifyPretty = 'No'
let g:EnhCommentifyRespectIndent = 'Yes'

" FuzzyFinder keybinding
nnoremap <leader>fb :FufBuffer<CR>
nnoremap <leader>fd :FufDir<CR>
nnoremap <leader>fD :FufDir <C-r>=expand('%:~:.:h').'/'<CR><CR>
nmap <leader>Fd <leader>fD
nmap <leader>FD <leader>fD
nnoremap <leader>ff :FufFile<CR>
nnoremap <leader>fF :FufFile <C-r>=expand('%:~:.:h').'/'<CR><CR>
nmap <leader>FF <leader>fF
nnoremap <leader>ft :FufTextMate<CR>
nnoremap <leader>fr :FufRenewCache<CR>
"let g:FuzzyFinderOptions = {}
"let g:FuzzyFinderOptions = { 'Base':{}, 'Buffer':{}, 'File':{}, 'Dir':{},
   "\                      'MruFile':{}, 'MruCmd':{}, 'Bookmark':{},
   "\                      'Tag':{}, 'TaggedFile':{},
   "\                      'GivenFile':{}, 'GivenDir':{}, 'GivenCmd':{},
   "\                      'CallbackFile':{}, 'CallbackItem':{}, }
let g:fuf_onelinebuf_location  = 'botright'
let g:fuf_maxMenuWidth     = 300
let g:fuf_file_exclude     = '\v\~$|\.o$|\.exe$|\.bak$|\.swp$|((^|[/\\])\.[/\\]$)|\.pyo|\.pyc|autom4te\.cache|blib|_build|\.bzr|\.cdv|cover_db|CVS|_darcs|\~\.dep|\~\.dot|\.git|\.hg|\~\.nib|\.pc|\~\.plst|RCS|SCCS|_sgbak|\.svn'

" YankRing
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :YRShow<CR>
let g:yankring_history_file = '.yankring_history_file'
let g:yankring_replace_n_pkey = '<c-\>'
let g:yankring_replace_n_nkey = '<c-m>'

" supertab
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"

" TagList
let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1

" UltiSnips
"let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = "<tab>"
"let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = "<S-tab>"

" NERD Commenter
nmap <leader><space> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
vmap <leader><space> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
imap <C-c> <ESC>:call NERDComment(0, "insert")<CR>

" disable unused Mark mappings
nmap <leader>_r <plug>MarkRegex
vmap <leader>_r <plug>MarkRegex
nmap <leader>_n <plug>MarkClear
vmap <leader>_n <plug>MarkClear
nmap <leader>_* <plug>MarkSearchCurrentNext
nmap <leader>_# <plug>MarkSearchCurrentPrev
nmap <leader>_/ <plug>MarkSearchAnyNext
nmap <leader>_# <plug>MarkSearchAnyPrev
nmap <leader>__* <plug>MarkSearchNext
nmap <leader>__# <plug>MarkSearchPrev

" Nerd Tree explorer mapping
nmap <leader>e :NERDTree<CR>

" TaskList settings
let g:tlWindowPosition = 1

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ---------- Keymappings ----------
"
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" edit/reload .vimrc-Configuration
nnoremap gce :e $HOME/.vimrc<CR>
nnoremap gcl :source $HOME/.vimrc<CR>:echo "Configuration reloaded"<CR>

" un/hightlight current line
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>H :match<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>h mk:exe 'match Search /<Bslash>%'.line(".").'l/'<CR>

" spellcheck off, german, englisch
nnoremap gsg :setlocal invspell spelllang=de<CR>
nnoremap gse :setlocal invspell spelllang=en<CR>

" switch to previous/next buffer
nnoremap <silent> <c-p> :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <c-n> :bnext<CR>

" kill/delete trailing spaces and tabs
nnoremap <Leader>kt msHmt:silent! %s/[\t \x0d]\+$//g<CR>:let @/ = ""<CR>:echo "Deleted trailing spaces"<CR>'tzt`s
vnoremap <Leader>kt :s/[\t \x0d]\+$//g<CR>:let @/ = ""<CR>:echo "Deleted trailing, spaces"<CR>

" kill/reduce inner spaces and tabs to a single space/tab
nnoremap <Leader>ki msHmt:silent! %s/\([^\xa0\x0d\t ]\)[\xa0\x0d\t ]\+\([^\xa0\x0d\t ]\)/\1 \2/g<CR>:let @/ = ""<CR>:echo "Deleted inner spaces"<CR>'tzt`s
vnoremap <Leader>ki :s/\([^\xa0\x0d\t ]\)[\xa0\x0d\t ]\+\([^\xa0\x0d\t ]\)/\1 \2/g<CR>:let @/ = ""<CR>:echo "Deleted inner spaces"<CR>

" start new undo sequences when using certain commands in insert mode
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>
inoremap <C-W> <C-G>u<C-W>
inoremap <BS> <C-G>u<BS>
inoremap <C-H> <C-G>u<C-H>
inoremap <Del> <C-G>u<Del>

" swap two words
" http://www.vim.org/tips/tip.php?tip_id=329
nmap <silent> gw "_yiw:s/\(\%#[ÄÖÜäöüßa-zA-Z0-9]\+\)\(\_W\+\)\([ÄÖÜäöüßa-zA-Z0-9]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o><C-l>:let @/ = ""<CR>
nmap <silent> gW "_yiW:s/\(\%#[ÄÖÜäöüßa-zA-Z0-9-+*_]\+\)\(\_W\+\)\([ÄÖÜäöüßa-zA-Z0-9-+*_]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o><C-l>:let @/ = ""<CR>

" Capitalize movement
nnoremap <silent> gC :set opfunc=Capitalize<CR>g@
vnoremap <silent> gC :<C-U>call Capitalize(visualmode(), 1)<CR>

" delete search-register
nnoremap <silent> <leader>/ :let @/ = ""<CR>

" browse current buffer/selection in www-browser
nnoremap <Leader>b :!x-www-browser %:p<CR>:echo "WWW-Browser started"<CR>
vnoremap <Leader>b y:!x-www-browser <C-R>"<CR>:echo "WWW-Browser started"<CR>

" lookup/translate inner/selected word in dictionary
" recode is only needed for non-utf-8-text
" nnoremap <Leader>T mayiw`a:exe "!dict -P - -- $(echo " . @" . "\| recode latin1..utf-8)"<CR>
"nnoremap <Leader>t mayiw`a:exe "!dict -P - -- " . @"<CR>
" vnoremap <Leader>T may`a:exe "!dict -P - -- $(echo " . @" . "\| recode latin1..utf-8)"<CR>
"vnoremap <Leader>t may`a:exe "!dict -P - -- " . @"<CR>

" delete words in insert mode like expected - doesn't work properly at
" the end of the line
inoremap <C-BS> <C-w>

" Switch buffers
nnoremap <silent> [b :ls<Bar>let nr = input("Buffer: ")<Bar>if nr != ''<Bar>exe ":b " . nr<Bar>endif<CR>
" Search for the occurence of the word under the cursor
nnoremap <silent> [I [I:le
```

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/elventails/vim/blob/master/vimrc

Has extras for CakePHP/PHP/Git

enjoy!

Will add nice options you guys are using to it and update the repo;

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this comes from the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) btw.

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
set nobackup
set tabstop=4
set nowrap

set guifont=Droid_Sans_Mono:h9:cANSI
colorscheme torte
set shiftwidth=4
set ic
syn off
set nohls
set acd
set autowrite
noremap \c "+yy
noremap \x "+dd
noremap \t :tabnew<CR>
noremap \2 I"<Esc>A"<Esc>
noremap \3 bi'<Esc>ea'<Esc>
noremap \" i"<Esc>ea"<Esc>
noremap ?2 Bi"<Esc>Ea"<Esc>
set matchpairs+=<:>
nnoremap <C-N> :next<CR>
nnoremap <C-P> :prev<CR>
nnoremap <Tab> :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <S-Tab> :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap \w :let @/=expand("<cword>")<Bar>split<Bar>normal n<CR>
nnoremap \W :let @/='\<'.expand("<cword>").'\>'<Bar>split<Bar>normal n<CR>

autocmd FileType xml exe ":silent %!xmllint --format --recover - "
autocmd FileType cpp set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab autoindent smarttab
autocmd FileType sql set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab autoindent smarttab

" Map key to toggle opt
function MapToggle(key, opt)
  let cmd = ':set '.a:opt.'! \| set '.a:opt."?\<CR>"
  exec 'nnoremap '.a:key.' '.cmd
  exec 'inoremap '.a:key." \<C-O>".cmd
endfunction
command -nargs=+ MapToggle call MapToggle(<f-args>)

map <F6> :if exists("syntax_on") <Bar> syntax off <Bar> else <Bar> syntax enable <Bar> endif <CR>

" Display-altering option toggles
MapToggle <F7> hlsearch
MapToggle <F8> wrap
MapToggle <F9> list

" Behavior-altering option toggles
MapToggle <F10> scrollbind
MapToggle <F11> ignorecase
MapToggle <F12> paste
set pastetoggle=<F12>
```

Answer (score 0):

The super money part from my .vimrc is how it shows a "»" character each place there's a tab, and how it highlights "bad" whitespace in red. Bad whitespace is stuff like tabs in the middle of a line or invisible spaces at the end.

```
syntax enable

" Incremental search without highlighting.
set incsearch
set nohlsearch

" Show ruler.
set ruler

" Try to keep 2 lines above/below the current line in view for context.
set scrolloff=2

" Other file types.
autocmd BufReadPre,BufNew *.xml set filetype=xml

" Flag problematic whitespace (trailing spaces, spaces before tabs).
highlight BadWhitespace term=standout ctermbg=red guibg=red
match BadWhitespace /[^* \t]\zs\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/

" If using ':set list' show things nicer.
execute 'set listchars=tab:' . nr2char(187) . '\ '
set list
highlight Tab ctermfg=lightgray guifg=lightgray
2match Tab /\t/

" Indent settings for code: 4 spaces, do not use tab character.
"set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 autoindent smartindent shiftround
"autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,xml,python,cs setlocal expandtab softtabstop=4
"autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,xml,python,cs 2match BadWhitespace /[^\t]\zs\t/
set tabstop=8 shiftwidth=4 autoindent smartindent shiftround
set expandtab softtabstop=4
2match BadWhitespace /[^\t]\zs\t\+/

" Automatically show matching brackets.
set showmatch

" Auto-complete file names after <TAB> like bash does.
set wildmode=longest,list
set wildignore=.svn,CVS,*.swp

" Show current mode and currently-typed command.
set showmode
set showcmd

" Use mouse if possible.
" set mouse=a

" Use Ctrl-N and Ctrl-P to move between files.
nnoremap <C-N> :confirm next<Enter>
nnoremap <C-P> :confirm prev<Enter>

" Confirm saving and quitting.
set confirm

" So yank behaves like delete, i.e. Y = D.
map Y y$

" Toggle paste mode with F5.
set pastetoggle=<F5>

" Don't exit visual mode when shifting.
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv

" Move up and down by visual lines not buffer lines.
nnoremap <Up>   gk
vnoremap <Up>   gk
nnoremap <Down> gj
vnoremap <Down> gj
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't live without TAB Completion

```
" Intelligent tab completion
inoremap <silent> <Tab> <C-r>=<SID>InsertTabWrapper(1)<CR>
inoremap <silent> <S-Tab> <C-r>=<SID>InsertTabWrapper(-1)<CR>

function! <SID>InsertTabWrapper(direction)
    let idx = col('.') - 1
    let str = getline('.')

    if a:direction > 0 && idx >= 2 && str[idx - 1] == ' '
                \&& str[idx - 2] =~? '[a-z]'
        if &softtabstop && idx % &softtabstop == 0
            return "\<BS>\<Tab>\<Tab>"
        else
            return "\<BS>\<Tab>"
        endif
    elseif idx == 0 || str[idx - 1] !~? '[a-z]'
        return "\<Tab>"
    elseif a:direction > 0
        return "\<C-p>"
    else
        return "\<C-n>"
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function that automatically sends your text to a private pastebin.

```
let g:pfx='' " prefix for private pastebin.

function PBSubmit()
python << EOF
import vim
import urllib2 as url
import urllib

pfx = vim.eval( 'g:pfx' )

URL = 'http://'

if pfx == '':
    URL += 'pastebin.com/pastebin.php'
else:
    URL += pfx + '.pastebin.com/pastebin.php'

data = urllib.urlencode( {  'code2': '\n'.join( vim.current.buffer ).decode( 'utf-8' ).encode( 'latin-1' ),
                            'email': '',
                            'expiry': 'd',
                            'format': 'text',
                            'parent_pid': '',
                            'paste': 'Send',
                            'poster': '' } )

url.urlopen( URL, data )

print 'Submitted to ' + URL
EOF
endfunction

map <Leader>pb :call PBSubmit()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite bit of my .vimrc is a set of mappings for working with macros:

```
nnoremap <Leader>qa mqGo<Esc>"ap
nnoremap <Leader>qb mqGo<Esc>"bp
nnoremap <Leader>qc mqGo<Esc>"cp
<SNIP>
nnoremap <Leader>qz mqGo<Esc>"zp

nnoremap <Leader>Qa G0"ad$dd'q
nnoremap <Leader>Qb G0"bd$dd'q
nnoremap <Leader>Qc G0"cd$dd'q
<SNIP>
nnoremap <Leader>Qz G0"zd$dd'q
```

With this \q[a-z] will mark your location, and print the contents of the given register at the bottom of the current file and \Q[a-z] will put the contents of the last line into the given register and go back to your marked location.  Makes it really easy to edit a macro or copy and tweak one macro into a new register.

Answer (score 0):

My [.vimrc](http://hackr.se/vim/vimrc), the plugins i use and other tweaks are customized to help me with the tasks i preform most frequently:

- Use Mutt/Vim to read/write emails
- Write C code under GNU/Linux, usually with glib, gobject, gstreamer
- Browse/Read C source code
- Work with Python, Ruby on Rails or Bash scripts
- Develop web applications with HTML, Javascript, CSS

I have some more info about my [Vim configuration here](http://hackr.se/vim/vim-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

Some of my favorite customizations that I haven't found to be all too common:

```
" Windows *********************************************************************"
set equalalways           " Multiple windows, when created, are equal in size"
set splitbelow splitright " Put the new windows to the right/bottom"

" Insert new line in command mode *********************************************"
map <S-Enter> O<ESC> " Insert above current line"
map <Enter> o<ESC>   " Insert below current line"

" After selecting something in visual mode and shifting, I still want that"
" selection intact ************************************************************"
vmap > >gv
vmap < <gv
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `~/.vim/after/syntax/vim.vim` file:

What it does is:

- highlights the word blue in the color blue
- highlights the wrod red in the color red
- etc

Ie: so if you go:

```
highlight JakeRedKeywords cterm=bold term=bold ctermbg=black ctermfg=Red
```

The word red will be red and the word black will be black.

Here is the code:

```
syn cluster vimHiCtermColors contains=vimHiCtermColorBlack,vimHiCtermColorBlue,vimHiCtermColorBrown,vimHiCtermColorCyan,vimHiCtermColorDarkBlue,vimHiCtermColorDarkcyan,vimHiCtermColorDarkgray,vimHiCtermColorDarkgreen,vimHiCtermColorDarkgrey,vimHiCtermColorDarkmagenta,vimHiCtermColorDarkred,vimHiCtermColorDarkyellow,vimHiCtermColorGray,vimHiCtermColorGreen,vimHiCtermColorGrey,vimHiCtermColorLightblue,vimHiCtermColorLightcyan,vimHiCtermColorLightgray,vimHiCtermColorLightgreen,vimHiCtermColorLightgrey,vimHiCtermColorLightmagenta,vimHiCtermColorLightred,vimHiCtermColorMagenta,vimHiCtermColorRed,vimHiCtermColorWhite,vimHiCtermColorYellow

syn case ignore

syn keyword vimHiCtermColorYellow yellow contained 
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorBlack black contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorBlue blue contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorBrown brown contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorCyan cyan contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkBlue darkBlue contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkcyan darkcyan contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkgray darkgray contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkgreen darkgreen contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkgrey darkgrey contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkmagenta darkmagenta contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkred darkred contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorDarkyellow darkyellow contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorGray gray contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorGreen green contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorGrey grey contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorLightblue lightblue contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorLightcyan lightcyan contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorLightgray lightgray contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorLightgreen lightgreen contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorLightgrey lightgrey contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorLightmagenta lightmagenta contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorLightred lightred contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorMagenta magenta contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorRed red contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorWhite white contained
syn keyword vimHiCtermColorYellow yellow contained

syn match  vimHiCtermFgBg   contained   "\ccterm[fb]g="he=e-1  nextgroup=vimNumber,@vimHiCtermColors,vimFgBgAttrib,vimHiCtermError

highlight vimHiCtermColorBlack ctermfg=black ctermbg=white
highlight vimHiCtermColorBlue ctermfg=blue
highlight vimHiCtermColorBrown ctermfg=brown
highlight vimHiCtermColorCyan ctermfg=cyan
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkBlue ctermfg=darkBlue
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkcyan ctermfg=darkcyan
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkgray ctermfg=darkgray
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkgreen ctermfg=darkgreen
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkgrey ctermfg=darkgrey
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkmagenta ctermfg=darkmagenta
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkred ctermfg=darkred
highlight vimHiCtermColorDarkyellow ctermfg=darkyellow
highlight vimHiCtermColorGray ctermfg=gray
highlight vimHiCtermColorGreen ctermfg=green
highlight vimHiCtermColorGrey ctermfg=grey
highlight vimHiCtermColorLightblue ctermfg=lightblue
highlight vimHiCtermColorLightcyan ctermfg=lightcyan
highlight vimHiCtermColorLightgray ctermfg=lightgray
highlight vimHiCtermColorLightgreen ctermfg=lightgreen
highlight vimHiCtermColorLightgrey ctermfg=lightgrey
highlight vimHiCtermColorLightmagenta ctermfg=lightmagenta
highlight vimHiCtermColorLightred ctermfg=lightred
highlight vimHiCtermColorMagenta ctermfg=magenta
highlight vimHiCtermColorRed ctermfg=red
highlight vimHiCtermColorWhite ctermfg=white
highlight vimHiCtermColorYellow ctermfg=yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine ! Thanks for sharing. You can find other stuff about vim plugins here: http://github.com/ametaireau/dotfiles/

Hope it helps.

```
" My .vimrc configuration file.
" =============================
"
" Plugins
" -------
" Comes with a set of utilities to enhance the user experience.
" Django and python snippets are possible thanks to the snipmate
" plugin.
"
" A also uses taglist and NERDTree vim plugins.
"
" Shortcuts
" ----------
" Here are some shortcuts I like to use when editing text using VIM:
"
" <alt-left/right> to navigate trough tabs
" <ctrl-e> to display the explorator
" <ctrl-p> for the code explorator
" <ctrl-space> to autocomplete
" <ctrl-n> enter tabnew to open a new file
" <alt-h> highlight the lines of more than 80 columns
" <ctrl-h> set textwith to 80 cols
" <maj-k> when on a python file, open the related pydoc documentation
" ,v and ,V to show/edit and reload the vimrc configuration file

colorscheme evening 
syntax on                       " syntax highlighting
filetype on                     " to consider filetypes ...
filetype plugin on              " ... and in plugins
set directory=~/.vim/swp        " store the .swp files in a specific path
set expandtab                   " enter spaces when tab is pressed
set tabstop=4                   " use 4 spaces to represent tab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4                " number of spaces to use for auto indent
set autoindent                  " copy indent from current line on new line
set number                      " show line numbers
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " make backspaces more powerful 
set ruler                       " show line and column number
set showcmd                     " show (partial) command in status line
set incsearch                   " highlight search
set noignorecase
set infercase
set nowrap

" shortcuts
map <c-n> :tabnew 
map <silent><c-e> :NERDTreeToggle <cr>
map <silent><c-p> :TlistToggle <cr>
nnoremap <a-right> gt
nnoremap <a-left>  gT
command W w !sudo tee % > /dev/null
map <buffer> K :execute "!pydoc " . expand("<cword>")<CR>
map <F2> :set textwidth=80 <cr>
" Replace trailing slashes
map <F3> :%s/\s\+$//<CR>:exe ":echo'trailing slashes removes'"<CR>
map <silent><F6> :QFix<CR>

" edit vim quickly
map ,v :sp ~/.vimrc<CR><C-W>_
map <silent> ,V :source ~/.vimrc<CR>:filetype detect<CR>:exe ":echo'vimrc reloaded'"<CR> 

" configure expanding of tabs for various file types
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set expandtab
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.c set noexpandtab
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.h set noexpandtab
au BufRead,BufNewFile Makefile* set noexpandtab

" remap CTRL+N to CTRL + space
inoremap <Nul> <C-n>

" Omnifunc completers
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete

" Tlist configuration
let Tlist_GainFocus_On_ToggleOpen = 1
let Tlist_Close_On_Select = 0
let Tlist_Auto_Update = 1
let Tlist_Process_File_Always = 1
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
let Tlist_WinWidth = 40
let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1
let Tlist_Show_Menu = 0
let Tlist_File_Fold_Auto_Close = 0
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = '/usr/bin/ctags'
let tlist_css_settings = 'css;e:SECTIONS'

" NerdTree configuration
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['\.pyc$', '\.pyo$']

" Highlight more than 80 columns lines on demand
nnoremap <silent><F1>
\    :if exists('w:long_line_match') <Bar>
\        silent! call matchdelete(w:long_line_match) <Bar>
\        unlet w:long_line_match <Bar>
\    elseif &textwidth > 0 <Bar>
\        let w:long_line_match = matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>'.&tw.'v.\+', -1) <Bar>
\    else <Bar>
\        let w:long_line_match = matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1) <Bar>
\    endif<CR>

command -bang -nargs=? QFix call QFixToggle(<bang>0)
function! QFixToggle(forced)
  if exists("g:qfix_win") && a:forced == 0
    cclose
    unlet g:qfix_win
  else
    copen 10
    let g:qfix_win = bufnr("$")
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"{{{1 Защита от множественных загрузок 
if exists("b:dollarHOMEslashdotvimrcFileLoaded")
    finish
endif
let b:dollarHOMEslashdotvimrcFileLoaded=1
" set t_Co=8
" set t_Sf=[3%p1%dm
" set t_Sb=[4%p1%dm
"{{{1 Options 
"{{{2 set 
set nocompatible
set background=dark
set display+=lastline
"set iminsert=0
"set imsearch=0
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set autoindent
set nosmartindent
set backup
set conskey
set bioskey
set browsedir=buffer
" bomb may work bad
set nobomb
exe "set backupdir=".$HOME."/.vimbackup,."
set backupext=~
set history=32
set ruler
set showcmd
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set nocindent
set textwidth=80
set complete=.,i,d,t,w,b,u,k
" set conskey
set noconfirm
set cscopetag
set cscopetagorder=1
" set copyindent
" !may be not safe
set exrc
set secure
" set foldclose
set noswapfile
" set swapsync=sync
set fsync
set guicursor="a:block-blinkoff0"
set autowriteall
set hidden
set nojoinspaces
set nostartofline
" set virtualedit+=onemore
set lazyredraw
set visualbell
set makeef=make.##.err.log
set modelines=16
set more
set virtualedit+=block
set winaltkeys=no
set fileencodings=utf-8,cp1251,koi8-r,default
set encoding=utf-8
set list
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:-,nbsp:_
set magic
set pastetoggle=<F1>
set foldmethod=marker
set wildmenu
set wildcharm=<Tab>
set formatoptions=arcoqn12w
"set formatoptions+=t
set scrolloff=2

"{{{3 define keys
"{{{4 get keys from zkbd
if isdirectory($HOME."/.zkbd") &&
  \filereadable($HOME."/.zkbd/".$TERM."-pc-linux-gnu")
    let s:keys=split(system("cat ".
                \shellescape($HOME."/.zkbd/".$TERM."-pc-linux-gnu").
                \" | grep \"^key\\\\[\" | ".
                \"sed -re \"s/^key\\\\[([[:alnum:]]*)\\\\]='(.*)'\\$".
                           \"/\\\\1=\\\\2/g\""), "\\n")
    for key in s:keys
        let tmp=split(key, "=")
        if tmp[0]=~"^F\\d\\+$"
            execute "set <".tmp[0].">=".
                        \substitute(tmp[1], "\\^\\[", "\<ESC>", "g")
        endif
    endfor
endif
" function g:DefineKeys()
    "{{{4 screen
    if 0 && $_SECONDLAUNCH
        set    <F1>=[11~
        set    <F2>=[12~
        set    <F3>=[13~
        set    <F4>=[14~
        set    <F5>=[15~
        set    <F6>=[17~
        set    <F7>=[18~
        set    <F8>=[19~
        set    <F9>=[20~
        set   <F10>=[21~
        set   <F11>=[23~
        set   <F12>=[24~
        set  <S-F1>=[23~
        set  <S-F2>=[24~
        set  <S-F3>=[25~
        set  <S-F4>=[26~
        set  <S-F5>=[28~
        set  <S-F6>=[29~
        set  <S-F7>=[31~
        set  <S-F8>=[32~
        set  <S-F9>=[33~
        set <S-F10>=[34~
        set <S-F11>=[23$
        set <S-F12>=[24$
        set  <HOME>=[7~
        set   <END>=[8~
    "{{{4 xterm 
    elseif $TERM=="xterm"
        set      <M-a>=a
        set      <M-b>=b
        set      <M-c>=c
        set      <M-d>=d
        set      <M-e>=e
        set      <M-f>=f
        set      <M-g>=g
        set      <M-h>=h
        set      <M-i>=i
        set      <M-j>=j
        set      <M-k>=k
        set      <M-l>=l
        set      <M-m>=m
        set      <M-n>=n
        set      <M-o>=o
        set      <M-p>=p
        set      <M-q>=q
        set      <M-r>=r
        set      <M-s>=s
        set      <M-t>=t
        set      <M-u>=u
        set      <M-v>=v
        set      <M-w>=w
        set      <M-x>=x
        set      <M-y>=y
        set      <M-z>=z
        "set <M-SPACE>= 
        "set    <Left>=OD
        "set  <S-Left>=O2D
        "set  <C-Left>=O5D
        "set   <Right>=OC
        "set <S-Right>=O2C
        "set <C-Right>=O5C
        "set      <Up>=OA
        "set    <S-Up>=O2A
        "set    <C-Up>=O5A
        "set    <Down>=OB
        "set  <S-Down>=O2B
        "set  <C-Down>=O5B
        set       <F1>=[11~
        set       <F2>=[12~
        set       <F3>=[13~
        set       <F4>=[14~
        set       <F5>=[15~
        set       <F6>=[17~
        set       <F7>=[18~
        set       <F8>=[19~
        set       <F9>=[20~
        set      <F10>=[21~
        set      <F11>=[23~
        set      <F12>=[24~
        "set    <C-F1>=
        "set    <C-F2>=
        "set    <C-F3>=
        "set    <C-F4>=
        "set    <C-F5>=[15;5~
        "set    <C-F6>=[17;5~
        "
        "set    <C-F7>=[18;5~
        "set    <C-F8>=[19;5~
        "set    <C-F9>=[20;5~
        "set   <C-F10>=[21;5~
        "set   <C-F11>=[23;5~
        "set   <C-F12>=[24;5~
        set     <S-F1>=[11;2~
        set     <S-F2>=[12;2~
        set     <S-F3>=[13;2~
        set     <S-F4>=[14;2~
        set     <S-F5>=[15;2~
        set     <S-F6>=[17;2~
        set     <S-F7>=[18;2~
        set     <S-F8>=[19;2~
        set     <S-F9>=[20;2~
        set    <S-F10>=[21;2~
        set    <S-F11>=[23;2~
        set    <S-F12>=[24;2~
        set      <END>=OF
        set    <S-END>=O2F
        set   <S-HOME>=O2H
        set     <HOME>=OH
        set      <DEL>=
        " set   <PageUp>=[5~
        " set <PageDown>=[6~
        "  noremap  <DEL>
        " inoremap  <DEL>
        " cnoremap  <DEL>
        set    <S-Del>=[3;2~
        " set   <C-Del>=[3;5~
        " set   <M-Del>=[3;3~
    "{{{4 rxvt --- aterm
    elseif $TERM=="rxvt"
        set      <M-a>=a
        set      <M-b>=b
        set      <M-c>=c
        set      <M-d>=d
        set      <M-e>=e
        set      <M-f>=f
        set      <M-g>=g
        set      <M-h>=h
        set      <M-i>=i
        set      <M-j>=j
        set      <M-k>=k
        set      <M-l>=l
        set      <M-m>=m
        set      <M-n>=n
        set      <M-o>=o
        set      <M-p>=p
        set      <M-q>=q
        set      <M-r>=r
        set      <M-s>=s
        set      <M-t>=t
        set      <M-u>=u
        set      <M-v>=v
        set      <M-w>=w
        set      <M-x>=x
        set      <M-y>=y
        set      <M-z>=z
        set       <F1>=OP
        set       <F2>=OQ
        set       <F3>=OR
        set       <F4>=OS
        set       <F5>=[15~
        set       <F6>=[17~
        set       <F7>=[18~
        set       <F8>=[19~
        set       <F9>=[20~
        set      <F10>=[21~
        set      <F11>=[23~
        set      <F12>=[24~
        set     <S-F1>=[23~
        set     <S-F2>=[24~
        set     <S-F3>=[25~
        set     <S-F4>=[26~
        set     <S-F5>=[28~
        set     <S-F6>=[29~
        set     <S-F7>=[31~
        set     <S-F8>=[32~
        set     <S-F9>=[33~
        set    <S-F10>=[34~
        set    <S-F11>=[23$
        set    <S-F12>=[24$
        " set  <C-S-F2>=[24^
        " set  <C-S-F3>=[25^
        " set  <C-S-F4>=[26^
        " set  <C-S-F5>=[28^
        " set  <C-S-F6>=[29^
        " set  <C-S-F7>=[31^
        " set  <C-S-F8>=[32^
        " set  <C-S-F9>=[33^
        " set <C-S-F10>=[34^
        " set <C-S-F11>=[23@
        " set <C-S-F12>=[24@
        " set    <M-F5>=<F5>
        " set    <M-F6>=<F6>
        " set    <M-F7>=<F7>
        " set    <M-F8>=<F8>
        " set    <M-F9>=<F9>
        " set   <M-F10>=<F10>
        " set   <M-F11>=<F11>
        " set   <M-F12>=<F12>
        " set  <M-S-F5>=<S-F5>
        " set  <M-S-F6>=<S-F6>
        " set  <M-S-F7>=<S-F7>
        " set  <M-S-F8>=<S-F8>
        " set  <M-S-F9>=<S-F9>
        " set <M-S-F10>=<S-F10>
        " set <M-S-F11>=<S-F11>
        " set <M-S-F12>=<S-F12>
    "{{{4 rxvt-unicode --- urxvt
    elseif $TERM=="rxvt-unicode"
        set      <M-a>=a
        set      <M-b>=b
        set      <M-c>=c
        set      <M-d>=d
        set      <M-e>=e
        set      <M-f>=f
        set      <M-g>=g
        set      <M-h>=h
        set      <M-i>=i
        set      <M-j>=j
        set      <M-k>=k
        set      <M-l>=l
        set      <M-m>=m
        set      <M-n>=n
        set      <M-o>=o
        set      <M-p>=p
        set      <M-q>=q
        set      <M-r>=r
        set      <M-s>=s
        set      <M-t>=t
        set      <M-u>=u
        set      <M-v>=v
        set      <M-w>=w
        set      <M-x>=x
        set      <M-y>=y
        set      <M-z>=z
        set       <F1>=[11~
        set       <F2>=[12~
        set       <F3>=[13~
        set       <F4>=[14~
        set       <F5>=[15~
        set       <F6>=[17~
        set       <F7>=[18~
        set       <F8>=[19~
        set       <F9>=[20~
        set      <F10>=[21~
        set      <F11>=[23~
        set      <F12>=[24~
        " fluxbox!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        set     <S-F1>=[23~
        set     <S-F2>=[24~
        set     <S-F3>=[25~
        set     <S-F4>=[26~
        set     <S-F5>=[28~
        set     <S-F6>=[29~
        set     <S-F7>=[31~
        set     <S-F8>=[32~
        set     <S-F9>=[33~
        set    <S-F10>=[34~
        set    <S-F11>=[23$
        set    <S-F12>=[24$
        " set    <C-F1>=[11^
        " set    <C-F2>=[12^
        " set    <C-F3>=[13^
        " set    <C-F4>=[14^
        " set    <C-F5>=[15^
        " set    <C-F6>=[17^
        " set    <C-F7>=[18^
        " set    <C-F8>=[19^
        " set    <C-F9>=[20^
        " set   <C-F10>=[21^
        " set   <C-F11>=[23^
        " set   <C-F12>=[24^
        " openbox!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        " set    <S-F1>=[23~
        " set    <S-F2>=[24~
        " set    <S-F3>=[25~
        " set    <S-F4>=[26~
        " set    <S-F5>=[28~
        " set    <S-F6>=[29~
        " set    <S-F7>=[31~
        " set    <S-F8>=[32~
        " set    <S-F9>=[33~
        " set   <S-F10>=[34~
        " set   <S-F11>=[23$
        " set   <S-F12>=[24$
        " set  <C-S-F2>=[24^
        " set  <C-S-F3>=[25^
        " set  <C-S-F4>=[26^
        " set  <C-S-F5>=[28^
        " set  <C-S-F6>=[29^
        " set  <C-S-F7>=[31^
        " set  <C-S-F8>=[32^
        " set  <C-S-F9>=[33^
        " set <C-S-F10>=[34^
        " set <C-S-F11>=[23@
        " set <C-S-F12>=[24@
        " set    <M-F5>=<F5>
        " set    <M-F6>=<F6>
        " set    <M-F7>=<F7>
        " set    <M-F8>=<F8>
        " set    <M-F9>=<F9>
        " set   <M-F10>=<F10>
        " set   <M-F11>=<F11>
        " set   <M-F12>=<F12>
        " set  <M-S-F5>=<S-F5>
        " set  <M-S-F6>=<S-F6>
        " set  <M-S-F7>=<S-F7>
        " set  <M-S-F8>=<S-F8>
        " set  <M-S-F9>=<S-F9>
        " set <M-S-F10>=<S-F10>
        " set <M-S-F11>=<S-F11>
        " set <M-S-F12>=<S-F12>
    endif
    " autocmd! DefineKeys
" endfunction
" "{{{4 autocmd 
" augroup DefineKeys
" autocmd BufEnter * call g:DefineKeys()
" augroup END

"{{{2 filetipe 
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

"{{{2 let 
"{{{ NERDCommenter 
let           NERDShutUp=1
let      NERDSpaceDelims=1
"}}}
let g:c_syntax_for_h=1
let g:xml_syntax_folding=1
let           paste_mode=0 " 0 = normal, 1 = paste
"{{{3 keys if $TERM=="rxvt-unicode"
    " " fluxbox!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    " let    g:C_F1="\<ESC>[11^"
    " let    g:C_F2="\<ESC>[12^"
    " let    g:C_F3="\<ESC>[13^"
    " let    g:C_F4="\<ESC>[14^"
    " let    g:C_F5="\<ESC>[15^"
    " let    g:C_F6="\<ESC>[17^"
    " let    g:C_F7="\<ESC>[18^"
    " let    g:C_F8="\<ESC>[19^"
    " let    g:C_F9="\<ESC>[20^"
    " let   g:C_F10="\<ESC>[21^"
    " let   g:C_F11="\<ESC>[23^"
    " let   g:C_F12="\<ESC>[24^"
    " let  g:M_S_F1="\<ESC>\<ESC>[23$"
    " let  g:M_S_F2="\<ESC>\<ESC>[24$"
    " let  g:M_S_F3="\<ESC>\<ESC>[25$"
    " let  g:M_S_F4="\<ESC>\<ESC>[26$"
    " let  g:M_S_F5="\<ESC>\<ESC>[28$"
    " let  g:M_S_F6="\<ESC>\<ESC>[29$"
    " let  g:M_S_F7="\<ESC>\<ESC>[31$"
    " let  g:M_S_F8="\<ESC>\<ESC>[32$"
    " let  g:M_S_F9="\<ESC>\<ESC>[33$"
    " let g:M_S_F10="\<ESC>\<ESC>[34$"
    " let g:M_S_F11="\<ESC>\<ESC>[23$"
    " let g:M_S_F12="\<ESC>\<ESC>[24$"
    " let  g:M_C_F1="\<ESC>\<ESC>[11^"
    " let  g:M_C_F2="\<ESC>\<ESC>[12^"
    " let  g:M_C_F3="\<ESC>\<ESC>[13^"
    " let  g:M_C_F4="\<ESC>\<ESC>[14^"
    " let  g:M_C_F5="\<ESC>\<ESC>[15^"
    " let  g:M_C_F6="\<ESC>\<ESC>[17^"
    " let  g:M_C_F7="\<ESC>\<ESC>[18^"
    " let  g:M_C_F8="\<ESC>\<ESC>[19^"
    " let  g:M_C_F9="\<ESC>\<ESC>[20^"
    " let g:M_C_F10="\<ESC>\<ESC>[21^"
    " let g:M_C_F11="\<ESC>\<ESC>[23^"
    " let g:M_C_F12="\<ESC>\<ESC>[24^"
" endif
"{{{3 Настройки :TOhtml 
let    html_number_lines=1
" let  html_ignore_folding=1
let         html_use_css=1
let          html_no_pre=0
let            use_xhtml=1
"{{{3 Предотвратить загрузку 
let      loaded_cmdalias=0
"{{{3 Mine 
" let g:kmaps={"en": "", "ru": "russian-dvp"}

"{{{1 Syntax 
highlight TooLongLine term=reverse ctermfg=Yellow ctermbg=Red
2match TooLongLine /\S\%>81v/

"{{{1 Autocommands 
autocmd VimLeavePre * silent mksession! ~/.vim/lastSession.vim
au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | execute "silent! !chmod a+x %" | 
            \endif
autocmd BufRead,BufWinEnter * let &l:modifiable=(!(&ro && !&bt=="quickfix"))

"{{{1 Digraphs 
digraphs ca  94 "^
digraphs ga  96 "`
digraphs ti 126 "~

"{{{1 Menus 
" menu Encoding.koi8-r       :e ++enc=8bit-koi8-r<CR>
" menu Encoding.windows-1251 :e ++enc=8bit-cp1251<CR>
" menu Encoding.ibm-866      :e ++enc=8bit-ibm866<CR>
" menu Encoding.utf-8        :e ++enc=2byte-utf-8<CR>
" menu Encoding.ucs-2le      :e ++enc=ucs-2le<CR>

"{{{1 Команды 
function s:Substitute(sstring, line1, line2)
    execute a:line1.",".a:line2."!perl -pi -e 'use encoding \"utf8\"; s'".
                \escape(shellescape(a:sstring), '%!').
                \" 2>/dev/null"
endfunction
command -range=% -nargs=+ S call s:Substitute(<q-args>, <line1>, <line2>)

"{{{1 Mappings 
"{{{2 Menu mappings 

"{{{2 function mappings 
"
"{{{3 Function Eatchar 
function Eatchar(pat)
    let l:pat=((a:pat=="")?("*"):(a:pat))
    let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
    return (c =~ l:pat) ? '' : c
endfunction
"{{{3 CleverTab - tab to autocomplete and move indent 
function CleverTab()
    if strpart( getline('.'), col('.')-2, 1) =~ '^\k$'
        return "\<C-n>"
    else
        return "\<Tab>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <C-R>=CleverTab()<CR>
"{{{3 Keymap switch 
function! SwitchKeymap(kmaps, knum)
    let s:kmapvals=values(a:kmaps)
    if a:knum=="+"
        let s:ki=index(s:kmapvals, &keymap)
        echo s:ki
        if s:ki==-1
            let &keymap=s:kmapvals[0]
            return
        elseif s:ki>=len(a:kmaps)-1
            let &keymap=s:kmapvals[0]
            return
        endif
        let &keymap=s:kmapvals[s:ki+1]
        return
    elseif has_key(a:kmaps, a:knum)
        let &keymap=a:kmaps[a:knum]
        return
    endif
    let s:ki=0
    for val in s:kmapvals
        if s:ki==a:knum
            let &keymap=val
            return
        endif
        let s:ki+=1
    endfor
    let &keymap=s:kmapvals[0]
endfunction
" inoremap <S-Tab> <C-\><C-o>:call<SPACE>SwitchKeymap(g:kmaps,<SPACE>"+")<C-m>


"{{{2 ToggleVerbose 
function! ToggleVerbose()
    let g:verboseflag = !g:verboseflag
    if g:verboseflag
        exe "set verbosefile=".$HOME."/.logs/vim/verbose.log
        set verbose=15
    else
        set verbose=0
        set verbosefile=
    endif
endfunction
noremap <F4>sv :call<SPACE>ToggleVerbose()
inoremap <F4>sv <C-o>:call<SPACE>ToggleVerbose()

"{{{2 Other mappings 
"{{{3 <.*F12> mappings - for some browsing 
 noremap <F12>        :TlistToggle<CR>
inoremap <F12>        <C-O>:TlistToggle<CR>
inoremap <S-F12>      <C-O>:BufExplorer<CR>
 noremap <S-F12>      :BufExplorer<CR>
inoremap <M-F12>      <C-O>:NERDTreeToggle<CR>
 noremap <M-F12>      :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
"{{{3 yank/paste 
vnoremap <C-Insert>   "+y
nnoremap <S-Insert>   "+p
inoremap <S-Insert>    <C-o><S-Insert>
vnoremap p            "_da<C-r><C-r>"<CR><ESC>
"{{{3 Motions 
"{{{4 Left/Right replace 
cnoremap <C-b>        <Left>
cnoremap <C-f>        <Right>
inoremap <C-b>        <C-\><C-o>h
inoremap <C-f>             <C-o>a

cnoremap <M-b>        <C-Right>
inoremap <M-b>        <C-o>w
inoremap <M-f>        <C-o>b
cnoremap <M-f>        <C-Left>
"{{{4 Page Up/Down 
nnoremap <C-b>             <C-U><C-U>
inoremap <PageUp>     <C-O><C-U><C-O><C-U>
nnoremap <C-f>             <C-D><C-D>
inoremap <PageDown>   <C-O><C-D><C-O><C-D>
"{{{4 Up/Down 
inoremap <C-G>        <C-\><C-o>gk
inoremap <Up>         <C-\><C-o>gk
inoremap <Down>       <C-\><C-o>gj
inoremap <C-l>        <C-\><C-o>gj
nnoremap <Down>       gj
vnoremap <Down>       gj
nnoremap  j           gj
vnoremap  j           gj
nnoremap gj            j
vnoremap gj            j
nnoremap gk            k
vnoremap gk            k
nnoremap  k           gk
vnoremap  k           gk
nnoremap <Up>         gk
vnoremap <Up>         gk
"{{{4 Smart <HOME> and <END> 

    " imap <HOME>        <C-o>g^
    " imap <C-O>g^<HOME> <C-o>^
" inoremap <C-o>^<HOME>  <C-o>0
    " imap <END>         <C-o>g$
" inoremap <C-o>g$<END>  <C-o>$
    " nmap <HOME>        <C-o>g^
    " nmap <C-O>g^<HOME>       ^
" nnoremap <C-o>^<HOME>        0
    " nmap <END>              g$
" nnoremap <C-o>g$<END>        $
"{{{3 <F3> and searching 
 noremap   <F3>            :nohl<CR>
inoremap <S-F3>       <C-o>:nohl<CR>
inoremap   <F3>       <C-o>n
"{{{3 <F2> for saving, <F10> for exiting 
 noremap <F2>              :up<CR>
inoremap <F2>         <C-o>:up<CR>
inoremap <F10>        <ESC>ZZ
 noremap <F10>        <ESC>ZZ
inoremap <S-F10>      <ESC>:q!<CR>
 noremap <S-F10>           :q!<CR>
inoremap <C-F10>      <ESC>:silent<SPACE>mksession<SPACE>session.vim<CR>:wq!
 noremap <C-F10>           :silent<SPACE>mksession<SPACE>session.vim<CR>:wq!
"{{{3 Something 
inoremap <C-z>        <C-o>u
 noremap <F1>         :set paste!<C-m>
inoremap <C-^>        <C-O><C-^>
inoremap <C-d>        <Del>
cnoremap <C-d>        <Del>
"{{{3 <C-j> 
inoremap <C-j>j       <C-o>:bn<CR>
inoremap <C-j>J       <C-o>:bN<CR>
 noremap <C-j>j            :bn<CR>
 noremap <C-j>J            :bN<CR>
"{{{3 for visual 
inoremap <S-Left>     <C-o>vge
inoremap <S-Up>       <C-o>vk
inoremap <S-Down>     <C-o>vj
inoremap <S-Right>    <C-o>ve
inoremap <S-End>      <C-o>v$
inoremap <S-Home>     <C-o>v$o^
vnoremap A            <C-c>i
"{{{3 <F4> 
"{{{4 <F4> folds 
 noremap <F4>{        a{{{<ESC>
inoremap <F4>{         {{{
 noremap <F4>}        a}}}<ESC>
inoremap <F4>}         }}}
inoremap <F4>[        <C-o>o{{{<C-o>:call NERDComment(0,"norm")<C-m>
 noremap <F4>[             o{{{<C-o>:call NERDComment(0,"norm")<C-m>
inoremap <F4>]        <C-o>o}}}<C-o>:call NERDComment(0,"norm")<C-m>
 noremap <F4>]             o}}}<C-o>:call NERDComment(0,"norm")<C-m>
"{{{4 <F4> folds 
inoremap <F4>f        <C-o>za<C-o>j<C-o>^
 noremap <F4>f             zaj
"{{{4 <F4> yank/paste/delete 
inoremap <F4>p        <C-o>p
inoremap <F4>gp       <C-o>"+p
inoremap <F4>y(       <C-o>ya)
inoremap <F4>yl       <C-o>yy
inoremap <F4>gy(      <C-o>"+ya)
inoremap <F4>gyl      <C-o>"+yy
inoremap <F4>P        <C-o>P
inoremap <F4>d(       <C-o>da)
inoremap <F4>dl       <C-o>dd
"{{{4 <F4> frequently used expressions 
inoremap <F4>c        \033[m<C-/><C-o>h
"{{{4 <F4> alternate 
    imap <F4>a        <C-o>:A<C-m>
     map <F4>a             :A<C-m>
"}}}
"}}}
"{{{3 «,» 
"
" &lower
" &upper
" &1st
" &2nd
" &both lower and upper (or both 1st and 2nd)
" prefixed with &e
" prefixed with &E
" is &Prefix for smth
" &prefixed with (([what]p(prefix)))
" -: nothing
" +: added
" /: replaced
" [invc]: for modes insert, normal, visual, command (for insert mode if
"         omitted)
"     |     vimrc       |        |        |       |       |
"     | i     n  v  c   |  tex   |   c    | html  | vim   | other
" ----+-----------------+--------+--------+-------+-------+---------------------
"   a | l     l         |        |        |       |       |
"   b | b     -  -  b   | +Pu    | +eb+Eb |       |       |
"   c | l     b         | +u     |        |       |       |
"   d | b     b  b      |        |        |       |       |
"   e | Pl          Pl  |        | +l+Pu  |       |       |
"   f | b(eb) - - b     |        |        |       | /u    | zsh:+el
"   g |                 |        |        |       |       |
"   h | b(el) - - b(el) | /u     |        |       |       | sh:/u+eu
"   i | l     l  -  l   |        |        |       |       |
"   j |                 |        |        |       |       |
"   k |                 |        |        |       |       |
"   l | l               | +Pu    |        |       |       | make:+u
"   m | l     l         | /[in]m | +u     |       |       |
"   n | l               | /l+u   |        | /l    | /l    |
"   o | l               |        |        |       |       |
"   p | -     -  -  b   | +el    |        |       |       |
"   q | b(eb)           | +Pl    |        |       |       |
"   r |                 | +u     |        |       |       |
"   s | l(el) - - b     | +u     | +u     |       | +u+eu | make,perl,zsh:+u
"   t | b(el) - - l     | +eu    |        |       |       |
"   u | l     -  -  b   |        |        | +u    | +u    |
"   v |                 |        |        |       |       |
"   w | b     -  -  b   |        |        |       |       |
"   x |                 |        |        |       |       |
"   y | l     l  l      |        |        |       |       |
"   z |                 |        |        |       |       |
" ' " | b               | /b     |        |       |       |
" ; : | 1               |        |        |       |       |
" , . | b     2  - 1    |        |        | +e2   |       |
" ? ! |                 |        |        |       |       |
" < > |                 | +b     |        | +b+eb | +1    |
" - _ |                 | +1     |        | +b    |       |
" @ / | b               |        |        |       |       |
"   = |                 |        |        |       |       |
"
"{{{4 insert 
inoremap ,<SPACE>     ,<SPACE>
inoremap ,<Esc>       ,
inoremap ,<BS>        <Nop>
inoremap ,ef           <C-o>I{<C-m><C-o>o}<C-o>O
inoremap ,eF            <C-m>{<C-m><C-o>o}<C-o>O
inoremap ,F              {<C-o>o}<C-o>O
inoremap ,f               {}<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,h               []<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,s               ()<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,u            <LT>><C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,es               (<C-\><C-o>E<C-o>a)<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,H           [[::]]<C-o>F:
inoremap ,eh            [::]<C-o>F:
inoremap ,,                \
inoremap ,.           <C-o>==
inoremap ,w           <C-o>w
inoremap ,W           <C-o>W
inoremap ,b           <C-o>b
inoremap ,B           <C-o>B
inoremap ,a           <C-o>A
inoremap ,i           <C-o>I
inoremap ,l           <C-o>o
inoremap ,o           <C-o>O
inoremap ,dw          <C-o>"zdaw
inoremap ,p           <C-o>"zp
inoremap ,P           <C-o>"zP
inoremap ,yw          <C-o>"zyaw
inoremap ,y           <C-o>"zy
inoremap ,d           <C-o>"zd
inoremap ,D           <C-o>"_d
inoremap ,c           <C-o>:call<SPACE>NERDComment(0,"toggle")<C-m>
inoremap ,ec          <C-o>:call<SPACE>NERDComment(0,"toEOL")<C-m>
inoremap ,t                                <C-r>=Tr3transliterate(input("Translit: "))<C-m>
inoremap ,T           <C-o>b<C-o>"tdiw<C-r><C-r>=Tr3transliterate(@t)<C-m>
inoremap ,et          <C-o>B<C-o>"tdiW<C-r><C-r>=Tr3transliterate(@t)<C-m>
inoremap ,/            <C-x><C-f>
inoremap ,@                 <C-o>:w!<C-m>
inoremap ,;                 <C-o>%
inoremap ,m           <C-\><C-o>:call system("make &")<C-m>
inoremap ,n           \<C-m>
inoremap ,q           «»<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,Q           „“<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,eq          “”<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,eQ          ‘’<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,"           ""<C-\><C-o>h
inoremap ,'           ''<C-\><C-o>h

"{{{4 visual 
vnoremap ,y                "zy
vnoremap ,d                "zd
vnoremap ,D                "_d
vnoremap ,p                "zp

"{{{4 command 
cnoremap ,s                ()<Left>
cnoremap ,S              \(\)<Left><Left>
cnoremap ,U           \<LT>\><Left><Left>
cnoremap ,u             <LT>><Left>
cnoremap ,F               \{}<Left>
cnoremap ,f                {}<Left>
cnoremap ,h                []<Left>
cnoremap ,H            [[::]]<Left><Left><Left>
cnoremap ,eh             [::]<Left><Left>
cnoremap ,i                  <Home>
cnoremap ,a                  <End>
cnoremap ,,                \
cnoremap ,.           <C-r>:
cnoremap ,p           <C-r>"
cnoremap ,P           <C-r>+
cnoremap ,z           <C-r>z
cnoremap ,t           <C-r>=Tr3transliterate(input("Translit: "))<C-m>
cnoremap ,b           <C-Left>
cnoremap ,w           <C-Right>
cnoremap ,B           <C-Left>
cnoremap ,W           <C-Right>

"{{{4 normal 
nnoremap ,C                     :!
nnoremap ,c           :call<SPACE>NERDComment(0,"toggle")<C-m>
nnoremap ,d           "_
nnoremap ,D           "_d
nnoremap ,m           :call system("make &")<C-m>
nnoremap ,a           $
nnoremap ,i           ^
nnoremap ,,           ==
nnoremap ,y           "zy
nnoremap ,p           "zp
nnoremap ,P           "zP

"{{{1 Functions 

"{{{1 
nohlsearch
" vim: ft=vim:fenc=utf-8:ts=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some parts of my vimrc and files sourced from the vimrc:

### Using <kbd>F10</kbd> to toggle common boolean settings:

```
" F10 inverts 'wrap'
xnoremap <F10>          :<C-U>set wrap! <Bar> set wrap? <CR>gv
nnoremap <F10>          :set wrap! <Bar> set wrap? <CR>
inoremap <F10>          <C-O>:set wrap! <Bar> set wrap? <CR>
" Shift-F10 inverts 'virtualedit'
xnoremap <S-F10>        :<C-U>set ve=<C-R>=(&ve == 'all') ? '' : 'all'<return> ve?<CR>gv
nnoremap <S-F10>        :set ve=<C-R>=(&ve == 'all') ? '' : 'all'<return> ve?<CR>
inoremap <S-F10>        <C-O>:set ve=<C-R>=(&ve == 'all') ? '' : 'all'<return> ve?<CR>
" Ctrl-F10 inverts 'hidden'
xnoremap <C-F10>        :<C-U>set hidden! <Bar> set hidden? <CR>gv
nnoremap <C-F10>        :set hidden! <Bar> set hidden? <CR>
inoremap <C-F10>        <C-O>:set hidden! <Bar> set hidden? <CR>
```

### Using <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> to move around quickfix entries

```
" F11 and F12 to go to resp. previous and next item in quickfix entries
nnoremap <F11>          :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cp <CR>:call ErrBlink()<CR>
nnoremap <F12>          :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cn <CR>:call ErrBlink()<CR>
" Shift-F11 and Shift-F12 to go to resp prev. and next file in quickfix list
nnoremap <S-F11>        :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cpf<CR>:call ErrBlink()<CR>
nnoremap <S-F12>        :silent! cc<CR>:silent! cnf<CR>:call ErrBlink()<CR>
" Ctrl-F11 and Ctrl-F1 to recall older and newer quickfix lists
nnoremap <C-F11>        :silent! col <CR>:call ErrBlink()<CR>
nnoremap <C-F12>        :silent! cnew<CR>:call ErrBlink()<CR>
```

### Search visually selected text with <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> (prefix with <kbd>_</kbd> to keep old search also)

```
xnoremap <silent> _* :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>/\|<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \substitute(escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\s\+', '\\s\\+', 'g'), '\_s\+', '\\_s*', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>

xnoremap <silent> _# :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>/\|<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \substitute(escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\s\+', '\\s\\+', 'g'), '\_s\+', '\\_s*', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>

xnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \substitute(escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\s\+', '\\s\\+', 'g'), '\_s\+', '\\_s*', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>

xnoremap <silent> # :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \substitute(escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\s\+', '\\s\\+', 'g'), '\_s\+', '\\_s*', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
```

### Using <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> to search (shift to add results to current ones)

```
set grepprg=ack
" F2 uses ack to search a Perl pattern
nnoremap <F2>         :grep<space>
nnoremap <S-F2>       :grepadd<space>
" F3 uses vim to search current pattern
nnoremap <F3>         :noautocmd vim // **/*<C-F>Bhhi
nnoremap <F3><F3>     :noautocmd vim /<C-R><C-O>// **/*<Return>
" F3 to search the current highlighted pattern
xnoremap <F3>         "zy:noautocmd vim /\M<C-R>=escape(@z,'\/')<CR>/ **/*<CR>
nnoremap <S-F3>       :noautocmd vimgrepadd // **/*<C-F>Bhhi
nnoremap <S-F3><S-F3> :noautocmd vimgrepadd /<C-R><C-O>// **/*<Return>
xnoremap <S-F3>       "zy:noautocmd vimgrepadd /\M<C-R>=escape(@z,'\/')<CR>/ **/*<CR>
```

### Do not store replaced text when pasting in visual mode

```
xnoremap p              pgvy
```

### Help functions

```
" Have cursor line and column blink a bit
function! BlinkHere()
    for i in range(1,6)
        set cursorline! cursorcolumn!
        redraw
        sleep 30m
    endfor
endfunction

" Blink on mappings to quickfix commands
function! ErrBlink()
    silent! cw
    silent! normal! z17
    silent! cc
    silent! normal! zz
    silent! call BlinkHere()
endfunction
```

### Automatically sort quickfix list

```
function! s:CompareQuickfixEntries(i1, i2)
  if bufname(a:i1.bufnr) == bufname(a:i2.bufnr)
    return a:i1.lnum == a:i2.lnum ? 0 : (a:i1.lnum < a:i2.lnum ? -1 : 1)
  else
    return bufname(a:i1.bufnr) < bufname(a:i2.bufnr) ? -1 : 1
  endif
endfunction

function! s:SortUniqQFList()
  let sortedList = sort(getqflist(), 's:CompareQuickfixEntries')
  let uniqedList = []
  let last = ''
  for item in sortedList
    let this = bufname(item.bufnr) . "\t" . item.lnum
    if this !=# last
      call add(uniqedList, item)
      let last = this
    endif
  endfor
  call setqflist(uniqedList)
endfunction
autocmd! QuickfixCmdPost * call s:SortUniqQFList()
```

Answer (score 0):

My (pretty heavily customized) vimrc is probably too long to post it here, so I'll just link to it instead:

https://github.com/majutsushi/etc/blob/master/vim/.vimrc

There are some useful tidbits in there that I either wrote myself or picked up somewhere like a statusbar with all kinds of information that I find useful. A screenshot is on the website of this plugin I wrote:

http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/