# Favorite minimalistic .vimrc configuration

Tags: vim

There are .vimrc related questions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/what-are-your-favorite-vim-tricks).

This question wants to deal with a minimalistic .vimrc file.

If you are on a new machine with no .vimrc file what are some 'must turn on' commands you use before doing any typing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is never a need for a minimalistic configuration. This solves everything:

```
wget -O ~/.vimrc http://github.com/lucasoman/Conf/raw/master/.vimrc
```

Comment: Better to clone it, so if you make changes locally you can just commit them back up to github.

Comment: Well, that assumes that git is installed or that I have permissions to install it. Cloning is preferable, but the above solution is universal.

Comment: using git rep for for environment setting is a great idea which is why I accepted the answer.

Comment: @LucasOman this .vimrc gives me error on opening any file *Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vimrc:
line    8:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles
Press ENTER or type command to continue
*

Comment: @pythonlearner you must install pathogen package (depending the distro), and also you've got to change pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles() by pathogen#infect() and the error disappear

Comment: I liked your .vimrc but by no mean it can be considered minimalistic. It ha rulers, it uses pathogen and so on... I would consider @Yada answer more suitable for that.

Comment: It is an extremely insecure answer to tell somebody to just blindly run a bash oneliner that will install your latest personal `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 27):

Here's my minimal settings with comments:

```
set backspace=2         " backspace in insert mode works like normal editor
syntax on               " syntax highlighting
filetype indent on      " activates indenting for files
set autoindent          " auto indenting
set number              " line numbers
colorscheme desert      " colorscheme desert
set nobackup            " get rid of anoying ~file
```

Comment: I had no idea about `nobackup`. Neat. `rm * ~` instead of `rm *~` is too easy to do...

Comment: set backspace=eol,start,indent

Comment: this assumes you have the "desert" schema installed

Answer (score 6):

My config:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Sets how many lines of history VIM has to remember
set history=700

" Enable filetype plugins
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread


"Always show current position
set ruler

" Ignore case when searching
set ignorecase

" When searching try to be smart about cases 
set smartcase

" Highlight search results
set hlsearch

" Show matching brackets when text indicator is over them
set showmatch


syntax enable


colorscheme desert
set background=dark

" Set extra options when running in GUI mode
if has("gui_running")
    set guioptions-=T
    set guioptions+=e
    set t_Co=256
    set guitablabel=%M\ %t
endif

" Set utf8 as standard encoding and en_US as the standard language
set encoding=utf8

" Use Unix as the standard file type
set ffs=unix,dos,mac

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Files, backups and undo
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Turn backup off, since most stuff is in SVN, git et.c anyway...
set nobackup
set nowb
set noswapfile


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Text, tab and indent related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab

" Be smart when using tabs ;)
set smarttab

" 1 tab == 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

" Linebreak on 500 characters
set lbr
set tw=500

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
set wrap "Wrap lines


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Moving around, tabs, windows and buffers
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Treat long lines as break lines (useful when moving around in them)
map j gj
map k gk



""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Status line
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Always show the status line
set laststatus=2

" Format the status line
set statusline=\ %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ CWD:\ %r%{getcwd()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l
```

I found this:

http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html

just copy things that you want

Answer (score 4):

This deviates a bit from the letter of the question, but is hopefully within the spirit.  The very first thing I do on a new machine is `set -o vi` to get vi-style key bindings on the commandline.

Answer (score 4):

So many lines to choose from, but the ones I wouldn't be without and would highly recommend for all vimmers:

```
" remap jj to escape in insert mode
inoremap jj <Esc>

" swapping : and ; save a lot of unneeded shifting:
noremap ; :
noremap : ;

" The wish that grants more wishes (edit vimrc with \ev)
nnoremap <Leader>ev :tabnew<CR>:e ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some real good must have commands.

```
        " do not make vim compatible with vi.
    set nocompatible

        " number the lines.
    set number

        " show location of cursor using a horizontal line.
    set cursorline

        " keep cursor in the middle of the screen while scrolling up and down.
    set scrolloff=999

    " show auto complete menus.
    set wildmenu

    " Make wildmenu behave like bash completion. Finding commands are so easy now.
    set wildmode=list:longest

    " run the Bash script by pressing F6 without leaving VIM.
    map <f6> :w <CR>:!bash % <CR>

    " turn on syntax hightlighting.
    set syntax=on
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of .vimrc ideas can be found [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=856051).

Answer (score 1):

`syntax enable`
`set background=dark` for black xterms.
`set autoindent` when I'm going to develop.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am on new machines a lot, I have put my minimalistic .vimrc on my homepage 
[here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/vim/gvimrc.html). So I don't have to carry it around on an USB stick.

Don't know, if there's anything for you in it or not.

Rene

Answer (score 1):

My vimrc lives on my dropbox folder. But it's not minimalistic.

If I'm doing something really simple (not worth grabbing my real vimrc) I'll do the following:

```
:set nocompatible
:set number
:set showmatch
:map! <F3> <Esc>
```