# Restoring vimrc

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I had to reinstall vim due to a problem with my vimrc file. I got that solved, but now I don't have a vimrc file. Can anybody tell me where how to create one or where I can download one? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create with

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

and add this how basic configurations

```
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set background=dark
syntax on
```

or use this examples as guide

[favorite-minimalistic-vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840862/favorite-minimalistic-vimrc-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm totally new to linux, and I am having trouble creating a ./vimrc file from scratch.  I can create a new file using vim ~./vimrc, but then, I don't know how to paste in the text from the sample file. Also, when I go to save the file using :w, it tells me that it can't create the file.

Comment: is `vim ~/.vimrc` you write `vim ~./vimrc`

Comment: maybe is useful for you http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html and http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

When I was getting started with vim, I used [this one](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-config/blob/master/vimrc) as base.
To create one you just need a file named `.vimrc` on your home dir

Answer (score 2):

Vim installs `vimrc_example.vim` file at $VIMRUNTIME directory. On my linux box it is a `/usr/share/vim/vim73/vimrc_example.vim`.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, sorry champ. No luck there. You lost yours, it seems :/

*(btw, vimrc and the appropriate dotfiles are often kept under source control and in some online repo (GitHub?) so why not put yours there as well?)*

Speaking of **GitHub**, if you search ***.vimrc*** it gives quite [a few suggestions](https://github.com/search?q=.vimrc&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1). Take your pick :)