# What are the must have vim commands to place in my vimrc file for general editing

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is in your .vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc)

I am fairly confident with vim having used it on and off for the past 3 years but I keep finding new **simple** suggestions for my vimrc for general editing which, after I use them seem blatantly obvious.

An example being:

```
noremap p "+p
noremap y "+y
```

For OS clipboard use (on my linux box anyway)

Another example being:

```
imap jj <ESC>
```

So in an attempt to collect together a definitive set of **simple** vimrc entries I will ask the questions, which do you find most useful?

Edit:

I am looking for the most basic vim commands, not functions and stringed commands

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc

Comment: I want simple commands, that question centers around more complex multi command functions etc..

Comment: I strongly feel that this is a duplicate, however if this must stay open it needs to be a community wiki as there is no correct answer.

Comment: what do the noremap examples do?

Comment: copies to the OS clipboard and pastes back, actually I have started using ,p and ,y for this so it's not intrusive on other vim clipboard functions

Comment: @Vijay Dev: the first one pastes from the system clipboard and the second one copies to it. Useful if you're copy-pasting from/to different applications. This will work only if you have `+xterm_clipboard` in `:version`. Else, you'll have to re-compile with this option.

Comment: I already know about p and y being paste and yank. My question was with the "+p and "+y mappings. Sorry if I wasnt clear earlier

Comment: @Vijay: please read what both of us had written... using the `+` copies it to the **system clipboard** (which is a special buffer in vim) and not vim's default buffer.

Comment: Ahh! I must have been sleeping while I read your earlier answers!! Sorry about that :)

Comment: no problem :). With that shortcut and `iTerm2` for mac, I can easily move between vim and an IDE in split windows and copy pasta from one to another. Pretty useful.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - For the record I disagree with this statement, I am unable to find a question that covers 'exactly' the same ground. The only link I have been provided (by Marco Mariani) specifically states an interest in Macros for c#, I state general simple editing commands, I think there is a big difference between the 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will save you a lot of pinky strain over the years

```
nnoremap ; :
```

This remaps `;` to `:`, as it is a relatively unused key and you don't have to press shift for the `:`. The `:` still works, just in case you still press shift from muscle memory.

Personally, I've also found these to be helpful:

1) Use first person shooter (FPS) games' movement keys for window movements (not a good idea if you use `A` or `D` often. I don't.)

```
map <W> <C-w><Up>
map <S> <C-w><Down>
map <A> <C-w><Left>
map <D> <C-w><Right>
```

2) Use `<space>` as a leader

```
nnoremap <space> <Nop>
let mapleader = " "
```

3) Disable middle mouse, especially on a mac, where inadvertently using the mouse (to switch applications) pastes content if middle click is accidentally pressed

```
map <MiddleMouse> <Nop>
imap <MiddleMouse> <Nop>
```

4) Movement between tabs (kind of similar to Firefox)

```
map <T> :tabnew<Space>
map <Q> :tabclose<cr>
map <Leader>[ gT
map <Leader>] gt
```

I forgot to add that for the above, I use it as `T <filename><enter>`, which is a nice and quick way of opening a file in the current directory in a new tab.