# In a .vimrc, is `set nocompatible` completely useless?

Tags: vim

Several users in [this epic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc) put the following in the `.vimrc`:

```
" Necesary for lots of cool vim things
set nocompatible
```

But is it really necessary? From the docs:

```
'compatible' 'cp'
    boolean (default on, off when a |vimrc| or |gvimrc| file is found)
```

If `set nocompatible` is going in a `.vimrc`, that means that a `.vimrc` file exists, seemingly making it pointless.

Comment: Nope: It fixes several bugs with insert mode and the delete key for me on my rhel5 box

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If it is the system-wide vimrc, this option won't be off. So, if you're changing the system-wide vimrc and you want it, you need to set it.

From the documentation section [*compatible-default*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#compatible-default) (emphasis mine):

> When Vim starts, the 'compatible'
>   option is on.  This will be used when
>   Vim starts its initializations.  But
>   as soon as a *user vimrc* file is found,
>   or a vimrc file in the *current
>   directory*, or the "VIMINIT"
>   environment variable is set, it will
>   be set to 'nocompatible'.

Another difference is that explicitly setting 'nocompatible' overrules calling vim with the [-C flag](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-D).

In any other scenario, yes, setting 'nocompatible' in your vimrc is a noop.

In the end I think it's just a matter of "better safe than sorry".

Comment: Damn, couldn't link directly to the `-C` flag. At least on my browser (Chrome 10, Windows 7) it jumps to the `-c` flag. So, I linked to the `-D` which is just above. :(

Comment: `:set nocompatible` in .vimrc does seem to change some settings, for example it implies `:set noshowcmd`. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 30):

Many people share their .vimrc files on GitHub and I sometimes will test out settings without replacing my .vimrc file.  vim allows me to do this with the -u flag.

```
vim -u test_vimrc
```

From vim ":help nocompatible"

> (Note: This doesn't happen for the system-wide vimrc or gvimrc file,
>   nor for a file given with the |-u| argument).

This means that if you share your .vimrc with someone and they use -u flag to load your file, vim won't be configured the same as if the file were named .vimrc and located in your home directory.

Comment: This is a very important point.  I recently learned this the hard way.  If you use -u, by default compatible is turned on.  As a result, vim -u ~/.vimrc is actually not the same as letting vim load your ~/.vimrc on its own--unless you add in the "set nocompatible."

Comment: Vim configuration files without nocompatible included can be loaded with `vim -Nu test_vimrc` as the -N specifies no-compatible mode.

Comment: Yes.  Vim ideally would have a flag --testvimrc that would simply follow the (no)compatible settings of the .vimrc itself.  It's simply confusing and unhelpful to have the flag that loads settings change one of the possible settings.  -u and -Nu both serve a purpose, but neither fully tests the .vimrc.

Answer (score 8):

I was using vim in Cygwin on a Windows VM and every time I was in Insert Mode, pressing arrow keys would result in vim printing "A", "B", "C" or "D" on the screen instead of scrolling. I found a forum that said putting vim in nocompatible mode would fix it. Thankfully, it did.

I put "set nocompatible" in my ~/.vimrc file and the problem remains gone. So perhaps it's not 100% useless.

Comment: You don't need to put anything in `~/.vimrc`. The sheer existence of that file will put vim into *nocompatible* mode. Try it, backup your current .vimrc `mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vimrc.bak` and create an empty one `touch ~/.vimrc`. Now open vim and see what happens.

Comment: Oh side effects, how we cherish thee.

Comment: @JohnnyBaloney Well, I can tell you "what happens" here on Ubuntu. What retsigam said is also true for this distro: without `set nocompatible`, vi is a nightmare to navigate with the cursor keys. When I tried your testcase, I instantly had the same nightmare again with that empty .vimrc. But YET you've been right throughout. :-) __See extra answer__ about my recent findings.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/353944/822409) is an example of "found a forum that said...[to set nocompatible]"   And it's actually this forum :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Johnny pointed out above, I was simply astonished when I just found THIS out:

```
$ cat /usr/share/vim/vimrc.tiny
" Debian system-wide default configuration Vim
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after

set compatible
```

ARGH!!!

No I did NOT expect that.
Debian (or Debian Unstable aka Ubuntu) indeed DOES put up a nightmare to their users by overriding the default setting by **set compatible**.
I hope that you will now know why when you're coming from FreeBSD, the first thing you would have to do is override the system-wide setting by putting a `set nocompatible` into your own `~/.vimrc`. Because otherwise you'd just produce letters instead of being able to move the cursor the way you've been used to.

I think this is a horrid idea. In other words, this `set compatible` line ought to be **removed** from the system-wide `vimrc.tiny` in both Debian and Ubuntu, because it will annoy new users who are not (yet) as smart as knowing how to get the cursor keys working.
It's things like these that force them to `nano` and others because of such entirely pointless blockers!

I would really want to talk with the dude who once propagated this change to the system-wide resource file in Debian. And maybe also to the people who acknowledged his change to the fullest.

**Johnny is right: on your private PC, you may remove said line from the system-wide .vimrc (if there), and touch an empty .vimrc on your $HOME**. Thanks so much for pointing that out, way less clutter again. Note that you MUST have that `~/.vimrc` (even if empty!) as otherwise you will not be able to use the cursors without *explicitly* putting in `set nocompatible`.

Comment: The comments in `vimrc.tiny` explain that it is only sourced when you invoke vim as `vi`, in which case it makes sense to vim to try to be compatible with`vi`. This file is not sourced when you run `vim`, and the related `vimrc` file in the same directory does not include them.  All this is explained in the comments of the `vimrc.tiny` file you found.

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem on using `-u vimrc` option, even doing `set nocompatible` was misbehaving with some of my older setting, after some search i found one compactible version that works for me:

```
" Avoid side-effects when nocompatible has already been set.
if &compatible
  set nocompatible
endif
```

this avoid re-setting of nocompatible flag when it is already set.

vim `:help nocompatible` shows conditions when it set/resets the options value, scroll to that table of options and values, for quick reference, conditions that effect this behaviour are:

> 1. Option is set to the value given in {set value} when 'compatible' is
>    set.
> 2. Option is set to the value given in {set value} when 'compatible' is set AND is set to its Vim default value when 'compatible' is
>    unset.
> 3. Option is NOT changed when setting 'compatible' but IS set to its Vim default when 'compatible' is unset.