# VIM maps directional keys to the letters ABCD

Tags: vim

Whenever I use vim, and press up, down, left, or right, it maps to A, B, C, D respectively but only in insert mode. Outside of insert mode, the keys work just fine. I checked the .vimrc file and didn't see anything suspicious that could cause this.

I'm on a Mac, OS X 10.8 and on VIM 7.3.923 (just upgraded, that didn't resole any problems either).

I ran `:map` which resulted in:

```
gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX                                                                                                                                                               
<Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
<BS>          "-d
<D-x>         "*d
<D-c>         "*y
<D-v>         "-d"*P
<D-v>         "*P
```

And `:imap` which resulted in:

```
<D-v>         <C-R>*
```

Ideas?

Comment: [Fix arrow keys that display A B C D on remote shell](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to turn off compatible mode.
This is [generally a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845557/in-a-vimrc-is-set-nocompatible-completely-useless) (better safe than sorry) even if you don't have this problem.

```
set nocompatible
```

It might also be a problem with your `$TERM`, among other things.
See [Fix arrow keys that display A B C D on remote shell](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell) for more information.

Comment: The mere presence of a `.vimrc` file disables compatible mode as long as it's not explicitly set in the `.vimrc`.  Not a knock on this answer, just a useful piece of related info.

Comment: I used the answer in the link, everything works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @RandyMorris Thanks, updated my answer. Better safe than sorry as the answer in the linked post said I guess.

Comment: I used the first solution in the Fix arrow keys that display A B C D on remote shell link (remapping the arrow keys). Everything worked correctly afterward.

Comment: Using *Cygwin*, in addition to the first solution, I had to add `alias vi="vi -u ~/.vimrc"` to my *~/.bash_aliases* files. For some reason it seems like `vi` wasn't picking up my *~/.vimrc* file.

Comment: @Batandwa That may be something with the Cygwin version of Vi. I've used Vim with Cygwin and did not have to do such a thing.

Comment: I had to set `TERM` to `xterm` in konsole (Settings > Edit Current Profile... >  Environment > Edit... > enter: `TERM=xterm`)

Answer (score 10):

Have you mapped the escape key?

I had the same issue when I tried remapping the escape key to clear out search highlighting.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Don't understand why mapping the escape key (I used `nnorem <esc> :nohlsearch<cr>`) would affect the arrow keys, though.

Comment: I tried the exact same thing and ran into the exact same problem - took a lot of googling before I finally tracked the problem to this answer.  WTF?

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing this as an issue only when I map the escape key. Anybody have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

In OS-X, in Terminal, go to Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Declare Terminal as vt102.