# Vi for OS X won't show -- insert -- on status

Tags: macos, vim, vi, status

I have tried many things such as add "set showmode" in .vimrc file and start vi with the command "vim" instead of just "vi". Nothing seems to work. I have another Mac and in that one the --Insert-- status does show up.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `'showmode'` is on by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the problem.
It seems that the status was always there but the text color was the same as the background (black). As soon as I changed the theme color, I was able to see the status --Insert--.

Answer (score 1):

vim will not show the mode if (later) in the settings you have

```
set compatible
```

That cancels and/or overrides *most* of the vim extensions.  See these for discussion:

- [In a .vimrc, is `set nocompatible` completely useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845557/in-a-vimrc-is-set-nocompatible-completely-useless)
- [Setting vim filetype with modeline not working as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19875/setting-vim-filetype-with-modeline-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: uhm! I tried that command and it only switches back to the old Vi but it won't fix the problem :(

Comment: My comment was that if you had (or used) an initialization script which set nocompatible, then that could explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if your trying status lines and term colours you might find this useful.
https://github.com/FallenAngelTodd/vim-status
lots used for setting different modes in the status line?