# .vimrc file not apply certain key mappings

Tags: vim

A lot of my key mappings, some of which worked before, are no longer being applied. I will display all the individual mappings one at a time. At the end I will put my whole `.vimrc` file. I should state that I am not a vim guru, so there has been a significant amount of copy pasting.

**Map Leaders:**

```
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>
map <leader>e :e! ~/.vimrc<cr>
```

neither <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> nor <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> do anything.

**NERD Tree:**

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>    "Toggle Nerd Tree on/off
```

<kbd>F2</kbd> no longer works.

**Buffer Navigation:**

```
map <S-j> :bp<CR>           
map <S-k> :bn<CR>
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> no longer move to the next or previous buffer, even though they used to.

In addition to this, a lot of other functions don't work, for example, the [Latex-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> command
 which is suppose to fold up the Latex code, does nothing.

---

**Answers to Follow up Questions:**

Q: Is it only a mapping/function problem

A: To the best of my knowledge, Yes

Q: Do your other settings work?

A: Yes

Q:Do these mappings work if you enter them on the commandline, like `:nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>`

A:It does not appear so, even if I did `:let mapleader = ","` and/or `let g:mapleader = ","`, however, `:NERDTreeToggle` works

**Requested commands:**

```
:redir >for_stack_overflow.txt
:scriptnames
:verb map ,
:verb map <f2>
:redir END
```

**Output of requested commands:**

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim73/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  7: /home/peyman/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
 10: /home/peyman/.vim/colors/xoria256.vim
 11: /home/peyman/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftoff.vim
 13: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 14: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/SearchComplete.vim
 15: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
 16: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/filebrowser.vim
 17: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/imaps.vim
 18: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/jsbeautify.vim
 19: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/libList.vim
 20: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/mru.vim
 21: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
 22: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/showmarks.vim
 23: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/supertab.vim
 24: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/syntastic.vim
 25: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/c.vim
 26: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/coffee.vim
 27: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/cpp.vim
 28: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/cucumber.vim
 29: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/eruby.vim
 30: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/haml.vim
 31: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/haskell.vim
 32: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/html.vim
 33: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/javascript.vim
 34: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/lua.vim
 35: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/perl.vim
 36: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/php.vim
 37: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/python.vim
 38: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/ruby.vim
 39: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/sass.vim
 40: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/sh.vim
 41: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/tex.vim
 42: /home/peyman/.vim/syntax_checkers/xhtml.vim
 43: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/c.vim
 44: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/coffee.vim
 45: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/cpp.vim
 46: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/cucumber.vim
 47: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/eruby.vim
 48: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/haml.vim
 49: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/haskell.vim
 50: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/html.vim
 51: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/javascript.vim
 52: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/lua.vim
 53: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/perl.vim
 54: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/php.vim
 55: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/python.vim
 56: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/ruby.vim
 57: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/sass.vim
 58: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/sh.vim
 59: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/tex.vim
 60: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/xhtml.vim
 61: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/tabname.vim
 62: /home/peyman/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
 63: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/gundo/plugin/gundo.vim
 64: /home/peyman/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim
 65: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 66: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
 67: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
 68: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 69: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 70: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
 71: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 72: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 73: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 74: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 75: /home/peyman/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
 76: /home/peyman/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim

   ,_s         * :TCommentAs <C-R>=&ft<CR>_
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
   ,_n         * :TCommentAs <C-R>=&ft<CR><Space>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
   ,_a         * :TCommentAs<Space>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
   ,_b         * :TCommentBlock<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
x  ,_r         * :TCommentRight<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
nos,_r         * :TCommentRight<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
x  ,_i         * :TCommentInline<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
   ,_<Space>   * :TComment<Space>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
   ,_p         * vip:TComment<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
x  ,__         * :TCommentMaybeInline<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
nos,__         * :TComment<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/tcomment.vim
   ,mm           :ShowMarksPlaceMark<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/showmarks.vim
   ,ma           :ShowMarksClearAll<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/showmarks.vim
   ,mh           :ShowMarksClearMark<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/showmarks.vim
   ,mo           :ShowMarksOn<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/showmarks.vim
   ,mt           :ShowMarksToggle<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/showmarks.vim
n  ,ff         * :call g:Jsbeautify()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/jsbeautify.vim
   ,e            :e! ~/.vimrc<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
n  ,/            :nohlsearch<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
n  ,w            :w!<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc

   <F2>          :NERDTreeToggle<CR>   <Space>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

---

**More Follow up Questions:**
 What is the value of the timeoutlen and timeout settings

**More Answers to Follow up Questions:**

```
`:verb set timeout` --> No Output
`:verb set timeoutlen` --> timeoutlen=1000
```

**.vimrc:**

```
" With a map leader it's possible to do extra key combinations
" like <leader>w saves the current file
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

"Turn on syntax (I guess)
syntax on

" Needed for Syntax Highlighting and stuff
filetype on
filetype plugin on
syntax enable
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" Tell vim to remember certain things when we exit
"  '10  :  marks will be remembered for up to 10 previously edited files
"  "100 :  will save up to 100 lines for each register
"  :20  :  up to 20 lines of command-line history will be remembered
"  %    :  saves and restores the buffer list
"  n... :  where to save the viminfo files
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo

"Restore cursor position
function! ResCur()
  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`"
    return 1
  endif
endfunction

augroup resCur
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
augroup END

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>

" Fast editing of the .vimrc
map <leader>e :e! ~/.vimrc<cr>

" When vimrc is edited, reload it
autocmd! bufwritepost vimrc source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrc

"Latex Suite
"This specifies what I want folded. I have included the defaults as well as
"some of my own as well
" let g:Tex_FoldedSections=',test'
" let g:Tex_FoldedCommands=',lstset'
" let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments=',itemize'
" let g:Tex_FoldedMiscl=',comments'

"These two lines display the file name at the bottom
set modeline                        
set ls=2

"Default for checking marks is 4 seconds, make it faster
set updatetime=100          

"Persistent Undo
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
set undolevels=10000    "maximum number of changes that can be undone
set undoreload=10000 "maximum number lines to save for undo on a buffer reload

"Use GUndo to better view undo tree
"http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/
nnoremap <F5> :GundoToggle<CR>

"Keep undo history when switching buffers
set hidden

"Don't use vi-compatibility mode
set nocompatible                    

"Use the smart version of backspace (jumps over tabs apparently instead of
"spaces 
set backspace=2                     

"Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab                       

"Line Numbers
set number                                              

"Makes unnamed clipboard accesible to X window
set clipboard=unnamedplus

"Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.
set shiftwidth=4

"This shows what you are typing as a command
set showcmd

"Not too sure what this does
set smarttab

"Indent every time you press enter
set autoindent
set smartindent                                          

"Use C style indent instead (note this causes problems with non C code)
" set cindent

"Cursor Always in middle
"NOTE This causes problems with word wrap of long lines as they are not
"displayed correctly
set scrolloff=999                       

"Always display row/column info 
set ruler                           

"Set a red ruler at some point for comment blocks
"But only for php and js files as they make heavy use of comments
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.php,*.js set cc=80

"turn on spell check for tex files
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex set spell spelllang=en_gb

set tags=tags;/

"make word wrap wrap words, not character
set formatoptions=l
set lbr

"Use ... when word wrapping
set showbreak=...

"enable status line always
set laststatus=2

"
" statusline
" cf the default statusline: %<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
" format markers:
"   %< truncation point
"   %n buffer number
"   %f relative path to file
"   %m modified flag [+] (modified), [-] (unmodifiable) or nothing
"   %r readonly flag [RO]
"   %y filetype [ruby]
"   %= split point for left and right justification
"   %-35. width specification
"   %l current line number
"   %L number of lines in buffer
"   %c current column number
"   %V current virtual column number (-n), if different from %c
"   %P percentage through buffer
"   %) end of width specification
set statusline=%f%m%r%h%w[%n]\ [F=%{&ff}][T=%Y]\ %=[LINE=%l][%p%%]

"set it up to change the status line based on mode
if version >= 700
  au InsertEnter * hi StatusLine term=reverse ctermbg=4
  au InsertLeave * hi StatusLine term=reverse ctermbg=2
endif

autocmd FileType tex setlocal makeprg=pdflatex\ --shell-escape\ '%'     "Compile tex files with :make

"start searching as you type
set incsearch

"Map jj to escape
imap jj <Esc>                       

map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>    "Toggle Nerd Tree on/off

"Highlight search strings
set hlsearch 

" Set off the other paren
highlight MatchParen ctermbg=4

"Ignore case when searching
set ignorecase 

"But remember case when capitals used
set smartcase

" Use english for spellchecking, but don't spellcheck by default
if version >= 700
   set spl=en spell
   set nospell
endif

" Cool tab completion stuff
" Is irritating and I hardly ever use it
" set wildmenu
" set wildmode=list:longest,full

"Show matching bracets when text indicator is over them
set showmatch 

"How many tenths of a second to blink
"Does not seem to change anything
set mat=2 

" Swap ; and :  Convenient.
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;

" Create Blank Newlines and stay in Normal mode
nnoremap <silent> zj o<Esc>
nnoremap <silent> zk O<Esc>

"Highlight current line
set cul

"adjust highlight color
hi CursorLine term=none cterm=none ctermbg=232

"Make cursor move as expected with wrapped lines:
inoremap <Down> <C-o>gj
inoremap <Up> <C-o>gk

"Map Shift+ J to previous buffer
map <S-J> :bp<CR>           

"Map Shift + K to next buffer
map <S-k> :bn<CR>               

"enable 256 color
set t_Co=256

" IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
" search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
" program to always generate a file-name.
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

"Do not want spell checking in my commented blocks
let g:tex_comment_nospell= 1

if &t_Co == 256
    colorscheme xoria256
else
    colorscheme peachpuff
endif

" Restore cursor position to where it was before
augroup JumpCursorOnEdit
   au!
   autocmd BufReadPost *
            \ if expand("<afile>:p:h") !=? $TEMP |
            \   if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
            \     let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = line("'\"") |
            \     let b:doopenfold = 1 |
            \     if (foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo) > foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1)) |
            \        let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1 |
            \        let b:doopenfold = 2 |
            \     endif |
            \     exe JumpCursorOnEdit_foo |
            \   endif |
            \ endif
   " Need to postpone using "zv" until after reading the modelines.
   autocmd BufWinEnter *
            \ if exists("b:doopenfold") |
            \   exe "normal zv" |
            \   if(b:doopenfold > 1) |
            \       exe  "+".1 |
            \   endif |
            \   unlet b:doopenfold |
            \ endif
augroup END

"for Syntastic
function! BufSel(pattern)
  let bufcount = bufnr("$")
  let currbufnr = 1
  let nummatches = 0
  let firstmatchingbufnr = 0
  while currbufnr <= bufcount
    if(bufexists(currbufnr))
      let currbufname = bufname(currbufnr)
      if(match(currbufname, a:pattern) > -1)
        echo currbufnr . ": ". bufname(currbufnr)
        let nummatches += 1
        let firstmatchingbufnr = currbufnr
      endif
    endif
    let currbufnr = currbufnr + 1
  endwhile
  if(nummatches == 1)
    execute ":buffer ". firstmatchingbufnr
  elseif(nummatches > 1)
    let desiredbufnr = input("Enter buffer number: ")
    if(strlen(desiredbufnr) != 0)
      execute ":buffer ". desiredbufnr
    endif
  else
    echo "No matching buffers"
  endif
endfunction

"Bind the BufSel() function to a user-command
command! -nargs=1 Bs :call BufSel("<args>")

call pathogen#infect() 

"For syntax checking (syntastic)
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
let g:syntastic_disabled_filetypes=['html']
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1

function! Time()
  return strftime("%c", getftime(bufname("%")))
endfunction

"For jsbeautify
map <F9> :call g:Jsbeautify()<CR> 

"Check PHP Syntax
:autocmd FileType php noremap <C-L> :!php -l %<CR>

"Beautify PHP Syntax In 4 steps
"1) reduce all multiple blank lines to a single blank line
"2) change all blank lines to something unique like 'if(true)echo('it puts the lotion on the skin');'
"3) apply beautifier 
"4) change unique quote back to new line
func! ParsePHP()
    :exe 'g/^\_$\n\_^$/d'
    :%s/^[\ \t]*\n/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';\r/ge
    :exe '%!php_beautifier --filters "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=k&r)"'
    :%s/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';//ge
endfunc

map <F8> :call ParsePHP()<CR>
```

Comment: Is it only a mapping/function problem? Do your other settings work? Where is your `.vimrc` located? Do these mappings work if you enter them on the commandline, like `:nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>`?

Comment: Could you please run: `:redir >for_stack_overflow.txt`, `:scriptnames`, `:verb map ,`, `verb map <f2>` and `:redir END`, and then post here the contents of the new file `for_stack_overflow.txt`

Comment: @romainl I have answered your questions above

Comment: @Benoit I have provided the requested output

Comment: @puk: Thank you. The mappings are defined but don't work. Have you remapped `:` for example? Try to modify them to the `nore` versions (`:map` => `:noremap`, `:nmap` => `:nnoremap`, etc.) and tell us whether things are better. What is the value of the `timeoutlen` and `timeout` settings (`:verb set timeout? timeoutlen?`)?

Comment: @puk: You have `nnoremap ; :` and `nnoremap : ;` in your `.vimrc`. Could you comment these lines and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @Benoit I have mapped `:` but I used `nnoremap`. I'm not quite sure if that is what you expect me to use. Check in the next few minutes and I will put up the results for those

Comment: @Benoit That did it. The problem was in `nnoremap ; :` and `nnoremap : ;`...now how do I get them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a mapping with `map`, the mapping behaves as if you were really interactively pressing the keys. Other mappings are triggered.

Here your problem is not with `nnoremap : ;` nor with `nnoremap ; :`. It is in `:map <whatever> :anything_else`.

You should declare this last mapping with `:noremap` instead of `:map`.

Comment: sorry but you lost me. Are you saying change `:nnoremap : ;` to `:noremap : ;`, `:nnoremap ; :` to `:noremap ; :` or something like `:map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` to `:noremap <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`

Comment: I think I get what you mean now, doing `:map <F2> :NER...` acts like I'm pressing buttons myself, which would insert a semicolon instead of the colon to make it like so `:map <F2> ;NER...`

Comment: You understood it well. So, `:noremap <F2> :NER...` does it correctly.