# How can I change the Python colours in Vim?

Tags: python, vim, vi

Can anyone tell me how to change the Python colors in Vim.
I've seen the following syntax but I'm not sure how to make it permanent.

```
:hi pythonComment ctermfg=2 gui=italic guifg=#408010
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put it in your `.vimrc` file. (Without the leading `:`, as favoretti mentioned.)

Comment: Without the leading ":" then.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't actually used vim much myself so I was double-checking the format just now (using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc, in fact) and noticed that.

Comment: Does this work? I would expect this vimrc setting to be overwritten once the colour scheme is set.

Answer (score 3):

The vimrc file is loaded before any plugins, so I would expect it to be overwritten later in the initialisation process, or at least when the colourscheme is changed. The best approach would be to associate the new `hi` command with the `ColorScheme` event, so that it is triggered automatically when the colour scheme is changed.

To do so, put this in your vimrc:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * hi pythonComment ctermfg=2 gui=italic guifg=#408010
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting really belongs in the colorscheme file, not in `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc`. Find  your current colorscheme under `~/.vim/colors` and add your statement to that file without the leading `:`.