# class & function names highlighting in Vim

Tags: c++, vim, syntax-highlighting, textmate, vim-syntax-highlighting

I just recently set up my Vim environment from Textmate, after becoming addicted to its modal input.

However, syntax highlighting seems to be not so beautiful in Vim. I code in C++ and since the function call and class names can't be highlighted, the code is more difficult to read.  I played with color scheme for a bit, but couldn't find any field that corresponded to "class name" or "function name".

In the picture below, notice how `DroughtLayer::` and `*.size()` is not highlighted on the right in MacVim.

[image: Picture comparison between Textmate(left) and Vim(right)]
<sub>(source: [ivzhao.com](http://ivzhao.com/temp/vimHL.png))</sub>

Any ideas how to solve this? It really annoys me as I am so much a visual-sensitive guy.

Comment: Do your TextMate highlight any name after 'new' or only those that were declared somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately what vim calls a syntax highlighter is usually just a lexer that can match parentheses and knows the basic context. That's the case for both C and CPP syntax files. You'd need a "real" parser to handle those cases... That means some c.vim hacking ;)

Comment: I have posted a similar question on #defines here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512602/highlighting-defined-value-in-vim. Your pointers/suggestions are appreciated. I'm hoping there is a way to highlight this like the cool answer suggested by Eduardo.

Comment: [STL improved : Improved C++ STL syntax highlighting](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2224) makes STL syntax prettier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Interestingly, the syntax highlighters in VIM don't support applying a syntax to identifiers or function names - at least not the syntax highlighters for C and C++.  So, even if you do:

```
:hi Function guifg=red
```

or

```
:hi Identifier guifg=red
```

it doesn't give these a color.  I just seems to be not much more than keywords and constants for these languages.

Here, someone has started extending the cpp syntax file to support method names.  It's a start I guess.
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlighting_of_method_names_in_the_definition

Comment: The question is about highlighting function names in the code.

Answer (score 137):

I had this very same problem when I started using vim. The solution is simple, you just have to edit the c syntax file used by vim, here's how to do it:

When you start editing a C or C++ file, vim reads the default c syntax file located in

```
$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim
```

(Where $VIMRUNTIME is where you have vim installed. You can find out it's default value by opening vim and using the command ":echo $VIMRUNTIME").

You can simply overwrite that file, or you can create your custom C syntax file (which will be loaded by vim instead of the default one) in this location:

```
$HOME/.vim/syntax/c.vim      (for UNIX)
$HOME/vimfiles/syntax/c.vim  (for PC or OS/2)
```

(I have never used a Mac so I don't know which one will work for you. You can find out more in the vim help, ":help vimfiles")

Now the fun part. Copy the default "$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim" file to your vimfiles directory ("$HOME/.vim/syntax/c.vim" for UNIX), and edit it by adding these lines:

> ```
> " Highlight Class and Function names
> syn match    cCustomParen    "(" contains=cParen,cCppParen
> syn match    cCustomFunc     "\w\+\s*(" contains=cCustomParen
> syn match    cCustomScope    "::"
> syn match    cCustomClass    "\w\+\s*::" contains=cCustomScope
>
> hi def link cCustomFunc  Function
> hi def link cCustomClass Function
> ```

That's it! Now functions and class names will be highlighted with the color defined in the "Function" highlight (":hi Function"). If you want to customize colors, you can change the last two lines above to something like this:

```
hi def cCustomFunc  gui=bold guifg=yellowgreen
hi def cCustomClass gui=reverse guifg=#00FF00
```

or you can leave the C syntax file alone and define colors in your vimrc file (":help vimrc"):

```
hi cCustomFunc  gui=bold guifg=yellowgreen
hi cCustomClass gui=reverse guifg=#00FF00
```

(Note the absence of the "def" keyword, go to ":help highlight-default" for details). For the available parameters to the ":hi" command see ":help :highlight".

You can find the complete c.vim file for Vim 7.2 on this link (Note: only use this if you have a non-modified Vim, version 7.2):

> http://pastebin.com/f33aeab77

And the obligatory screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Sorry you are supposed to be the winner of this bounty. But StackOverflow some how auto-picked the highest point one instead.
Any knowledge we can change that so you can earn 200 points (if you want).

Thanks alot anyway.

Comment: You don't need to copy c.vim. Just create a new one as `vimfiles/syntax/c.vim` with the 8 lines.

Comment: Very nice solution. I have adopted it. Is there any one one could refine the pattern so that it only highlights the function names when they are declared and not every time they are called ?

Comment: You are awesome. Enough said. I am trying to switch from Textmate to Vim and came across the same problem. This is a big thumb up for the switch!

Comment: What's the `(Sorry for imageshack)` for?  Why not just embed the image?

Comment: @Cogwheel: it works on Vim 7.4 for .cpp files. As it is, the curly braces of a `if` are highlighted as an error on C files. Removing the reference to `cCppParen`, similar to user176963's answer, makes it works for .c files too -- although I don't understand exactly the reason.

Comment: The screen shot appears to have died. Can you embed the image?

Answer (score 36):

this is my first post here and i didn't know how to make an observation, the answer of Eduardo makes "(" and "{" look unmached and bugs syntax foldind, I changed it a little to fix this.

```
syn match    cCustomParen    "?=(" contains=cParen,cCppParen
syn match    cCustomFunc     "\w\+\s*(\@=" contains=cCustomParen
syn match    cCustomScope    "::"
syn match    cCustomClass    "\w\+\s*::" contains=cCustomScope
hi def cCustomFunc  gui=bold guifg=yellowgreen
hi def link cCustomClass Function
```

Comment: Yes it breaks the folding indeed. This is the correct answer.

Comment: This can be made even better using http://stackoverflow.com/a/1819151/2716069. Then, the `cCustomParen` isn't needed any more, and the `cCustomFunc` becomes `"\w\+\ze\s*("` (Code folding still works using this I believe.)

Comment: I'm not currently using Vi but I found this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Syntax-based_folding

Answer (score 11):

The one solution is to use built ctags database. So create one with the [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) utility. Then set the 'tags' variable and put the following to the

```
~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim

function! s:highlight()
    let list = taglist('.*')

    for item in list
        let kind = item.kind

        if kind == 'f' || kind == 'c'
            let name = item.name
            exec 'syntax keyword Identifier '.name
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

call s:highlight()
```

I must warn you that this can work very slow on the very big ctags database.

Also there is [one solution](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1232) on the vim.org but I didn't try this one. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: color_coded may be too heavy for you. try [octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight](https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight). It supports C++11/14 and integrates what @Eduardo answers.
[image]

**Semantic** based highlighter:
I would recommend [jeaye/color_coded](https://github.com/jeaye/color_coded),
A vim plugin for libclang-based highlighting
So sorry that i'm new to stackoverflow which means I've not enough reputation to post images. Go see its effects if you wanna give it a shot. :)

Pros:

- Easy installation
- Semantic highlighting
- Clighter mentioned as above, need vim compiled with `python2.7`.
  However, color_coded is written in C++ and provides lua binding ->
  C++.

Cons:

- It delays unless you make some vim events to acitve it.
- Customization is bit harder; you need to edit syntax/color_coded.vim
  yourself. But customization has been placed on its roadmap.

Although it's still under development, it's increasingly gaining attention.

[image: before]
  [image: after]

Comment: Can you include some code/documentation that shows why this would be the correct answer?  A link can change over time which would then make this answer wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Sergey, changing the first line from

```
syn match    cCustomParen    "(" contains=cParen,cCppParen
```

to

```
syn match    cCustomParen    "(" contains=cParen contains=cCppParen
```

seems to fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646
Its does all ctags highlighting very efficiently for you

Answer (score 1):

Use a plug-in for vim like [Taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) or set up `ctags` or `cscope` integration with vim ([here's](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) a tutorial for the vim/cscope.)

Comment: I installed the Taglist plugin already, but isn't it for showing function/method outlines instead of highlighting/coloring the text?

Comment: @ivanTheTerrible: Please go through the FAQ(<http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/faq.html>) and the how to documentation.

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev: The FAQ mentions how to get there I believe.

Comment: @Dirkgently: a) link is broken. b) taglist doesn't highlight source code.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you the `taghighlight` plugin, click [here](http://www.cgtk.co.uk/vim-scripts/taghighlight) for it's website.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Clighter`](https://github.com/bbchung/clighter) plugin can also be considered, which is a

```
plugin for c-family semantic source code highlighting, based on Clang
```

However, requires fairly recent versions and software: `vim 7.4.330 +python2` and `libclang`.

Answer (score 1):

To match **C** functions definitions only, this works for me:

```
syn match    cCustomFuncDef display /\(\w\+\(\s\|*\)\+\)\@<=\w\+\s*(\@=/ 
hi def cCustomFuncDef ctermfg=lightblue
```