# displaying functions in c using vi

Tags: vim, editor

Is there a way to display all functions in a C source file using vim. This feature is available with the brief editor. And this would help me a lot.

Note: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Do you think this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736701/class-function-names-high-lighting-in-vim> is similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [Taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) plugin is what you are looking for. It shows functions, classes etc. in a sidebar and is designed to make source code browsing a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one. [0scan](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2507)

You can make incremental search on all functions in the current file using tag search mechanism.

[0scan](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2507) is designed to perform lots of different searches. And [here](http://www.railmoon.com/0scan/scan-current-file-ctags) you can find how to search for a functions and objects in the current file.