# Vim syntax files ... trying to understand "contains"

Tags: vim

I'm trying to patch up a new vim syntax file for some custom format I'm using. Most of it I can understand, but the keyword "contains" is giving me trouble.

Is there anyone here who could give me an explanation of what it does (I've read the help -> didn't quite get it) in a way as if he were explaining it to a tree.

Comment: Take a look at the existing syntax files in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax, a lot of them use the `contains` keyword.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In general, you can only have one syntax highlighting method in one place.  Therefore, to use C-like syntaxes as an example, if you define a region to start on an opening brace '{' and end on a closing brace '}', the syntax highlighting for that region will be the same.

`contains=` allows you to configure other syntax highlighting groups to be contained within an outer group.  To follow the previous example, you may want `int` to be highlighted even when it is in the outer region.  You could then have something like:

```
syn keyword Keyword int
syn region BraceBlock start='{' end='}' contains=Keyword
```

It is quite common to need to add items later to the list of contained keywords.  There are a few ways of doing this.  Firstly, you can use `contains=ALL` or `contains=ALLBUT,Error` to allow anything to be in a region.  Secondly, you can use `containedin` to push something into the contains of another region:

```
syn region BraceBlock start='{' end='}'
syn keyword Keyword int containedin=BraceBlock
```

Thirdly, you can define anything that is "contained" as valid in this group:

```
syn region BraceBlock start='{' end='}' contains=CONTAINED
syn keyword Keyword int contained
```

Finally, you can use clusters, which make it quite easy to decide what goes where:

```
syn region BraceBlock start='{' end='}' contains=@MyCluster
syn keyword Keyword int
syn cluster MyCluster contains=Keyword
syn keyword Conditional if else
syn cluster MyCluster add=Conditional
" Now conditionals and keywords can appear in a BraceBlock
```

Without knowing exactly what you want to understand, I'm not sure what else to say - what are you trying to achieve and what is causing you problems?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it is a way of definind rules within rules, so to speak. For example, match everything between brackets ... and then, another rule for matching "something" within an selection in brackets ? (am I even on the right trail) ?

Comment: @ldigas: That's a good summary.  Note that the internal "somethings" can either be just within the outer group (if you add the "contained" keyword to the internal item - as the third example above) or in the outer group and anywhere else (if you don't add the "contained" keyword).

Comment: Please explain me the use of `contained`. At the third point, `syn region BraceBlock start='{' end='}' contains=CONTAINED` and the line below it,