# Enable Sublime Text 3 or 4's syntax highlighting for custom types

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I'm tring to set a specific color on Sublime Text (coding C/C++) for custom types such as ones created with `typedef`s. By default, ST3/4 seems to treat one of these custom types as variable names, hence coloring them in the same way.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827517/coloring-defined-types-as-types), which is quite the same but it's about Vim, mine is specific to ST.

My problem is identical:
[image: Screenshot of my editor]

Here you see `InitMyStruct` takes a pointer to `MyStruct` as an argument and returns one, but they are not colored like a type which is, in my opinion, misleading.

Is there a way to make Sublime Text 3 or 4 change the color of those custom types? Also, I have the same request for references to `#define`d elements such as with `#define ERROR_CODE (-1)`, `ERROR_CODE` will appear as a common variable elsewhere in the code.

I tried looking into preferences for color scheme but there is no Sublime scope for that. I doubt this is a problem with my theme/color scheme as I can't find a single color scheme which handles that.

Comment: Oh yeah, yeah. mock us. Mock the colour blind with your fancy-schmancy colour-coded dev tools.

Comment: @user4581301 I specifically want to set these types to italics lol, and only lightly colorize them

Answer (score 0):

The reason they aren’t colored as types is because they aren’t built-in. You’ve declared it elsewhere in the file, or perhaps even elsewhere in the project. Regex-based syntax highlighting (mostly) only knows about the string of characters on a given line, so it can only provide scopes for what it can anticipate *a priori* based purely on the syntax.

Your best bet to get relevant scopes for these types would be to use LSP. I haven’t used it, though, so I’m not sure whether it will actually help in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What you require is "Semantic Highlighting". With Sublime Text now having an [LSP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) plugin with [clangd](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-clangd) support, you can enable these settings in `LSP.sublime-settings`.

Here are my `LSP.sublime-settings`

```json
// Settings in here override those in "LSP/LSP.sublime-settings"
{
  "lsp_format_on_save": true,
  "lsp_code_actions_on_save": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true,
  },
  "show_diagnostics_count_in_view_status": true,
  "show_inlay_hints": true,
  "semantic_highlighting": true,
}
```