# How to disable highlight brackets in GVim

Tags: c++, c, vim, syntax, highlight

I am trying to highlight my own class name and function name in C++ via GVim.
I read and followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736701/class-function-names-highlighting-in-vim) from stackoverflow. Please also check out the result [link](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2073/vimy.png)

I copied the following settting in my cpp.vim where is under syntax directory.

```
" Highlight Class and Function names 
syn match    cCustomParen    "(" contains=cParen,cCppParen 
syn match    cCustomFunc     "\w\+\s*(" contains=cCustomParen
syn match    cCustomScope    "::"
syn match    cCustomClass    "\w\+\s*::" contains=cCustomScope
hi def link cCustomFunc  Function
hi def link cCustomClass Function
```

It worked, but highlight my brackets in red. How do I disable the highlight of the brackets?
I deleted .vimrc file and open my cpp file again, it's still same. So I think it's the above code issue.

--------------------   Resolved [Solution]  --------------------

```
syn match   customFunc "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>[^()]*)("me=e-2
syn match   customFunc "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>\s*("me=e-1
hi def customFunc   gui=NONE guifg=#E54023   
syn match    cCustomScope    "::"
syn match    cCustomClass    "\w\+\s*::" contains=cCustomScope
hi def link cCustomClass Function
```

--------------------------- EOF ------------------------------

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit your `.vimrc` file. Simply add this line to the file:

```
let g:loaded_matchparen= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't introduce the mathcing brakcets with your changes. It's vim default behaviour.
So, just add

```
let g:loaded_matchparen= 1
```

to your .vimrc file.

Comment: @sav, it's still same. I think it's the problem of the code, coz after I remove the code, it doesn't have the problem.

Comment: is: enter code here`syn match    cCustomFunc     "\w\+\s*(" contains=cCustomParen、just a copy and paste issue here in stackoverflow ? or is this really in your vimrc ? doesn't this cause issues ?

Comment: @sav, yes, I just copy the code and save into my cpp.vim file, not .vimrc file. Before I add the code I haven't had the issue.

Comment: please make sure that second line: "enter code here" which is in your example above and NOT in the original post is only a copy&paste issue here, and NOT in your vimrc file :-)

Comment: @sav, ;-) right, not in my code, I changed in the post. I am sure my code is correct.

Comment: @sav, I think it's the Line2 and Line3 issue. coz for the class name, it works. Anyway, I used other pattern to solve it.