# memcpy and malloc syntax highlighting in vim for c program

Tags: c, vim, highlighting

I did enable the vim syntax highlight in vimrc,I can see void and int keyword is different color than other code,but the problem is I cannot see the function syntax highlight, function like memcpy malloc doesn't have syntax highlight,and of course my own function doesn't have syntax highlight too,

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736701/class-function-names-highlighting-in-vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vim only highlight keywords of `C`, such as `if`, `else`, `while` ... and `"string literal"`.

Because it's can be easily parsed by `regex`.

Only compiler can tell `memcpy` is a function.

Answer (score 3):

I use [this C syntax file extension](http://goo.gl/EVlK6), and I would recommend it, because it works nice: all functions, both built-in and user-defined, are highlighted. You can check out [screenshot](http://goo.gl/L0jjx).

Just for your information: there's colorscheme [desert256](http://goo.gl/SABjG) on this screenshot, but, of course, you can use any colorscheme.

Answer (score 0):

Please download a `colorscheme` from [here](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-java.html) and update your `.vimrc` with `colorscheme <name-of-the-color-scheme>` to get highlighting.

Please refer [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme) for details in `vim colorscheme`