# Semantic hilight function names in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a file with some subroutines.

The syntax is like

```txt
subroutine sub_name_1
    ...
endsub

/* or optionally */

subroutine sub_name_2 {
    ...
}
```

There are called like `call sub_name_1`.
I can't give arguments there, there is nothing of "(", ")", ";" behind.
Maybe some space characters.

I'm looking for a possibility to "collect" all the name behind the `subroutine` keywords an highlight them not only after the `subroutine` keyword but also after the `call` keywords if exist.
It would be best if I could color them in another way if the sub not exists.
If i comment, it shouldn't work.

Example:

```txt
call sub_name_1  /* "sub_name_1" should be highlighted e.g. yellow */
call sub_name_2  /* "sub_name_2"  -"- */
call sub_name_3  /* "sub_name_3" doesn't exists (outcommented). Should be e.g. red */

subroutine sub_name_1
endsub

subroutine sub_name_2 {
}

/*
subroutine sub_name_3
endsub
*/
```

Is this possible?

I already found
[class & function names highlighting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736701/class-function-names-highlighting-in-vim)
but this is not all I'm looking for. There is no highlighting of just existing subs.

Comment: Have you take a look to https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic ? Or perhaps https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp if there lsp already checking your languages

Comment: @Ôrel - Looks good to get some function :) . It's not so easy I think. And no my "language" (or whatever this syntax could be called...) is definitly not provided by anything. But I have a checking tool (puh:). Thanks so far!