# Emacs shortcut typing sequence

Tags: emacs

How to type this shortcut in emacs: C-c .|w

Comment: CAn you tell the purpose of the command?

Comment: using ecb (emacs code browser);  this command should toggle the visibilty of ecb windows.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be C-c . lw (that's the letter l, not the pipe)

    C-c . lw: `ecb-toggle-ecb-windows'     (was C-c . w)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press the control key, then press the c key, then release both keys.  Then type . normally, | normally, and w normally.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?  You really do need to put a little more effort in if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
C-h k <key sequence>
```

to learn what (if anything) `<key sequence>` is bound to in your environment as currently set up.

They read the docs for the function (`C-h f <function>`) and you are on your debugging way.

Comment: Don't forget C-h w <function> to find out what key the function is one. :)

Comment: Hm! Emacs users. This is, then, a good place to have some fun by posting this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726894/vim-tricks-your-mom-never-told-you-about-dark-corners :-)