# How can I insert text in the middle of the line to multiple lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Say I have ten lines and I want to prepend text to some word that occurs in those lines? It does not have to be at the beginning of the line.

From:

```
sdfsd   foo sdfsd
sfsd    foo fsdf
sdfsdf  foo  sdfsdf
```

to:

```
sdfsd   bar(foo sdfsd
sfsd    bar(foo fsdf
sdfsdf  bar(foo  sdfsdf
```

Is it also possible to not only prepend the `bar(` but actually surround `foo` with `bar(foo)`?

I would also like a quick way to append `//` comments to multiple lines (C-style comments).

I use Vim/GVim 7.2.

Comment: C style comments are /* */
BCPL style comments are //

Comment: Related: [How to comment out a set of lines which are selected in visual mode?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/130/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Go to the first `foo`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual block mode and press down until all the lines with `foo` are marked. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> to insert at the beginning (of the block). When you are finished and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the inserted characters will be added to each line at the left of the marked block.

To insert at the end, press again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, move up/down to mark all affected lines and then press <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>$</kbd> to extend the selection until the end of the lines. Now you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to append at the end of all the lines, just like previously with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>.

The visual selection can also be done with normal movement commands. So to comment a whole block in C you could move to the opening brace and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Just an addition: if Ctrl-V does not start visual block mode in Vim on Windows, one should use Ctrl-Q instead.

Comment: A variation of then answer is to mark visual block with shift+V thenalter the block in ex mode:
    :'<,'>s/^/prexix_text/
    :'<,'>s/$/suffix_text/
Note than "'<,'>" is printed automatically by vim when you press ":".

Comment: To uncomments use visual block (mark with Ctrl+V). One the column with comment sign "//" is marked press "d" to remove the comments.

dont forget about C++ comments (/**/) too :)

Comment: It's worth noting in Linux I had to escape out of Insert mode before the prefix applied to all lines, and it is a capital I needed to go into insert mode from Visual mode - i.e. Shift+I, type prefix, Escape, Escape.

Comment: This doesn't work on putty. When I press `i` nothing happens. When I press `shift+i` the selection disappears but I am able to insert text (on the current place where the cursor is only).

Comment: Since the visual selection in step 2 is the same as in step 1, you can avoid monotony by typing `gv` instead.

Comment: I think some people might be getting the impression that you have to press escape more than once because of the slight delay after pressing Escape, wait a moment and the changes will be there, only need to press escape once, exactly as it is said in his answer  (exactly). And new users dont forget, if your commenting shell scripts using #, that # is also a highlight key, dont let that confuse you when doing this.

Comment: @pate: You undo this like you undo anything else, with `u`.

Comment: @sth, I mean: what is the inverse operation of prepending a block? I subsequently discovered `Shift+X`.

Comment: If you are used to using Ctrl-C to exit Insert mode, make sure you use Esc instead for this. Otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 44):

To answer your first question, the below

```
:%s/foo/bar(&)/g
```

will look for `foo`, and surround the matched pattern with `bar()`. The `/g` will do this multiple times in one line.

Since you're just matching `foo`, you could do a simple `:s/foo/bar(foo)/g`. The above will work, however, if you decide to match on a regular expression rather than a simple word (e.g. `f[a-z][a-z]`). The '&' in the above represents what you've matched.

Comment: I had a big long answer with macros.  This is way easier :-)

Comment: How do you do it for multiple lines? A practical case is when you have a  block of code consisted of similar lines which require this substitution.

Comment: It sure looks like it works across all lines... note the :%s and /g.

Comment: what is interesting is that :%s/foo/bar(&)/gc  doesn't confirm  -- 'c' has no effect..Ugh

Comment: @orjac  / @Sasha - my mistake (or misinterpretation). The above will work for all lines - not just the current.

Comment: @Sasha - so the above will work for your multiple line scenario

Comment: @Sasha - I've just run the above on Vim 7.0 (not 7.2, admittedly) and the /gc *does* force a confirmation message. I don't believe there's anything in the regexp that would disable a confirmation...

Comment: The text between the `:` and the `s` determines which lines it operates on.  Nothing means just the current line.  `1,30` means lines 1 to 30 (inclusive).  `'<,'>` means the lines in the current visual selection.

Answer (score 18):

To prefix a set of lines I use one of two different approaches:

One approach is the block select (mentioned by sth). In general, you can select a rectangular region with <kbd>ctrl-V</kbd> followed by cursor-movement. Once you've highlighted a rectangle, pressing <kbd>shift-I</kbd> will insert characters on the left side of the rectangle, or <kbd>shift-A</kbd> will append them on the right side of the rectangle. So you can use this technique to make a rectangle that includes the left-most column of the lines you want to prefix, hit <kbd>shift-I</kbd>, type the prefix, and then hit escape.

The other approach is to use a substitution (as mentioned by Brian Agnew). Brian's substitution will affect the entire file (the % in the command means "all lines"). To affect just a few lines the easiest approach is to hit <kbd>shift-V</kbd> (which enables visual-line mode) while on the first/last line, and then move to the last/first line. Then type:

```
:s/^/YOUR PREFIX/
```

The ^ is a regex (in this case, the beginning of the line). By typing this in visual line mode you'll see '<,'> inserted before the s automatically. This means the range of the substitution will be the visual selection.

Extra tip: if your prefix contains slashes, you can either escape them with backslash, or you can use a different punctuation character as the separator in the command. For example, to add C++ line comments, I usually write:

```
:s:^:// :
```

For adding a suffix the substitution approach is generally easier unless all of your lines are exactly the same length. Just use $ for the pattern instead of ^ and your string will be appended instead of pre-pended.

If you want to add a prefix and a suffix simultaneously, you can do something like this:

```
:s/.*/PREFIX & SUFFIX/
```

The .* matches the whole line. The & in the replacement puts the matched text (the whole line) back, but now it'll have your prefix and suffix added.

BTW: when commenting out code you'll probably want to uncomment it later. You can use visual-block (<kbd>ctrl-V</kbd>) to select the slashes and then hit d to delete them, or you can use a substitution (probably with a visual line selection, made with <kbd>shift-V</kbd>) to remove the leading slashes like this:

```
:s:// ::
```

Answer (score 6):

:normal to the rescue!

> `:%norm Wibar(`
>
> `:%norm WEa)`

:norm(al) replays the commands as if you had typed them:

> W - goes to the next word
>
> i - starts insertion mode
>
> bar( - types the sequence 'bar('

Or in one line:

> `:%norm Wibar(`<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>`Ea)`

If you're running Windows then type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another possibility (probably not-so-useful in your test case, but handy in other situations) is to cordon off the area you want to change with marks.

- Put the cursor anywhere in the top line and press <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>
- Put the cursor anywhere in the last line and press <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>
- Issue the command `:'a,'b s/foo/bar(&)/`

I usually like visual block mode if everything is visible on the screen, and I usually prefer marks if the start and stop are separated by many screens.

Comment: It should be `m` instead of `'` to set a new marker.  `'` is for jumping to the line of an existing marker. `\`` jumps to the line and column of that marker.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple regular expression is:

```
%s/^/<text you want to prepend>/
```

Answer (score 0):

For the C-style comments, use the regexp answer by Brian, and match on line ending `$`, and insert away.