# Create a Vim function to prefix a range of lines with a user-input string

Tags: vim

I would like to create a Vim function to prefix all selected lines with some text (it's quicker than using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, etc.).

I have no experience in scripting and found this great piece of documentation and this question:

- [Scripting the Vim editor, Part 1: Variables, values, and expressions – IBM Developer](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/articles/l-vim-script-1/),
- [How can I insert text in the middle of the line to multiple lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174274/how-can-i-prepend-text-to-multiple-lines-in-vim).

I guess, I will be using the `input` function to get the text to prefix with, and then will use the `:'<,'>s/^/‹prefix_text›/` command to do the actual prefixing, but I have no idea about how to provide that `‹prefix_text›` as a variable to be plugged into a substitute expression.

I tried this very naive solution (which, evidently, does not work because it appends `input("Enter prefix text: ")` only to the current line):

```
" Prefix lines
command PrefixLines call <SID>PrefixLines()

function! <SID>PrefixLines()
    '<,'>substitute/^/input("Enter prefix text: ")/
endfunction
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ugh, too tired now to give a working solution, but read up on "execute" and "normal". Then try to copy what you usually do in normal mode with C-v I.

Comment: Why not to just use `:'<,'>s/^/prefix/` without intermediate command?

Comment: Because I'm using it all the time!

Comment: It is not obvious that typing `:PrefixLines` is faster than `:s/^/`.  Probably a mapping could be more useful.  For example, mapping like `:noremap <leader>i :s/^/\V` (for both Normal and Visual modes) allows you to press a shortcut, enter the prefix text, hit `Enter`, and get the text inserted.

Comment: Thanks! That's another good option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of the Vim substitute-with-an-expression
feature that allows for the replacement string to be the result
of evaluating a Vimscript expression. (See `:help :s\=` and
`:help s/\=` for details.)

In your case, the expression may be as simple as a reference to
the value of a local variable set to the desired prefix string
via `input()`:

```
command! -range -bar Prepend <line1>,<line2>call PrefixLines()
function! PrefixLines() range
    call inputsave()
    let t = input('Prefix: ')
    call inputrestore()
    exe a:firstline.','.a:lastline 's/^/\=t'
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `-range=%` so that default range is the whole file.