# Using Ctrl-A in Vim command line to increment a number

Tags: vim

In normal mode (in Vim) if the cursor is on a number, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> increments the number by 1. Now I want to do the same thing, but from the command line. Specifically, I want to go to certain lines whose first character is a number, and increment it, i.e., I want to run the following command:

```
:g/searchString/ Ctrl-A
```

I tried to store <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> in a macro (say `a`), and using `:g/searchString/ @a`, but I get an error:

> E492: Not an editor command ^A

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use [`normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal) to execute *normal mode* commands in *command mode*:

```
:g/searchString/ normal ^A
```

Note that you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to get the `^A` character.

Comment: Been using vim for years and never came across "normal" -- kool

Comment: @James: Beauty of the unknown :) Vim surprises like no other software!

Comment: Try the dark corners of vim question for discovering more of the unknown: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726894/what-are-the-dark-corners-of-vim-your-mom-never-told-you-about

Answer (score 11):

As well as the `:g//normal` trick posted by CMS, if you need to do this with a more complicated search than just finding a number at the start of the line, you can do something like this:

```
:%s/^prefix pattern\zs\d\+\zepostfix pattern/\=(submatch(0)+1)
```

By way of explanation:

```
:%s/X/Y            " Replace X with Y on all lines in a file
" Where X is a regexp:
^                  " Start of line (optional)
prefix pattern     " Exactly what it says: find this before the number
\zs                " Make the match start here
\d\+               " One or more digits
\ze                " Make the match end here
postfix pattern    " Something to check for after the number (optional)

" Y is:
\=                 " Make the output the result of the following expression
(
    submatch(0)    " The complete match (which, because of \zs and \ze, is whatever was matched by \d\+)
    + 1            " Add one to the existing number
)
```

Comment: Very helpful! And I like how you explained it too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i am sure you can do that with vim on the command line. But here's an alternative,

```
$ cat file
one
2two
three

$ awk '/two/{x=substr($0,1,1);x++;$0=x substr($0,2)}1' file #search for "two" and increment
one
3two
three
```