# how to i save a file as root in vim under windows

Tags: windows, vim

I sometimes open files in vim which have admin only permissions, such as config files in the program files.  I edit these and attempt to save them only to discover that the file is readonly and I can't save in the original location.  I have to save the file in a different place a copy it over the top.

I want to just issue a vim command to run the write as root, is this possible?

There is a unix verison here using sudo and tee [What are the dark corners of Vim your mom never told you about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726894/what-are-the-dark-corners-of-vim-your-mom-never-told-you-about/726920#726920)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of is to open the file as admin in the first place. 
I know in Windows 7, you're given the option to 'Open' or 'Open as Administrator'.

I think is similar to vim in unix, such that you have to open the editor with sudo in the first place.

Comment: I think I will accept this answer since it is technically correct, and maybe write a utility to save a file as admin from the vim ex mode (think I got the mode right :-}).

Comment: +1, worked so simply, just by opening it via `Run As Administrator`, saved me the agony :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `Run As Administrator` does not show up in my case as seen below.

[image]

So I went to 'Properties' as seen in the above image and under 'Security>Edit', seen below, enabled 'Full control' to my user. Though this is not as secure as `Run As Administrator`. 
[image]