# notepad2 with custom added fortran highlighting

Tags: fortran

Is there someone here, that perhaps, took upon himself the time and effort and added and recompiled [notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) with fortran highlighting?

I tried looking at the code of notepad2, but unfortunately, not having any knowledge of c/c++ was immediately lost in it. Would someone here be willing to add the fortran keywords, if I supplied him with a list of them ?

I absolutely love the editor, but since all my work is fortran and vba, not having the highlighting is a downer.

Comment: Notepad2 is my favorite editor too. I have been using since I started programming.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be [Programmers Notepad](http://programmer-s-notepad.software.informer.com/2.0) and [Notepad++ V5.3.1](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=539)

But, have you tried [GVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc)?
It comes with the `FORTRAN 77` syntax file (Vim\vim*\syntax\fortran.vim) and is a personal favorite.

If nothing else, the syntax file might be useful for enhancing your Notepad2 copy.

---

Specifically for FORTRAN support in Notepad2...
Notepad2 is based on the [Scintilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scintilla/) project at Sourceforge.
It appears to be quite simple and probably more portable than the other Scintilla based editors.
There is a [fortran lexer update reference for Scintilla](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1945318&group_id=2439&atid=102439) that might be useful, but you will have to probably integrate that into Notepad2 in some way.

Finally, you could [request a patch from Florian Balmer or Kai Liu](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html), who seem to be active **`:-)`**

---

But, my **last suggestion** is still to [learn GVim or Cream](http://www.vim.org/docs.php).
It is far more widely used and available across platforms.
Look at Stackoverflow question: **[What is the best way to force yourself to master vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74625/what-is-the-best-way-to-force-yourself-to-master-vi)**

Comment: Yes, I've tried both PN and N++, but there are some notepad2 features that I like the best. Single file for instance. Also, N++ crashed a few times on me. I even tried GVim but gave up after a while, it was too complicated and too different than all other windows programs. Maybe sometimes in the future.

Comment: I thought GVim was quite windows style. Yet, there is also Cream (http://cream.sourceforge.net/home.html) which is supposedly even more friendlier.

Comment: @nik - what I ment by "it was not windows style" ... I mean, different copy/paste, open/close ... everything. I know GVim is regarded good, and so on, but for me it's just too much different from everything else I'm used to.

Comment: GVim (as against vim) is quite windows style in your sense of the meaning. copy/paste, open/close are made to match typical windows apps. In fact, GVim is vim for the windows user AFAIK.

Comment: Don't take this wrong. But, have you tried GVim? I might have overestimated GVim in my last comment. I would not know better. Coz, I come from the school of people that end up going ":wq" in notepad applications.

Comment: Not taken. Yes, I've used it through college (that, and nano, ugh). I never could get used to it. Personal preference, if you prefer.

Comment: I'll try to talk Kai Liu into adding fortran support. I just thought I'd check here, in case someone already did it before.