# Is there an interactive way to learn Vim?

Tags: vim, editor

Years ago I was looking for a way to learn Vim that didn't involve a wall of text, or scrolling through vimtutor without knowing the commands to do so. I wondered if anything else existed for such a purpose.

Comment: Actually, the vimtutor didn't require you to scroll through walls of text without knowing the commands. The scrolling commands are right on the first page.

Comment: [This is the basic tutorial for Vim to start off with](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf) and you can get a lot of videos from Youtube as well.

Comment: I realise that - however, I was uncomfortable with vimtutor. I have classmates who also didn't particularly enjoy learning it that way. I am sure it is fine for some people, but it clearly isn't for everyone. Hence, people bothering to make screencasts and openvim, right? If vimtutor was perfect, then nobody would bother.

Comment: Vimtutor tells you exactly what to do, if you don't know what commands to use then you probably aren't actually looking at your computer screen.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Interactive tutorial:

- http://www.openvim.com/

HJKL-learning game:

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3409

Screencasts:

- http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/index.html
- http://vimcasts.org

Comment: Further screencasts https://www.semicolonandsons.com/series/A-Decade-of-Vim

Answer (score 110):

I programmed a game just for this purpose! It's an online game where you move the cursor using vim commands and motions. Check it out on http://vim-adventures.com.
The first couple of levels teach <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> and word navigation. The rest is planned to cost money.

Comment: genius! Recommended game for all vim lovers!

Comment: Yeah, it's the only think that has got me to move beyond cursor movements, / G, and i

Comment: brilliant project. Keep working on it!

Comment: No offense intended, it's a nice game, but it's not worth $25 (especially with just 6 months of access) when there are other free resources that can be used to learn vim.

Comment: This game need offline mode and I would buy it.

Comment: @nyuszika7h I agree. I would 100% buy this if it wasn't for the time limit. I need something I can use to refresh my memory 5 years from now.

Comment: After so much time I'm playing again Gothic (love it!) and I set motion keys to be `hjkl`!

Comment: It's nice to see such a wonderful game. But it requires money which was too much for me.

Comment: I think it doesn't deserve this 25$. It should be cheaper.

Comment: Given how VIM can transform how you edit text, and how good this game is at teaching it, I think $25 is a bargain.

Answer (score 16):

To answer your question: vimtutor is the good way to interactively learn vim. If you read through it, it gives you all the necessary commands to go through it, and you actually learn to use vim.

If that's too much effort, I really doubt vim is for you.

Comment: I meant answering your question as in the question in the title of your post. The reason vimtutor feels painful is that you actually learn something in the process. In any case, please don't feel attacked by my answer, I was mainly targeting it at other people than you since you obviously didn't like it.

Answer (score 11):

Old question, but for others looking for something similar that has not been mentioned:  https://www.shortcutfoo.com/

Comment: It requires subscription. Upvoted too quickly :(

Answer (score 9):

http://kikuchiyos-vim-game.herokuapp.com

Spiked this mid 2011, around time vim adventures was made, but never went nearly as far as vim adventures did.  Never got much play, but still a free alternative for anyone interested in getting over the vim learning curve - basic movement and changing modes.

Comment: Finally just put it on heroku:  http://kikuchiyos-vim-game.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I played it for a while. I didn't downvote, but the game was hard. Because there is no way to grab diamond when those are placed outside the region! Insane!

Comment: @Anwar, Hey, sorry for the late reply.  Haven't been on SO in a while. 
 You need to use jump (w (word-right), b (word-left), o ( insert-line-down), O (insert-line-up) ) to access diamonds or rubies outside of the standard region.   You'll get stuck when you do, so you'll need to teleport out with (H (top of page), L (bottom of page), 0 (beginning of line) or $ (end of line). The jump and teleport commands are on the home page.  Sorry about that.  It needs a lot of work.  Thanks for giving it a try.  Here is an example of jumping off the ledge https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fgmblzHerU

Answer (score 7):

haven't used it, but it looks close to what you're asking for

http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html

Comment: @Benoit: I have e-mailed the tutorial author who will fix it. Now, beware that it assumes you're using a standard QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: @Benoit I removed it from the tutorial. As the sandbox doesn't yet mention . I leave it to support it until I don't have more important tasks. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: @egaga: you are really quick to fix things!

Answer (score 3):

For the very beginner http://vimsnake.com is also a nice one.
It will interestingly improves the muscle memory for keys <kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd>

Now after getting prepared for those keys, we can move to http://www.vimgenius.com/ for learning. It is just similar and alternative for shortcutfoo.com and more it is vim specific.

Comment: Wow, vimsnake is *hard* if you're just learning hjkl movement!

Comment: @jrahhali checkout my score on leaderboard :P